# Converter data com timezone

Tags: javascript, java, data

`new Date()` em JavaScript me retorna esse formato:

> Tue Apr 01 2014 13:43:13 GMT-0300 (BRT)

Eu preciso converter isso para um `java.util.Date`. Para isso estou tentando utilizar `SimpleDateFormat` mas não achei um *pattern* que desse certo, sempre me retorna:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Tue Apr 01 2014 13:43:13 GMT-0300"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Como você já tem a identificação do `TimeZone` correto, que no caso é o **BRT** você poderia ignorar a parte que tem o **GMT-0300**, porque colocar o GMT no formato pode ser problemático, a não ser que ele seja fixo. Então proponho 2 soluções.

**1) Removendo o GMT-0300**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String text = stripGMT("Tue Apr 01 2014 13:43:13 GMT-0300 (BRT)");
    String format = "EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss  (zzz)";
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    System.out.println(dateFormat.parse(text));
}

private static String stripGMT(String text) {
    return text.replaceAll("GMT-\\d{4}", "");
}
```

**2) Mantendo o GMT como um argumento fixo**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String text = "Tue Apr 01 2014 13:43:13 GMT-0300 (BRT)";
    String format = "EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z (zzz)";
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    System.out.println(dateFormat.parse(text));
}
```

Comment: Testei aqui e nas duas é lançada a exception: java.text.ParseException

Comment: Opa, instanciei o SimpleDateFormat com um parâmetro a mais. Adicionei o Locale.US e deu certo. Vou testar um pouco.

Answer (score 1):

Complementando, existem alguns detalhes que não foram cobertos nas outras respostas.

Por exemplo, o dia da semana e mês estão em inglês ("Tue Apr"), e por padrão [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) usa o idioma correspondente ao [*locale default* da JVM](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23095_01/Platform.93/ATGProgGuide/html/s1809settingthejavavirtualmachineloca01.html), então não é garantido que os códigos sugeridos na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/11293/112052) funcionem sempre. Por exemplo, na minha JVM o *locale default* é `pt_BR` ([Português do Brasil](https://lh.2xlibre.net/locale/pt_BR/)), então o código sugerido dá erro, pois ele tenta fazer o *parsing* dos nomes em português.

Para que ele sempre considere os nomes em inglês, **independente da configuração da JVM**, basta informar o [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) correto no [construtor de `SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat-java.lang.String-java.util.Locale-):

```
String text = "Tue Apr 01 2014 13:43:13 GMT-0300 (BRT)";
String format = "EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z (zzz)";
// usando Locale.US (Inglês Americano)
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US);
System.out.println(dateFormat.parse(text));
```

Usei [`Locale.US`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#US) (Inglês Americano), assim ele considera os nomes em inglês, independente do *locale* que estiver configurado na JVM.

Outro ponto que discordo da outra resposta é sobre "*você já tem a identificação do `TimeZone` correto, que no caso é o BRT*". Na verdade essas abreviações como "BRT" [**não são padronizadas**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18407231), e muitas são ambíguas: há várias delas que representam mais de um timezone - veja [esta lista](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/), temos o exemplo de "CST" que é usada nos Estados Unidos, Cuba e China, ou ainda "IST", que é usada na Irlanda, Índia e Israel. Ou seja, **nem sempre (na verdade quase nunca) será possível determinar o timezone a partir da abreviação**.

Mesmo no caso de "BRT", há mais de um timezone que usa esta sigla, como `America/Sao_Paulo` e `America/Recife` (a diferença entre eles é que em muitos anos, [um adotava o horário de verão](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/brazil/sao-paulo?year=2003), e [o outro não](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/brazil/recife?year=2003)). Tudo bem que durante o horário de verão a sigla muda para "BRST", mas como já disse, as abreviações são ambíguas e não-padronizadas, e de qualquer forma, [existem muitos outros timezones no Brasil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Brazil#IANA_time_zone_database), como `America/Belem`, `America/Rio_Branco`, entre outros, que apesar de usarem a mesma sigla, possuem diferentes históricos com relação a quando cada um adotava horário de verão ou não. Ou seja, ter a abreviação não garante "a identificação do timezone correto" (ou você aceita o *default* que `SimpleDateFormat` usa, ou escolhe um arbitrariamente, como veremos a seguir).

<sup>E para entender melhor o que é um timezone e de onde vem esses nomes como `America/Sao_Paulo` e `America/Recife`, [leia aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).</sup>

---

## `java.time`

A partir do Java 8 (lançado em 2014), é possível usar a [API `java.time`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/112052). A diferença que esta API é mais flexível, e nela é possível configurar qual timezone você quer usar para a abreviação (no caso de `SimpleDateFormat`, ele usará um valor *default* e não é possível mudá-lo). Esta flexibilidade tem um preço, que é ter que dizer explicitamente o que queremos:

```
String text = "Tue Apr 01 2014 13:43:13 GMT-0300 (BRT)";

// timezones usados para "desambiguar" as abreviações
Set<ZoneId> preferredZones = new HashSet<ZoneId>();
preferredZones.add(ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo"));

DateTimeFormatter parser = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // data, hora e offset
    .appendPattern("EEE MMM dd uuuu HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z (")
    // usar timezone arbitrário para abreviação
    .appendZoneText(TextStyle.SHORT, preferredZones)
    // usar locale inglês para mês e dia da semana
    .appendLiteral(')').toFormatter(Locale.US);
// faz o parsing da String
ZonedDateTime data = ZonedDateTime.parse(text, parser);
// se precisar de um java.util.Date
Date date = Date.from(data.toInstant());
```

Uma das características desta API é que existem [várias classes diferentes para representar datas e horas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html), e você pode escolher a mais adequada para cada situação. Como neste caso eu tenho a data, hora e timezone, a melhor opção é um [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

E se precisar especificamente de um `java.util.Date`, o exemplo acima mostra como fazer a conversão.

Apesar de parecer mais trabalhoso, esta API corrige muitos dos [problemas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1969442) e [falhas de *design*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1571265) de [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) e [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), então na minha opinião é um trabalho que no fim vale a pena.

Answer (score 0):

Estabeleça um padrão de data em String que o Javascript deva passar. Depois disso, deixe por conta do Java. Um jeito um pouco mais alternativo (só um pouco) de se fazer isso seria usando o método `setTimeZone()` do `DateFormat` da seguinte maneira:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
String strData = "30/05/2014 21:45";

try {
    Date data = df.parse(strData);
    System.out.println(data);
}
catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

A saída seria:

```
Fri May 30 18:45:00 BRT 2014
```

Mas você pode se perguntar, quais os TimeZones disponíveis para a utilização no método `setTimeZone()`. Você pode listar todos os TimeZones da seguinte forma:

```
for (String tz : TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()) {
    System.out.println(tz);
}
```

Não vou postar aqui a saída, porque é um pouco extensa. Mas tenho certeza que o timezone que você procura estará na lista.

**EDIT:** Complementando a resposta a respeito do Javascript. Você pode formatar o object Date, através de vários métodos como `getMonth()`, `getDate()`, `getMinutes()`... Dessa forma você formata a data como quiser para enviar ao Java. Veja a **[referência completa do objeto Date](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)** no Javascript.

Answer (score -1):

Como no [SO em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712618/passing-javascript-date-to-java)

> A melhor formar de converter é usando o time em milisegundos, UTC. O object Javascript Date e
>   java.util.Date suportam conversão utilizando milisegundos.

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda. Eu preciso salvar com timezone. Eu posso estar errado, mas acho que com os milisegundos eu não consigo isso.

Comment: Com o milisegundos o timezone é o UTC padrão.