# Quero comparar data inicial e data final. A data inicial sempre precisa ser menor que a final. CompareTo() me surgiu um error

Tags: java, data

Quando a data final é com o horário de 00:00, ele identifica que a data inicial é maior que a data final só que não é, a data inicial continua sendo menor.

Quando eu coloco data final valendo `14/01/2017 23:45` o método me retorna `-1`. Mas se eu colocar data final valendo `14/01/2017 00:45` ele me retorna 1. Isso está errado. Como posso resolver essa questão?

Classe de exemplo:

```
public class Hora {
public static void main(String[] args) {

Date dataInicial = null;
Date dataFinal = null;
String datafinal = "14/01/2017 00:45";

//Aqui eu pego a hora atual.
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
dataInicial = c.getTime();
//System.out.println(dataInicial);

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");

try { 

  dataFinal = sdf.parse(datafinal);

} catch (Exception e) {

}       
//datafinal = sdf.format(dataFinal);

    System.out.println(dataInicial.compareTo(dataFinal));


   if(dataInicial.compareTo(dataFinal) < 0){
    System.out.println("tudo ok!");
   }
  }
   }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O resultado está correto, pois se `dataInicial` é `14/01/2017 23:45` e `dataFinal` é `14/01/2017 00:00`, `dataInicial` é maior que `dataFinal`, pois o dia se inicia as zero horas e termina as 23:59.

Veja este exemplo:

```
Date dataInicial, dataFinal;
String strDataInicial = "14/01/2017 23:45";
String strDataFinal = "14/01/2017 00:00";

SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");

dataFinal = sdf1.parse(strDataFinal);
dataInicial = sdf2.parse(strDataInicial);

System.out.println(dataInicial.compareTo(dataFinal));
System.out.println(dataInicial.after(dataFinal));
```

O retorno será `1` e `true`, pois a `dataInicial` ocorreu depois da `dataFinal`, logo ela é maior.

Minha recomendação é que veja a possibilidade de [utilizar a nova API para comparar datas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/177130/28595), nela há mais possibilidades de fazer esse tipo de comparação (neste caso `LocalDateTime` seria melhor que o `Date`).

Comment: Era só isso o que eu precisava...obrigada.