# Calendar não está funcionando corretamente

Tags: java, timestamp, calendar

A minha conversão de timestamp para calendar foi feita, aparentemente com sucesso, já que os dados apresentados aparentam corretos, exceto o dia da semana.

> data=(java.util.GregorianCalendar)
>   java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=-125784706799416,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/Sao_Paulo",offset=-10800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=129,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=America/Sao_Paulo,offset=-10800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=9,startDay=15,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=0,startTimeMode=0,endMode=3,endMonth=1,endDay=15,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=0,endTimeMode=0]],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=0,YEAR=2017,MONTH=1,WEEK_OF_YEAR=6,WEEK_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_MONTH=2,DAY_OF_YEAR=33,DAY_OF_WEEK=2,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=0,HOUR=8,HOUR_OF_DAY=8,MINUTE=40,SECOND=0,MILLISECOND=584,ZONE_OFFSET=-10800000,DST_OFFSET=0]

Notem os seguintes valores:
YEAR: 2017 (OK)
MONTH: 1 (OK - Começa em 0, então estamos falando de fevereiro)
DAY_OF_YEAR: 33 (OK - já que temos o dia 2 de fevereiro)
DAY_OF_WEEK: 2 (ERRADO, deveria ser o 5)

Foram executadas as seguintes linhas:

```
Calendar data = Calendar.getInstance();
data.set(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
data.setTime(arrAAM.get(i).getRegistroAulaAvulsa().getDataInicio());
```

OBS: Vale lembrar que tentei em com milisegundos (`setTimeInMillis`).

Comment: Dica - Use o `java.time.LocalDateTime`. Trabalhar com `java.util.Calendar` é horrível. Veja mais aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/132

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, mas estou utilizando o calendar em todo o sistema, e isto me causou estranhamento, pois aparentemente é o único atributo que está incorreto.

Comment: Cara, tente facilitar para as pessoas poderem te ajudar não colocando a imagem do erro, mas sim o erro escrito. E depois tente definir o timezone do calendar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Testei o seguinte programa:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class TesteCalendar {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar data = Calendar.getInstance();
        data.set(2017, Calendar.FEBRUARY, 2, 8, 40, 0);
        data.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 584);
        data.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Sao_Paulo"));
        System.out.println(data.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
        System.out.println(data);
    }
}
```

Eis a saída dele:

> 5
>   java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1486032000584,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/Sao_Paulo",offset=-10800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=129,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=America/Sao_Paulo,offset=-10800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=9,startDay=15,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=0,startTimeMode=0,endMode=3,endMonth=1,endDay=15,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=0,endTimeMode=0]],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2017,MONTH=1,WEEK_OF_YEAR=5,WEEK_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_MONTH=2,DAY_OF_YEAR=33,DAY_OF_WEEK=5,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=0,HOUR=8,HOUR_OF_DAY=8,MINUTE=40,SECOND=0,MILLISECOND=584,ZONE_OFFSET=-10800000,DST_OFFSET=3600000]

Entretanto, um detalhe me atentou, na sua saída aparece **time=-125784706799416** e na minha saída está **time=1486032000584**. Olhando mais atentamente, o seu está com **ERA=0** e o meu com **ERA=1**. Indo no javadoc, vejo que [`BC` é 0](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.GregorianCalendar.BC) e [`AD` é 1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.GregorianCalendar.AD). Ou seja o seu está em `BC` e o meu em `AD`. Eis o que é `BC` de acordo com o [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#BC):

> Value of the ERA field indicating the period before the common era (before Christ), also known as BCE. The sequence of years at the transition from BC to AD is ..., 2 BC, 1 BC, 1 AD, 2 AD,...

Vou só enfatizar essa parte:

> before Christ

Ou seja, você colocou 2 de fevereiro do ano 2017 **antes de Cristo**!

A solução então, é acrescentar isso:

```
data.set(Calendar.ERA, GregorianCalendar.AD);
```

Comment: Com a sua resposta foi possível entender a raiz do problema. Então vou colocar ela aqui, para ajudar a comunidade. Ao colocar **data.set(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);**, o ano é setado para "0" indo para antes de Cristo, mesmo sobrescrevendo o ano para a data atual, ele não muda o BC.

Comment: @Lucas_Kunze É porque não houve ano zero. Antes do ano 1 AD, teve o ano 1 BC. Assim sendo, 0 é o ano 1 BC, -1 é o ano 2 BC, -2 é o ano 3 BC, etc.

Comment: Sim, entendi, o efeito que eu queria era o de limpar os campos, para depois sobrescrevê-lo. Não pensei que isso causaria mudança no AC/DC. Para falar a verdade, nem lembrei da existência dos mesmos.