# Percorrendo Datas utilizando Calendar

Tags: java, data, calendar

Estou fazendo um relatório em `java`, que passo um período especificado pelo usuário. Na minha `DAO` eu estou fazendo o tratamento.

Aqui Pego a data passada.

```
String data1 = DateUtil.toString(dto.getDataInicio(), "MM/yyyy");
        String data2 =  DateUtil.toString(dto.getDataFim(), "MM/yyyy");

        Calendar c1 = DateUtil.parseCal (data1);
        Calendar c2 = DateUtil.parseCal (data2);
```

Aqui faço um tratamento para verificar os meses passados.

```
for (Calendar c = (Calendar) c1.clone(); c.compareTo (c2) <= 0; c.add (Calendar.DATE, +1)) {
           if (c.get (Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.JANUARY  && c.get (Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == 01){
                     mesesql += "total_faturado_mensal(cs.id_corp, '"+c1.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"-01-01', '"+c2.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"-01-01', to_char('"+c1.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"-01-01'::date, 'yyyy-mm'), cl.id_convenio) as janeiro, ";       
                       nomesMeses.add("Janeiro");
               }
             if (c.get (Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.FEBRUARY && c.get (Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == 01){
                            mesesql += "total_faturado_mensal(cs.id_corp, '"+c1.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"-02-01', '"+c2.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"-02-01', to_char('"+c1.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"-02-01'::date, 'yyyy-mm'), cl.id_convenio) as fevereiro, ";     
                            nomesMeses.add("Fevereiro");
               }     
             if (c.get (Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.MARCH && c.get (Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == 01){
                            mesesql += "total_faturado_mensal(cs.id_corp, '"+c1.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"-03-01', '"+c2.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"-03-01', to_char('"+c1.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"-03-01'::date, 'yyyy-mm'), cl.id_convenio) as marco, ";
                            nomesMeses.add("Março");
               }
             if (c.get (Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.APRIL && c.get (Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == 01){
                            mesesql += "total_faturado_mensal(cs.id_corp, '"+c1.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"-04-01', '"+c2.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"-04-01', to_char('"+c1.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"-04-01'::date, 'yyyy-mm'), cl.id_convenio) as abril, ";
                            nomesMeses.add("Abril");
               }
             if (c.get (Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.MAY && c.get (Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == 01){
                           mesesql += "total_faturado_mensal(cs.id_corp, '"+c1.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"-05-01', '"+c2.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"-05-01', to_char('"+c1.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"-05-01'::date, 'yyyy-mm'), cl.id_convenio) as maio, ";
                            nomesMeses.add("Maio");
               }
             if (c.get (Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.JUNE && c.get (Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == 01){
                           mesesql += "total_faturado_mensal(cs.id_corp, '"+c1.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"-06-01', '"+c2.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"-06-01', to_char('"+c1.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"-06-01'::date, 'yyyy-mm'), cl.id_convenio) as junho,  ";
                            nomesMeses.add("Junho");
               }
             if (c.get (Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.JULY && c.get (Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == 01){
                           mesesql += "total_faturado_mensal(cs.id_corp, '"+c1.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"-07-01', '"+c2.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"-07-01', to_char('"+c1.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"-07-01'::date, 'yyyy-mm'), cl.id_convenio) as julho, ";
                            nomesMeses.add("Julho");
               }
             if (c.get (Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.AUGUST && c.get (Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == 01){
                           mesesql += "total_faturado_mensal(cs.id_corp, '"+c1.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"-08-01', '"+c2.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"-08-01', to_char('"+c1.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"-08-01'::date, 'yyyy-mm'), cl.id_convenio) as agosto, ";
                            nomesMeses.add("Agosto");
               }
             if (c.get (Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.SEPTEMBER && c.get (Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == 01){
                           mesesql += "total_faturado_mensal(cs.id_corp, '"+c1.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"-09-01', '"+c2.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"-09-01', to_char('"+c1.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"-09-01'::date, 'yyyy-mm'), cl.id_convenio) as setembro, ";
                            nomesMeses.add("Setembro");
               }
             if (c.get (Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.OCTOBER && c.get (Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == 01){
                           mesesql += "total_faturado_mensal(cs.id_corp, '"+c1.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"-10-01', '"+c2.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"-10-01', to_char('"+c1.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"-10-01'::date, 'yyyy-mm'), cl.id_convenio) as outubro, ";
                            nomesMeses.add("Outubro");
               }
             if (c.get (Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.NOVEMBER && c.get (Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == 01){
                           mesesql += "total_faturado_mensal(cs.id_corp, '"+c1.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"-11-01', '"+c2.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"-11-01', to_char('"+c1.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"-11-01'::date, 'yyyy-mm'), cl.id_convenio) as novembro, ";
                            nomesMeses.add("Novembro");
               }
             if (c.get (Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.DECEMBER && c.get (Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == 01){
                           mesesql += "total_faturado_mensal(cs.id_corp, '"+c1.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"-12-01', '"+c2.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"-12-01', to_char('"+c1.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"-12-01'::date, 'yyyy-mm'), cl.id_convenio) as dezembro, "; 
                            nomesMeses.add("Dezembro");
               }

            }
```

Está funcionando, porém ao informar um período por exemplo de 01/2016 há 12/2016 ele não está entrando dentro do `if (c.get (Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.DECEMBER` trazendo então só de janeiro a Novembro.  Mas se eu coloco só 11/2016 e 12/2016 aparece o dezembro.
E para aparecer os 12 meses de 2016, eu tenho que colocar um mês amais por exemplo:
01/2016 á 01/2017 ai sim ele me traz o mês de dezembro.... e assim consequentemente, com datas maiores. Eu não intendo muito como funciona o Calendar, estou fazendo algo errado?

Comment: Month retorna o número do mês -1, ou seja, 11 será dezembro.

Comment: Recomendado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/132

Comment: sim @diegofm, por isso comparo com Calendar.DECEMBER que  é um int 11. Mas funciona normalmente com os meses de janeiro a outubro. Sò nesses últimos está assim.  Eu achei casos parecidos com esse problema mas não resolveram.

Comment: Arthur, acho que o problema aqui é mais básico do que isso, a condição  `c.compareTo (c2) <= 0` é estrita e o Calendário leva em consideração campos além do mês e ano, estando eles presentes na data inicial ou não. Se você quer que a pesquisa seja inclusiva é necessário usar o último millisegundo do último segundo do último minuto da última hora do último dia do mês em questão (da mesma forma é importantente zerar todos esses valores para o primeiro dia).

Comment: Que classe é essa que você está usando: `DateUtil`?

Comment: Se você realmente quer usar `Calendar` (por que? :() um *workaround* conhecido é tornar o *range* aberto e utilizar o primeiro dia do mês seguinte, se precisar de outras opções de uma olhada [nessa pergunta](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3672052/664577). Dito isso, eu daria uma lida no link que o @VictorStafusa compartilhou e no [Tutorial Oficial da Oracle sobre Date Time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Um detalhe que achei suspeito é que no `for`, você está incrementando dias, e não meses. Em qualquer dia que não for um dia 01, a iteração do `for` não vai fazer nada, apenas ficar pulando dia após dia. Além disso, a quantidade de código repetido é imensa. Por isso, vamos refazer o seu código:

```
String data1 = DateUtil.toString(dto.getDataInicio(), "MM/yyyy");
String data2 = DateUtil.toString(dto.getDataFim(), "MM/yyyy");

Calendar c1 = DateUtil.parseCal(data1);
Calendar c2 = DateUtil.parseCal(data2);

String[] meses = {
    "zero",
    "Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março", "Abril",
    "Maio", "Junho", "Julho", "Agosto",
    "Setembro", "Outubro", "Novembro", "Dezembro"
};

String template = "total_faturado_mensal(cs.id_corp, '$A-$I-01', '$B-$I-01', to_char('$A-$I-01'::date, 'yyyy-mm'), cl.id_convenio) as $M, ";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(8192);
sb.append(mesesql);

Calendar c = (Calendar) c1.clone();
while (c.compareTo(c2) <= 0) {
    int mes = c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    sb.append(template
            .replace("$A", String.valueOf(c1.get(Calendar.YEAR)))
            .replace("$B", String.valueOf(c2.get(Calendar.YEAR)))
            .replace("$M", meses[mes])
            .replace("$I", mes < 10 ? "0" + mes : "" + mes));
    nomesMeses.add(meses[mes]);
    c.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
    c.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}

mesesql = sb.toString();
```

Neste código acima, **estou supondo que a classe `DateUtil` funciona e não tem nenhum bug ou surpresa.** Se não for este o caso, pode ser que dê errado, mas aí você vai ter que postar ao menos os métodos `toString` e `parseCal` dela para darmos uma olhada.

Outra alternativa é usando [as classes do pacote `java.time`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/132), muito melhores do que usar a horrorosa `java.util.Calendar`. Eis como fica o código nesse caso:

```
Date a = dto.getDataInicio();
Date b = dto.getDataFim();

LocalDate c1 = a.toInstant().atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDate().withDayOfMonth(1);
LocalDate c2 = b.toInstant().atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDate().withDayOfMonth(1);

String[] meses = {
    "zero",
    "Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março", "Abril",
    "Maio", "Junho", "Julho", "Agosto",
    "Setembro", "Outubro", "Novembro", "Dezembro"
};

String template = "total_faturado_mensal(cs.id_corp, '$A-$I-01', '$B-$I-01', to_char('$A-$I-01'::date, 'yyyy-mm'), cl.id_convenio) as $M, ";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(8192);
sb.append(mesesql);

for (LocalDate c = c1; c.compareTo(c2) <= 0; c = c.plusMonths(1)) {
    int mes = c.getMonth().getValue();
    sb.append(template
            .replace("$A", String.valueOf(c1.getYear()))
            .replace("$B", String.valueOf(c2.getYear()))
            .replace("$M", meses[mes])
            .replace("$I", mes < 10 ? "0" + mes : "" + mes));
    nomesMeses.add(meses[mes]);
}

mesesql = sb.toString();
```

E neste código, é claro que se você puder mudar o `dto.getDataInicio()` e o `dto.getDataFim()` para retornar `LocalDate` ao invés de `Date`, fica mais fácil.

Comment: Os dois métodos deu certo. Obrigado. Realmente ficou mais limpo e bunito o codigo.