# @QueryParam - Tipo Date

Tags: java

Estou com problemas ao enviar uma Data, está sempre null na minha controller rest. Já tentei sem $.param também e não rolou.

Meu $scope.filter.begin já está indo no formato Date na requisição e o valor está correto.

Como eu envio os meus dados do tipo Date corretamente? Devo usar outra anotação que não seja @QueryParam?

Estou enviando uma data para o REST da seguinte maneira:

```
$scope.doFilter = function(){
    $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: "rest/entry/loadEntriesByFilter",
        data: $.param({filterBegin: $scope.filter.begin}, true)
    }).then(function sucessCallback(response){
        console.log(response);
    }),
    function error(response){
        console.log(response);
    }       
}
```

E na minha Controller estou recebendo dessa maneira:

```
@GET
@Path("/loadEntriesByFilter")
public Collection<EntryPojo> loadEntriesByFilter(@QueryParam("filterBegin")
       Date data){
```

Comment: você quer enviar a data atual?

Comment: Tenho dois inputs do tipo date o usuário escolhe a data que ele deseja filtrar. 

No caso ali só tem um parametro de data que é o filterBegin, porque eu só estou testando com um parametro primeiro.

Se o usuário escolher 20/02/2017, deve ir essa data na requisição, entendeu?

Comment: Olha essa resposta dos gringos, talvez te ajude: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9522619/2570426

Comment: Talvez o problema esta relacionado ao formato da data.

Comment: Acho que o link que você me passou não ajudaria na minha situação.

Então, o formato que estou enviando é Sun Oct 10 2010 01:00:00 GMT-0200

Comment: Você vai ter que passar a data como uma String e fazer a conversão no back-end, ou seja, mudar o seu serviço para passar a receber uma String ao inves de um Date.

Comment: Sugiro a você abandonar o `Date` e migrar para o `LocalDate`, `LocalDateTime` ou `OffsetDateTime`, dependendo de qual for o mais apropriado. Veja isso: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/132

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com a [documentação do Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2225), para uma classe ser suportada como um `@QueryParam`, ela precisa satisfazer os seguintes requisitos:

1. Ser um tipo primitivo;
2. Tem um construtor que aceita apenas uma `String` como argumento;
3. Ter um método estático cujo nome seja `fromString` ou `valueOf` e aceite apenas uma `String` como argumento;
4. Ter uma implementação da interface `javax.ws.rs.ext.ParamConverterProvider` que retorne uma instância da interface`javax.ws.rs.ext.ParamConverter`, ou;
5. Ser uma `List<T>`, `Set<T>` ou `SortedSet<T>`, onde `T` satisfaça as opções 2 ou 3.

O único critério que a classe `Date` satisfazia era a 2, porém, como o construtor `Date(String)` foi marcado como `@Deprecated` (obsoleto), os desenvolvedores do Jersey optaram por [parar de suportá-lo](https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2553) a partir do Jersey 2.x.

Sendo assim, a única opção que resta é implementar um `javax.ws.rs.ext.ParamConverterProvider` e registrá-lo. Exemplo:

```
public class DateParamProvider implements ParamConverterProvider {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public <T> ParamConverter<T> getConverter(final Class<T> rawType, final Type genericType,
                                              final Annotation[] annotations) {
        if (rawType != Date.class) {
            return null;
        }
        //TODO teste se esse é realmente o formato utilizado pelas suas datas
        final DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z");

        return (ParamConverter<T>) new ParamConverter<Date>() {
            @Override
            public Date fromString(final String value) {
                try {
                    return format.parse(value);
                } catch (final ParseException e) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public String toString(final Date value) {
                return format.format(value);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

E registrá-lo (isso vai depender de como você configurou o seu projeto. Ex: via `javax.ws.rs.core.Application`, `web.xml` ou `org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig`):

`javax.ws.rs.core.Application`

```
//TODO ajuste para o caminho da sua aplicação
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class InitApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<>();
        classes.add(SuaClasseAnotadoComPath.class);      //Sua classe anotado com @Path
        classes.add(DateParamProvider.class);
        return classes;
    }
}
```

`org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig`

```
//TODO ajuste para o caminho da sua aplicação
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class InitApp extends ResourceConfig {

    public InitApp() {
        register(SuaClasseAnotadoComPath.class);        //Sua classe anotado com @Path
        register(DateParamProvider.class);
    }
}
```

Uma outra solução mais simples seria receber o parâmetro como uma `String` e, dentro do próprio método, fazer a conversão para `Date`.

Observação: se não houver nenhuma obrigação em utilizar a classe `Date`, dê uma olhada novas classes inseridas no Java 8 do pacote `java.time`, nesse caso em especial, na classe `ZonedDateTime` (mesmo com essa classe, o uso de uma implementação de um  `javax.ws.rs.ext.ParamConverterProvider` ainda é necessário).

Comment: Adorei a sua resposta, tem muita informação nela que eu não sabia e que me será muito útil. +1

Comment: @VictorStafusa Muito obrigado!