# Como Verificar se a data é válida ou inválida?

Tags: java, data

Estou aprendendo Java por conta própria e me deparei com um exercício que não sei por onde começar a pesquisar. Eu achei alguma coisa sobre datetime, try, catch. Mas eu não consegui entender bem porque os exemplos eram muito mais complexos do que o meu problema.

Alguém poderia me dar uma direção sobre o datetime e algum método que eu possa conhecer que vai me ajudar com esse exercicio?

O meu enunciado do exercicio é:

```
   //Faça um Programa que peça uma data no formato dd/mm/aaaa 
   //e determine se a mesma é uma data válida.
```

Comment: Simples, porque é Java.

Comment: O que já tentou? A pergunta está meio ampla pelo enunciado.

Comment: Eu tentei fazer com array, mas tem resultados que podem não ser datas válidas e diz que é.

Comment: [Como migrar de Date e Calendar para a nova API de datas no Java 8?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/177129/como-migrar-de-date-e-calendar-para-a-nova-api-de-datas-no-java-8)

Comment: @diegfm

Encontrei esse código, porém não compila. (Estou aprendendo usando Geany, sem autocomplete e outras ajudas)

Da erro Na linha do catch, na linha do DateFormat

`class DataValida {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String s = "31/02/2009";
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd/MM/yyyy");
        df.setLenient (false); // aqui o pulo do gato
        try {
            df.parse(s);
            // data válida
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            System.out.println("Data inválida");
        }        
    }
}`

Comment: Coloquei o código entre ` ` e não formatou

Comment: Se sua intenção é aprender a manipular datas em java, o post que linkei te dará bastante conteudo a respeito, vale a pena da uma lida.

Comment: Acabei de ver, vou dar uma lida

Comment: @GabrielSaldanha viu minha resposta? Ela soluciona o problema?

Answer (score 8):

Complementando a resposta do [Murilo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/63110/murillo-goulart), apesar de validar o formato, acaba que o método deixa passar algumas datas consideradas inválidas(como 30 de fevereiro).

Utilizando [`ResolverStyle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html) em modo `Strict`, você acaba por forçar o formatter a validar se a data, mesmo tendo um formato válido de data, é realmente uma data válida:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

        System.out.println("29/02/2016 eh uma data valida? " + isDateValid("29/02/2016"));
        System.out.println("29/02/2017 eh uma data valida? " + isDateValid("29/02/2017"));
        System.out.println("31/06/2017 eh uma data valida? " + isDateValid("30/01/2017"));
        System.out.println("31/04/2017 eh uma data valida? " + isDateValid("31/04/2017"));

}

public static boolean isDateValid(String strDate) {
    String dateFormat = "dd/MM/uuuu";

    DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter
    .ofPattern(dateFormat)
    .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);
    try {
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(strDate, dateTimeFormatter);
        return true;
    } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
       return false;
    } 
}
```

Que resultará em:

> ```
> 29/02/2016 eh uma data valida? true  //2016 é bissexto, data válida  
> 29/02/2017 eh uma data valida? false   //inválida  
> 31/06/2017 eh uma data valida? true    //data válida  
> 31/04/2017 eh uma data valida? false   //abril só tem 30 dias, data inválida
> ```

Veja um teste no [**Ideone**](https://ideone.com/dEPvpS)

Esta resposta foi baseada nesta do [SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32823520/5524514). Nesta [outra pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41177442/5524514) há uma explicação do porquê o uso de `u`(nova representação de ano) ao invés de `y`(representação de ano de uma era) para formatação dentro da nova API.

Comment: muito legal @diegofm, obrigado por compartilhar.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando a API do Java 8, é possível fazer o teste com `LocalDate` e o método parse, conforme segue:

```
public class DateValidator {

   public boolean isValid(String date) {
      try {
         DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
         LocalDate d = LocalDate.parse(date, formatter);    
         return true;
      } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
        return false;
      }   
   }
}
```

Execute a classe criada via [Ideone](https://ideone.com/o7mRI4).

Comment: Seu código está validando várias datas que podem ser consideradas inválidas, veja: https://ideone.com/y44z0s