# Retornar dia da semana a partir de uma data no formato dd/mm/yyy

Tags: java, data

tenho essa função que me traz o dia da semana:

```
public static String getWeek(String date){ //ex 07/03/2017
    String dayWeek = "---";
    GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
    try {
        gc.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", BRAZIL).parse(date));
        switch (gc.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)) {
            case Calendar.SUNDAY:
                dayWeek = "DOM";
                break;
            case Calendar.MONDAY:
                dayWeek = "SEG";
                break;
            case Calendar.TUESDAY:
                dayWeek = "TER";
            break;
            case Calendar.WEDNESDAY:
                dayWeek = "QUA";
                break;
            case Calendar.THURSDAY:
                dayWeek = "QUI";
                break;
            case Calendar.FRIDAY:
                dayWeek = "SEX";
                break;
            case Calendar.SATURDAY:
                dayWeek = "SAB";

        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dayWeek;
}
```

Mas ela esta me trazendo o dia da semana anterior, ex: 07/03/2017 terça-feira ele traz como segunda-feira.

Answer (score 7):

Sua máscara de formatação de data está errada. Você está usando o formato `MM/dd/yyyy` quando sua string recebe um formato `dd/MM/yyyy`. Apenas altere a máscara:

```
public static String getWeek(String date){ //ex 07/03/2017
    String dayWeek = "---";
    GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
    try {
        gc.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(date));
        switch (gc.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)) {
            case Calendar.SUNDAY:
                dayWeek = "DOM";
                break;
            case Calendar.MONDAY:
                dayWeek = "SEG";
                break;
            case Calendar.TUESDAY:
                dayWeek = "TER";
            break;
            case Calendar.WEDNESDAY:
                dayWeek = "QUA";
                break;
            case Calendar.THURSDAY:
                dayWeek = "QUI";
                break;
            case Calendar.FRIDAY:
                dayWeek = "SEX";
                break;
            case Calendar.SATURDAY:
                dayWeek = "SAB";

        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dayWeek;
}
```

Bastou esta alteração e funcionou corretamente, veja: https://ideone.com/LLcvyr

Answer (score 3):

A sua máscara está errada, como o Articuno respondeu.

Você também pode encurtar o seu código para:

```
public static String getWeek(String date){ //ex 07/03/2017
        String dayWeek = "---";
        GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
        try {
            gc.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", new Locale("pt", "BR")).parse(date));
           return new SimpleDateFormat("EEE", new Locale("pt", "BR")).format(gc.getTime()).toUpperCase();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return dayWeek;
    }
```

Comment: Alternativa interessante, +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

A partir do Java 8, você pode usar a [API `java.time`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/112052)

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
import java.util.Locale;

public static String getDayOfWeek(String data) {
    DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu");
    DayOfWeek dow = DayOfWeek.from(parser.parse(data));
    return dow.getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, new Locale("pt", "BR")).toUpperCase();
}

System.out.println(getDayOfWeek("07/03/2017")); // TER
```

Eu também poderia fazer `LocalDate.parse(data, parser).getDayOfWeek()` para obter o [`DayOfWeeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html), mas se você só quer o dia da semana, não precisa criar um [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) à toa.

E mudei o nome do método, pois `getWeek` dá a impressão de que vai retornar toda a semana, mas você só quer um dia da semana, então deixei como `getDayOfWeek`.

---

Outro detalhe é que no seu método você está capturando a exceção (`ParseException` caso a data seja inválida), imprimindo o *stack trace* e depois retornando `"---"`. Sem entrar no mérito de não estar tratando o erro, uma forma de ter o mesmo comportamento é:

```
public static String getDayOfWeek(String data) {
    try {
        DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu")
                                      .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);
        DayOfWeek dow = DayOfWeek.from(parser.parse(data));
        return dow.getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, new Locale("pt", "BR")).toUpperCase();
    } catch (DateTimeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "---";
}

System.out.println(getDayOfWeek("31/02/2017")); // ---
```

O [`ResolverStyle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html), conforme explicado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/187296/112052), serve para garantir que datas como 29 de fevereiro em anos não-bissextos e 31 de abril sejam consideradas inválidas - tem uma explicação mais detalhada [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/370367/112052), na seção "Modos de *parsing*".

---

Mas este método não é muito eficiente, pois toda vez que for chamado, cria duas instâncias de [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html): uma explicitamente, e outra implicitamente, dentro de [`getDisplayName`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#getDisplayName-java.time.format.TextStyle-java.util.Locale-) ([veja no código fonte](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/time/DayOfWeek.java#l226)).

Sendo assim, uma alternativa é guardar essas instâncias em variáveis estáticas, assim eles são criados apenas uma vez:

```
public static DateTimeFormatter DOW_FMT = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E", new Locale("pt", "BR"));

public static DateTimeFormatter PARSER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu").withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);

public static String getDayOfWeek(String data) {
    try {
        return DOW_FMT.format(PARSER.parse(data)).toUpperCase();
    } catch (DateTimeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "---";
}
```

Repare que assim você nem precisa criar o `DayOfWeek`, pois o resultado do *parsing* é passado diretamente para o formatador, que já pega o dia da semana e formata.

---

Se quiser continuar usando `SimpleDateFormat`, há um detalhe importante: por padrão, esta classe aceita datas inválidas como "33/22/2017", fazendo alguns ajustes bem estranhos:

```
// 33/22/2017 vira 2 de novembro de 2018
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("33/22/2017")); // Fri Nov 02 00:00:00 BRT 2018
```

Para evitar esse problema, basta setá-lo como não-leniente:

```
public static String getWeek(String date) { // ex 07/03/2017
    String dayWeek = "---";
    GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
    SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    parser.setLenient(false); // <- setar como não-leniente, assim não aceita datas inválidas
    try {
        gc.setTime(parser.parse(date));
        switch (gc.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)) {
            etc...
```

---

Uma [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/463699/112052) sugeriu usar [`DateFormatSymbols`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormatSymbols.html), mas foi usado [`getWeekdays`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormatSymbols.html#getWeekdays--), que retorna os nomes completos ("Domingo", "Segunda-feira", etc). Sem contar que se você criá-la sem especificar um `Locale`, como foi sugerido, ela usará o *default* que está configurado na JVM (por exemplo, se a JVM estiver configurada com algum *locale* em inglês, serão retornados os nomes neste idioma - "Sunday", "Monday", etc).

Então se quiser usar aquela solução, você precisa especificar o *locale* para que use o português, e usar [`getShortWeekdays`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormatSymbols.html#getShortWeekdays--) para ter os nomes abreviados. E como esse array é fixo e será usado sempre que o método for chamado, pode criá-lo apenas uma vez também:

```
public static String[] WEEKDAYS = new DateFormatSymbols(new Locale("pt", "BR")).getShortWeekdays();

public static String getDayOfWeek(String data) {
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        parser.setLenient(false);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(parser.parse(data));
        return WEEKDAYS[cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)].toUpperCase();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "---";
}
```

Ou, se quiser otimizar mais ainda, já deixe o array com os nomes em maiúsculas, assim você não precisa chamar `toUpperCase`:

```
public static String[] WEEKDAYS;
static {
    WEEKDAYS = new DateFormatSymbols(new Locale("pt", "BR")).getShortWeekdays();
    for (int i = 0; i < WEEKDAYS.length; i++) {
        WEEKDAYS[i] = WEEKDAYS[i].toUpperCase();
    }
}

public static String getDayOfWeek(String data) {
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        parser.setLenient(false);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(parser.parse(data));
        return WEEKDAYS[cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)];
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "---";
}
```

---

E claro que também tem a opção de usar um array com os valores fixos:

```
public static String[] WEEKDAYS = {"DOM", "SEG", "TER", "QUA", "QUI", "SEX", "SAB"};

public static String getDayOfWeek(String data) {
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        parser.setLenient(false);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(parser.parse(data));
        return WEEKDAYS[cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1];
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "---";
}
```

O detalhe é que arrays começam do índice zero, mas os valores de `DAY_OF_WEEK` vão de 1 a 7 (Domingo a Sábado), então preciso subtrair 1 para obter o valor correto (no caso de `getShortWeekdays` não é necessário porque ele retorna um array cuja primeira posição é uma string vazia).

Answer (score 0):

Costumo usar o componente DateChooser na interface.
O componente DateChooser retorna um java.util.Calendar.
Com isso, você poderá  usar métodos como estes:

```
public String diaDaSemana(Calendar calendar) {
    return new DateFormatSymbols().getWeekdays()[calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)];
}

public String nomeDoMes(Calendar calendar) {
    return new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths()[calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)];
}
```

Comment: Isso não retorna no formato indicado ("SEG", "TER", etc), pois `getWeekdays` retorna os nomes completos ("Domingo", "Segunda-feira", etc) - deveria ser `getShortWeekdays` para ter os nomes abreviados - e se a JVM estiver configurada com um *locale* que não seja em português, os nomes virão em outro idioma - veja os detalhes na [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/463769/112052) :-)