# Extrair data com Regex

Tags: java, string, regex

Estou tentando extrair uma data de uma String, mas não estou conseguindo.

Exemplo:

```
String stringQualquer = "um teste qualquer12/02/1998 19/09/1880 Nulo";
```

Eu quero pegar a primeira data deste exemplo "12/02/1998".

Tentei assim, mas não funcionou:

```
^(\\d{2}\\/\\d{2}\\/\\d{4})
```

Comment: Apenas complementando, se a `String` contém somente datas válidas, a regex resolve, mas caso ela tenha coisas como `31/04/2018` (31 de abril, que é uma data inválida), a regex dará um falso positivo. Eu sugiro que, depois que a data seja obtida da `String`, ela também seja validada, usando as APIs de data do java, conforme explicado nesta resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/187296/112052

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O caractere `^` significa início de string, ou seja, sua string teria que começar com o padrão indicado.

Somente `(\\d{2}\\/\\d{2}\\/\\d{4})` é suficiente.

Pra pegar o primeiro, basta não avançar o matcher:

```
String stringQualquer = "um teste qualquer12/02/1998 19/09/1880 Nulo";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4})");

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(stringQualquer);

if(matcher.find()) {
  System.out.println(matcher.group()); // printa 12/02/1998
}
```

https://ideone.com/RoKEGH

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

A sua regex está correta, porém o `^` é uma âncora e indica que irá realizar o match no início da `String`.

Para a `String` em questão o ideal é dar um match na primeira ocorrência de uma data sem nenhum modificador como o `g` que é global, vide o exemplo abaixo:

```
(\\d{2}\\/\\d{2}\\/\\d{4})
```

[Exemplo no Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/E5LuvY/2)

Comment: Como poderia verificar com regex se essa string contém números ?

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score -2):

Sua regex só vai funcionar se a data estiver no início da string, tente tirar o "^" da frente.

Comment: Muito obrigado!