# Como gerar TimeFormatter no formato YYYY-mm-DDThh:mm:ss-TZ

Tags: java, datetime

Eu tenho a string `2018-09-26T10:36:40-03:00` e gostaria de converter ela para `LocalDateTime`.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");

LocalDate.parse("2018-09-26T10:36:40-03:00",formatter)
```

Comment: Possivel duplicata de [Como migrar de Date e Calendar para a nova API de datas no Java 8?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/177129/como-migrar-de-date-e-calendar-para-a-nova-api-de-datas-no-java-8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As classes do `java.time` já fazem parsing de strings no [formato ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), que é o formato no qual a sua string está.

Você disse que quer um `LocalDateTime`, mas no seu código está usando `LocalDate`. De qualquer forma, é possível obter ambos.

A sua string possui data (`2018-09-26`), horário (`10:36:40`) e [offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC) (`-03:00`), portanto o melhor tipo para representá-la é [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).

A partir do `OffsetDateTime` você pode obter o `LocalDateTime` e o `LocalDate`:

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2018-09-26T10:36:40-03:00");
LocalDateTime datetime = odt.toLocalDateTime();
LocalDate date = odt.toLocalDate();
```

---

O seu código não funcionou porque o formato passado para o `DateTimeFormatter` não corresponde à string de entrada.

O trecho `dd-MM-yyyy`, por exemplo, representa o dia, seguido de traço, seguido do mês, traço e ano, mas a string começa com os 4 dígitos do ano (veja a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns) para conhecer todas as letras que podem ser usadas e o que cada uma significa). Sem contar o `'Z'` (entre aspas simples), que corresponde à própria letra "Z" (e não a um campo específico da data).

---

Caso queira usar um `DateTimeFormatter`, é possível fazer o parsing diretamente para `LocalDate` ou `LocalDateTime`, sem precisar do `OffsetDateTime`:

```
String str = "2018-09-26T10:36:40-03:00";
LocalDateTime datetime = LocalDateTime.parse(str, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(str, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
```

Note que a API já possui um `DateTimeFormatter` pronto para fazer parsing do formato que você possui (`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`).

---

Apenas como curiosidade, também é possível construir seu próprio `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
String str = "2018-09-26T10:36:40-03:00";
LocalDateTime datetime = LocalDateTime.parse(str, parser);
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(str, parser);
```

A diferença é que o `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` é mais flexível, pois também faz parsing se a string tiver as frações de segundo, enquanto o `parser` acima só aceita strings no formato especificado.

Note que usei `u` em vez de `y` para o ano, pois o `y` não funciona para datas AC (Antes de Cristo). Como `u` funciona para ambos os casos (AC e DC), acaba sendo a melhor escolha (e este campo é o mesmo usado por `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`, a propósito). Veja [esta resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41178418/540552) para entender melhor os detalhes.

---

Outra diferença é que o `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` não aceita datas inválidas como 31 de abril (pois este mês só tem 30 dias) e 29 de fevereiro em anos não-bissextos. Já usando `ofPattern`, o padrão é aceitar estas datas (e fazer alguns ajustes estranhos). Veja [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/187296/112052) para mais detalhes sobre este comportamento.

Apenas para exemplificar:

```
DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
// 31 de abril
String str = "2018-04-31T10:36:40-03:00";
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse(str, parser)); // 2018-04-30
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse(str, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME)); // DateTimeParseException
```

Usando `ofPattern`, o `DateTimeFormatter` retornado aceita dia 31 de abril, ajustando-o para 30 de abril. Já `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` lança um `DateTimeParseException`, pois a data é inválida.

Para usar `ofPattern` e não aceitar datas inválidas, basta usar a solução sugerida [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/187296/112052):

```
DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX")
    .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);
```

Usando `ResolverStyle.STRICT`, o `DateTimeFormatter` só aceitará datas válidas.