# Converter String para OffSetDateTime (dd 'de' MMMM 'de' yyyy 'às' HH:mm:ss)

Tags: java, data, datetime

Tenho essa String :

> 17 de Outubro de 2008 às 11:35:04

E esse Pattern:

> dd 'de' MMMM 'de' yyyy 'às' HH:mm:ss

E esse código:

```
private OffsetDateTime getData(){
     return Optional.ofNullable(page.<HtmlTableCell>getFirstByXPath(String.format(DOMAIN_XPATH, "Data de Distribuição")))
            .map(HtmlTableCell::asText)
            .map(DATE_TIME_PATTERN::matcher)
            .filter(Matcher::find)
            .map(Matcher::group)
            .map(str -> LocalDateTime.parse(str, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_TIME_PATTERN.toString())).atOffset(ZoneOffset.ofHours(-3)))
            .orElse(null);
}
```

Quero transformar essa data em um `OffsetDateTime` porém usando esse `Pattern` não está funcionando, ele não passa pelo `find()`.

Comment: Atualizei a minha resposta para pegar o mês de Março (faltou a `ç` na expressão regular)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo código, estou assumindo que `DATE_TIME_PATTERN` é um `java.util.regex.Pattern`.

---

Pois bem, o padrão usado em um [`java.util.regex.Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) deve ser uma expressão regular (regex), que é bem diferente do [padrão usado em um `DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns).

A expressão regular serviria para verificar se a string está em determinado formato (como "dois dígitos, seguido de espaço, seguido de várias letras (o mês), etc"). Então ela poderia ser assim: **¹**

```
Pattern DATE_TIME_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\d{2} de [a-zA-Zç]+ de \\d{4}.+\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}");
```

Com isso, você verifica se a `String` está no referido formato:

- `\\d{2}` quer dizer "dois dígitos" e `\\d{4}` quer dizer "quatro dígitos"
- `[a-zA-Zç]+` quer dizer "uma ou mais letras" (incluindo `ç`, para o mês de Março), o que é o suficiente para o nome do mês, já que o `DateTimeFormatter` irá verificar o nome posteriormente
- `.+` é "um ou mais caracteres"

Já para fazer o parsing da data, eu também sugiro setar o [`java.util.Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) para o idioma português, por causa do nome do mês. Se você não especificar um locale, será usado o *default* da JVM, e nem sempre é garantido que seja português:

```
// expressão regular para verificar se a String se parece com uma data no formato que você precisa
Pattern DATE_TIME_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\d{2} de [a-zA-Zç]+ de \\d{4}.+\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}");

// usar o pattern para fazer o parsing da data, com locale em português por causa do nome do mês
DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd 'de' MMMM 'de' uuuu 'às' HH:mm:ss", new Locale("pt", "BR"));

OffsetDateTime odt = Optional.ofNullable("17 de Outubro de 2008 às 11:35:04")
    .map(DATE_TIME_PATTERN::matcher)
    .filter(Matcher::find)
    .map(Matcher::group)
    .map(str ->LocalDateTime.parse(str, parser).atOffset(ZoneOffset.ofHours(-3)))
    .orElse(null);
System.out.println(odt); // 2008-10-17T11:35:04-03:00
```

A data obtida será `2008-10-17T11:35:04-03:00`.

---

**1:** Geralmente expressões regulares para verificar datas válidas [são bem mais complicadas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15504877), já que precisam verificar se o mês possui 28, 29, 30 ou 31 dias, se o ano é bissexto, etc (além de poder ter outras melhorias, como [só aceitar nomes dos meses válidos](https://regex101.com/r/phq00o/1) e por aí vai).

Mas neste caso, estamos usando a regex apenas para extrair um trecho que **parece** uma data (que está no formato indicado, e portanto tem potencial para ser uma data válida), e em seguida validando com `DateTimeFormatter`, então a regex pode ser mantida simples do jeito que está (pois o `parse` já irá verificar todos os detalhes, como o nome do mês, valores válidos para cada campo, etc). Se a data for inválida, o `parse` lançará um `DateTimeParseException`.

---

Você também pode trocar a regex para:

```
Pattern.compile("\\d{2} de [a-zA-Zç]+ de \\d{4} às \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}");
```

Usando `às` diretamente, em vez de `.+`, pois aí só vai aceitar strings que contenham exatamente esses caracteres (já que `.+` é mais abrangente, pois aceita várias ocorrências de qualquer caractere). Enfim, use o que melhor se encaixar nos seus casos de uso.

Se optar pelo `.+`, sugiro também trocar por `.+?`, para o caso de ter mais de uma data na mesma `String`. Exemplo:

```
Pattern DATE_TIME_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\d{2} de [a-zA-Zç]+ de \\d{4}.+\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}");

String s = "17 de Outubro de 2008 às 11:35:04" +
    "  blablabla " +
    "10 de Outubro de 2018 às 10:35:04";
```

Neste caso, toda a string será passada para `parse`, resultando em erro. Isso acontece porque `.+` é [ganancioso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/482807/112052) e tenta pegar o máximo possível de caracteres. Para evitar este comportamento, basta trocar `.+` por `.+?`. O `?` depois do `+` [cancela a ganância](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/401755/112052), fazendo com que somente a primeira data seja pega pela regex e passada para `parse`.

---

**PS**: por padrão, `DateTimeFormatter` faz alguns ajustes para datas como 31 de abril (que [é ajustado para 30 de abril](https://ideone.com/e4NbSu)). Se quiser que ele só aceite datas válidas, pode mudar o `java.time.format.ResolverStyle` para `STRICT`:

```
DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter
    .ofPattern("dd 'de' MMMM 'de' uuuu 'às' HH:mm:ss", new Locale("pt", "BR"))
    .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);
```

Desta forma, o ajuste de 31 de abril não é mais feito, e em vez disso é lançado um `DateTimeParseException`. Para mais detalhes, veja [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/187296/112052).

Se quiser, também é possível fazer um `DateTimeFormatter` *case insensitive*, caso o nome do mês esteja todo em minúsculas (ou maiúsculas). Para isso usamos um `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder`:

```
DateTimeFormatter parser = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .parseCaseInsensitive()
    .appendPattern("dd 'de' MMMM 'de' uuuu 'às' HH:mm:ss")
    .toFormatter(new Locale("pt", "BR"))
    .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);
```

Assim, o nome do mês pode ser tanto "outubro", quanto "Outubro" ou "OUTUBRO".