# Conversão de um formato de data específico não funciona se tentar múltiplos formatos

Tags: java, data, simpledateformat

```
SimpleDateFormat[] formatos = {
            new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy"),
            new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"),
            new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy"),
            new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MM dd")
        };
    SimpleDateFormat formatoSaida = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MM");
    String entradad;
entradad="2018 05 01";
    Date data = null; 
    for (SimpleDateFormat sdf : formatos) {
            try {
                data = sdf.parse(entradad);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
            }
        }
        if (data != null) {
            System.out.println(formatoSaida.format(data));
        } else {
            System.out.println("Não foi possível obter a data");
        }
      }
```

Quando eu digito nesse formato dá certo e o resultado sai `2018 05`, mas quando digito na entrada de dados `"01 05 2018"` o resultado é `0006 11`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que `SimpleDateFormat` é uma classe extremamente leniente, ou seja, ela aceita "praticamente qualquer coisa", e tenta fazer o *parsing* de qualquer maneira. O resultado é que ela não dá erro em muitos casos em que - na minha opinião - deveria. E isso leva a resultados bem [estranhos](https://eyalsch.wordpress.com/2009/05/29/sdf/) e [inesperados](https://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue172-Wonky-Dating.html).

Vamos modificar um pouco seu código para você entender melhor o problema:

```java
SimpleDateFormat[] formatos = {
    new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy"),
    new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"),
    new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy"),
    new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MM dd")
};
SimpleDateFormat formatoSaida = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MM");
String entradad = "01 05 2018";
Date data = null;
for (SimpleDateFormat sdf : formatos) {
    try {
        System.out.print("Usando formato " + sdf.toPattern() + ": ");
        data = sdf.parse(entradad);
        System.out.println(data);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.out.println("Erro");
    }
}
```

Ou seja, para todos os formatos indicados, eu mostro a data obtida, ou erro. O resultado é:

```
Usando formato dd MM yyyy: Tue May 01 00:00:00 BRT 2018
Usando formato dd/MM/yyyy: Erro
Usando formato ddMMyyyy: Mon Dec 01 00:00:00 BRT 4
Usando formato yyyy MM dd: Mon Nov 08 00:00:00 BRT 6
```

Repare que, mesmo que a string `"01 05 2018"` esteja no formato "dia mês ano", três formatos conseguiram fazer o *parsing* e retornar uma data (se é a data correta ou não, aí é outra história - explicada nos links já indicados no primeiro parágrafo).

Note que o último resultado é 8 de novembro do ano 6 (não é 2006 nem 1906, é o ano **6**). O que acontece é que você faz um `for` por todos os formatos, e pega o resultado do último que não deu erro. Por isso que ao formatar esta data usando `yyyy MM` o resultado foi `0006 11`.

A string `"01 05 2018"` se transformar em 8 de novembro de 0006 é um péssimo e indesejado efeito colateral de `SimpleDateFormat`, e de sua natureza leniente (e que nem sempre produz resultados aceitáveis). Ao tentar ser "esperta" e aceitar "qualquer coisa", <opinião>ela acaba mais atrapalhando que ajudando</opinião>.

---

### Então como resolver?

Uma solução é mudar todas as instâncias de `SimpleDateFormat` para não serem lenientes, usando o método `setLenient`:

```java
SimpleDateFormat[] formatos = {
    new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy"),
    new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"),
    new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy"),
    new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MM dd")
};
for (SimpleDateFormat sdf : formatos) {
    sdf.setLenient(false); // agora elas só aceitam strings no formato indicado
}

SimpleDateFormat formatoSaida = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MM");
String entradad = "01 05 2018";
Date data = null;
for (SimpleDateFormat sdf : formatos) {
    try {
        data = sdf.parse(entradad);
        break; // se já deu certo, não tem porque tentar com os outros
    } catch (ParseException e) {
    }
}
if (data != null) {
    System.out.println(formatoSaida.format(data));
} else {
    System.out.println("Não foi possível obter a data");
}
```

Assim, ele passa a não aceitar "qualquer coisa", e só faz o *parsing* se a string tiver exatamente o formato indicado.

---

### Java >= 8

A partir do Java 8 você pode usar a [API `java.time`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/112052), que possui a classe `DateTimeFormatter`, que ao contrário de `SimpleDateFormat`, não é leniente por padrão. Além disso, ela possui suporte a múltiplos formatos:

```java
DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[dd MM uuuu][dd/MM/uuuu][ddMMuuuu][uuuu MM dd]")
        .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);
DateTimeFormatter formatoSaida = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu MM");
String entrada = "01 05 2018";
try {
    // se for **somente** para converter para outro formato, faça-o diretamente
    System.out.println(formatoSaida.format(parser.parse(entrada)));
} catch(DateTimeParseException e) {
    System.out.println("Não foi possível obter a data");
}
```

Os colchetes indicam um trecho opcional. Sendo assim, o *pattern* acima aceita qualquer um dos 4 formatos indicados.

O código acima faz o *parsing* e já passa para o outro `DateTimeFormatter` formatar. Se a ideia é **somente** alterar o formato para "ano mês", isso é o suficiente.

Mas se quiser obter uma data, você pode criar um `java.time.LocalDate` (me parece a classe mais adequada, já que a string inicial tem apenas dia, mês e ano - o `java.time` possui [várias classes diferentes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html) para os mais variados casos de uso):

```java
DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[dd MM uuuu][dd/MM/uuuu][ddMMuuuu][uuuu MM dd]")
        .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);
DateTimeFormatter formatoSaida = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu MM");
String entrada = "01 05 2018";
// se quiser criar a data para usar depois
LocalDate data = null;
try {
    data = LocalDate.parse(entrada, parser);
} catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
    System.out.println("Não foi possível obter a data");
}
if (data != null) {
    System.out.println(formatoSaida.format(data));
    // continuar usando a data, etc...
}
```

---

Obs: o `ResolverStyle.STRICT` é para não aceitar datas como 31 de abril, que é ajustado para dia 30, entre outros (mais detalhes [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/187296/112052)). Quanto a usar `uuuu` em vez de `yyyy` para o ano, veja [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41178418).

Comment: Resposta muito boa cara, tá de parabéns.