# Testar data de pelo menos um dia anterior

Tags: java, calendar

Sistema que controla Ordens de Serviço, no momento que eu abro uma nova chamada de ordem de serviço eu fecho a ordem anterior. 
Caso a ordem de serviço anterior tenha sido aberta em uma data anterior(pelo menos um dia atras) eu fecho ela no final do expediente da data anterior e abro a nova no inicio do expediente do dia atual.

O que estou querendo com isso, uma forma de saber se a data em questão é de pelo menos um dia anterior. Pensei em testar a diferença de horas entre o fim do expediente do dia anterior com o inicio do expediente do dia atual, mas não me parece uma solução boa.

Fiz um teste com calendar da seguinte forma:

```java
Calendar diaAnterior = DATA_HORA_INICIAL_OS;
diaAnterior.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
  if (DATA_HORA_ATUAL.get(Calendar.DATE) >= diaAnterior.get(Calendar.DATE)) {
    return true;
  }
return false;
```

Porem desta forma ele apenas testa o dia em questão e caso tenha sido aberta o dia 30 do mês e hoje é dia 1, o método me retornara uma informação inválida, ou caso tenha saído de férias e voltado no inicio do mês, aconteceria o mesmo erro.

Então, como posso testar se a data da abertura da ordem de serviço é no minimo do dia anterior?

Comment: Aproveitando a oportunidade, deixo-lhe uma recomendação para usar a [nova API de datas](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/28595), que é mais eficiente.

Comment: Poh! Valeu cara, realmente não tinha conhecimento dessa API, vou dar uma olhada. Problema pra mim que o Java 8 não aceita mais o Windows XP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zerando os atributos de horas, você terá exatamente a meia-noite de hoje. Com isto, você pode verificar se a data do parâmetro é anterior a hoje.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calendar dataOrdem = Calendar.getInstance();
    // coloca a data em 31/03
    dataOrdem.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 31);
    dataOrdem.set(Calendar.MONTH, 2); // 2 = março

    System.out.println(testarDiaAnterior(dataOrdem));

  }

  private static boolean testarDiaAnterior(Calendar dataOrdem){
    Calendar hoje = Calendar.getInstance();
    hoje.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
    hoje.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    hoje.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    hoje.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    return hoje.after(dataOrdem);
  }
```

Obs.: Você também pode utilizar o método before:

```
return dataOrdem.before(hoje);
```

Mas, por se tratar de um parâmetro, em algum momento o método poderá receber nulo.

Comment: Olá, poderia explicar o código?

Comment: zerando os atributos de horas você terá exatamente a meia-noite de hoje. Com isto, se hoje a meia-noite for depois da data passada por parâmetro, significa que a data é anterior.

Comment: Jefferson coloca na resposta, é mais fácil. Clique no botão `editar` para editar a resposta. Aproveite e faça um [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aprender mais a respeito do site.

Comment: @gato resposta alterada. Obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Faz muito sentido, obrigado