# Como obter e formatar data e hora atual?

Tags: java, data, formatação

Gostaria de saber como faço para obter a data e a hora atual e então formatar elas em JAVA.

Por exemplo, tenho esses dois valores:

```
23062017 
212010
```

Quero armazenar cada valor em uma variável, e depois quero formatá-las desse jeito:

```
23/06/2017 
21:20:10
```

Answer (score 7):

Para recuperar a data e hora atuais do sistema você pode fazer:

```
Date dataHoraAtual = new Date();
String data = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(dataHoraAtual);
String hora = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(dataHoraAtual);
```

Dessa forma você receberá a data e hora nos formatos que deseja e em variáveis separadas.

---

Para referência, no [meu GitHub](https://github.com/igorventurelli/bilac/blob/master/2017-1/ProgamacaoParaWeb/14_JAVA/1/bilac-servlet/src/br/com/igorventurelli/bilac/controller/DateServlet.java#L55) tem uma classe (um Servlet) que fiz para um trabalho da faculdade que retorna a data e hora.

Comment: boa resposta, mas não aponte links externos, de preferência por copiar o conteúdo aqui e apenas referenciar a fonte original ...

Comment: @pmargreff mas está como referencia. Inclusive escrevi exatamente: "Para referência". A resposta é o que está em cima da linha horizontal ._.

Answer (score 6):

<sup>*No título da pergunta é mencionado "data e hora atual", mas no corpo da pergunta são mencionados valores específicos. De qualquer forma, segue uma solução para ambos.*</sup>

---

As outras respostas usam [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), mas a partir do Java 8, você pode usar a [API `java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). [Nesta API](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/112052), há classes para manipular apenas a data, ou apenas a hora, que parece ser o que você precisa.

Para ler as `Strings` mencionadas, você pode usar um [`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), que transforma a `String` no tipo correspondente ([`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) para datas, ou [`java.time.LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) para horas).

Depois, eu uso outro `DateTimeFormatter` para formatá-las (converter para o outro formato):

```
// converter 23062017 para 23/06/2017
DateTimeFormatter parserData = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMuuuu");
LocalDate data = LocalDate.parse("23062017", parserData);
DateTimeFormatter formatterData = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu");
String dataFormatada = formatterData.format(data); // 23/06/2017

// converter 212010 para 21:20:10
DateTimeFormatter parserHora= DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HHmmss");
LocalTime hora = LocalTime.parse("212010", parserHora);
DateTimeFormatter formatterHora = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
String horaFormatada = formatterHora.format(hora); // 21:20:10
```

Caso queira usar a data e hora atual, você pode usar um [`java.time.LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) (que já possui ambas as informações) e formatá-lo:

```
// data/hora atual
LocalDateTime agora = LocalDateTime.now();

// formatar a data
DateTimeFormatter formatterData = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu");
String dataFormatada = formatterData.format(agora);

// formatar a hora
DateTimeFormatter formatterHora = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
String horaFormatada = formatterHora.format(agora);
```

Repare também que no `java.time` é possível usar `u` em vez de `y` para o ano. A diferença é que o `y` não funciona para datas AC (Antes de Cristo). Como `u` funciona para ambos os casos (AC e DC), acaba sendo a melhor escolha. Veja [esta resposta do SOen](http://Note%20que%20usei%20u%20em%20vez%20de%20y%20para%20o%20ano,%20pois%20o%20y%20n%C3%A3o%20funciona%20para%20datas%20AC%20(Antes%20de%20Cristo).%20Como%20u%20funciona%20para%20ambos%20os%20casos%20(AC%20e%20DC),%20acaba%20sendo%20a%20melhor%20escolha%20(e%20este%20campo%20%C3%A9%20o%20mesmo%20usado%20por%20DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME,%20a%20prop%C3%B3sito).%20Veja%20esta%20resposta%20do%20SOen%20para%20entender%20melhor%20os%20detalhes.) para entender melhor os detalhes.

---

Se você ainda não usa Java 8, pode usar o [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), que possui as mesmas classes já mencionadas e funciona basicamente do mesmo jeito. A diferença é que elas estão no pacote `org.threeten.bp` (ao invés de `java.time`).

O backport é compatível com JDK 6 e 7.

Se você puder usar esta API ao invés de `Date` e `SimpleDateFormat`, faça-o. A nova API é muito superior e corrige vários dos [problemas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1571265) existentes [na API antiga](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1969442).

---

Se você por algum motivo estiver preso ao Java 5, não é possível usar o ThreeTen Backport. Mas se quiser usar uma API melhor que `Date` e `SimpleDateFormat`, uma opção é usar o [Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/). Ela é bem parecida com o `java.time` (pois é a sua predecessora, e ambas foram feitas [pela mesma pessoa](https://blog.joda.org/)), apesar de [haver algumas diferenças entre elas](https://blog.joda.org/2009/11/why-jsr-310-isn-joda-time_4941.html).

Mas a ideia é essencialmente a mesma, veja como converter as suas strings para uma data e hora no formato desejado:

```
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;
import org.joda.time.LocalTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

// converter 23062017 para 23/06/2017
DateTimeFormatter parserData = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("ddMMyyyy");
LocalDate data = LocalDate.parse("23062017", parserData);
DateTimeFormatter formatterData = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
String dataFormatada = formatterData.print(data);
System.out.println(dataFormatada); // 23/06/2017

// converter 212010 para 21:20:10
DateTimeFormatter parserHora = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HHmmss");
LocalTime hora = LocalTime.parse("212010", parserHora);
DateTimeFormatter formatterHora = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm:ss");
String horaFormatada = formatterHora.print(hora);
System.out.println(horaFormatada); // 21:20:10
```

A ideia é a mesma: usar um [`org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) para converter as strings para um [`org.joda.time.LocalDate`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) (representando a data - apenas o dia, mês e ano) e para um [`org.joda.time.LocalTime`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html) (um horário).

Em seguida, uso outro `DateTimeFormatter` para converter o `LocalDate` e o `LocalTime` para outro formato. Uma diferença para o `java.time` é que nas classes do Joda-Time também é possível usar `toString()` com o formato desejado:

```
System.out.println(data.toString("dd/MM/yyyy")); // 23/06/2017
System.out.println(hora.toString("HH:mm:ss")); // 21:20:10
```

E para obter a data/hora atual, pode-se construir um [`org.joda.time.LocalDateTime`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDateTime.html), que já possui tanto a data quanto a hora, e a partir daí imprime-se nos 2 formatos:

```
LocalDateTime dataHoraAtual = new LocalDateTime();
System.out.println(dataHoraAtual.toString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
System.out.println(dataHoraAtual.toString("HH:mm:ss"));
```

Só lembrando que o Joda-Time é uma alternativa para o JDK 5, já que no seu próprio site [há um aviso](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/#Support) dizendo que esta API é um projeto "encerrado", não há melhorias previstas e por fim recomenda o uso do `java.time` (ou seja, o ThreeTen Backport para JDK 6 e 7, e `java.time` para JDK >= 8).

---

Isso não invalida as demais respostas que usam `SimpleDateFormat` e `Date`. Se não tiver como usar o Java >= 8, ou não houver possibilidade de adicionar uma biblioteca como o ThreeTen Backport ou o Joda-Time, a API legada continua sendo uma opção válida.

Answer (score 1):

Neste exemplo gera duas strings dia e hora, com o formato para dia 02-03-2018 e string hora 22:21:30

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();//cria o obj calendar e atribui a hora e data do sistema
Date data = calendar.getTime();//transforma o obj calendar em obj Date

SimpleDateFormat sddia = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");//cria um obj de formatação de data
SimpleDateFormat sdhora = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");//cria um obj de formatação de hora
String dia = sddia.format(data);//gera a string final formatada no estilo "dd-MM-yyyy"
String hora = sdhora.format(data);//gera a string final formatada no estilo "HH:mm:ss"
```

Comment: Só um detalhe, para obter a data atual, é mais simples fazer `Date data = new Date()`. Criar um `Calendar` **só** pra isso é desnecessário, pois `new Date()` já obtém a data e hora atual do sistema :-)

Answer (score 1):

Opa, blza!?

É possível obter a data atual das APIs clássicas (`Date`), e também pelas novas APIs de data e hora do java 8 (`LocalDateTime` e `LocalDate`).

> **API clássica**
>
> para o `java.util.Date`:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Date date = new Date();
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date)); //01/02/2019 14:08:43
```

> **Java 8+**
>
> para o `java.time.LocalDateTime`:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
System.out.println(dtf.format(now)); //01/02/2019 14:08:43
```

> para o `java.time.LocalDate`:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
System.out.println(dtf.format(localDate)); //01/02/2019
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String dataAtualFormatada = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
                                    .format(System.currentTimeMillis());

    //Seta valores da data
    String dataString = dataAtualFormatada.substring(0,10);

    //Seta valores do horário
    String horario = dataAtualFormatada.substring(11,19);     

}
```