# Como salvar um localdate numa tabela mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, data, java-8

Tenho uma tabela livro que tem uma coluna do tipo "Date" e no meu código java tenho um campo do tipo "localdate". Eu preciso salvar os dados do campo "LocalDate" na tabela porém estou encontrando dificuldades para fazer isso, alguma sugestão?

Java:

```
package servico;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import model.Livro;


public class LivroService {
    private List<Livro> listaLivros;
    SimpleDateFormat sdt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

    public LivroService() {
        listaLivros = new ArrayList<>();
        listaLivros.add(new Livro(1,123456,"Harry Potter","J.K Rowling","HP",sdt.format("12-10-2015")));
    }

}
```

Comment: Pergunta relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/132

Comment: @VictorStafusa obrigado por responder porém  eu até sei fazer a conversão, o que eu não sei como salvar no bd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você consegue usando o `sql.Date` gerar um `util.Date` a partir de um `LocalDate`:

```java
java.util.Date date = java.sql.Date.valueOf(localDate);
```

E para fazer a operação reversa utiliza-se o método `toLocalDate` da classe `java.sql.Date`

```java
LocalDate ld = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime()).toLocalDate();
```

Traduzido de: [en.stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33066904/localdate-to-java-util-date-and-vice-versa-simpliest-conversion)

---

### EDIT:

Para gerar uma `LocalDate` a partir de uma `String`

```java
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
LocalDate seuLocalDate = dtf.parseLocalDate("25-06-2017");

//sua implementação
listaLivros.add(new Livro(1,123456,"Harry Potter","J.K Rowling","HP", seuLocalDate));
```

Para tornar um `java.sql.Date` a partir de uma `String` você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```java
String string = "25-06-2017";
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
Date date = format.parse(string);
System.out.println(date);
```

Se você está tentando salvar um `sql.Date` dentro do seu `ArrayList` a partir de uma `String`, use o método `parse` da classe `DateFormat`, pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```java
public class LivroService {

    private List<Livro> listaLivros;
    SimpleDateFormat sdt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

    public LivroService() {
        listaLivros = new ArrayList<>();
        listaLivros.add(new Livro(1,123456,"Harry Potter","J.K Rowling","HP",sdt.parse("12-10-2015")));
    }

}
```

Comment: Eu tentei fazer de acordo com a tua sugestão porém não deu muito certo.

`java.util.Date date = java.sql.Date.valueOf("12-10-2015");` e depois fiz isso `listaLivros.add(new Livro(1,123456,"Harry Potter","J.K Rowling","HP",date));` depois disso ele pede para criar um construtor que não faz sentido nenhum

Comment: Fiz uma edição em minha resposta adicionando como pegar um `sql.Date` a partir de uma `String`, que a principio é o que você esta tentando fazer

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo!