# Converter java.util.date para java.sql.Date

Tags: java, android, data

Com esta linha de código conseguirei passar `java.util.Date` para `java.sql.Date`?

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf(String.valueOf(date));
```

Tendo em conta que date esta neste formato :

```
Sat Jul 01 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2017
```

Comment: date é tipo java.util.Date?

Comment: Sim é , mas ta me dando um erro se calhar é onde estou usando este parâmetro  esta variável sqlDate, que esta com problemas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se a variável `date` for um tipo `java.util.Date`, basta apenas:

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
```

Agora se for converter uma data em string para `sql.Date`, somente será possível se estiver no formato `yyyy-[m]m-[d]d`, onde o mês e o dia podem conter apenas um dígito se o segundo for zero, como em `2017-05-01`, que pode ser passado como  `2017-5-1`.

Porém, caso seja possível, recomendo utilizar [Joda Time](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/177130/28595) que torna operações com datas e periodos no tempo mais flexíveis.

**Referência:**

- [documentação da classe sql.Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html)

Comment: Esse date.getTime() vai passa-la para dd-mm-yyyy?

Comment: @PedroGouveia, não, ele retorna uma representação de data em milissegundos do tipo `long`, que é o intervalo desde 01 de janeiro de 1970 as 00:00:00 até a data da variável.

Comment: Como posso fazer para que ao invés do sqlDate ficar , imagine 2017-01-01 fique 01-01-2017 ?

Comment: Não tem como, sesse formato é padrão da maioria dos bancos de dados para coluna de data. Aí você precisa consultar seu banco de dados e ver se tem algo assim.

Comment: Meu banco de dados tem no formato dd-mm-yyyy porque penso que esse o formato normal para mostrar aos users

Comment: @PedroGouveia seus users acessam seu banco de dados diretamente? Pois o que geralmente se faz é salvar nesse formato padrão e quando for recuperar a data via consulta, formatar ela para `dd/mm/yyyy` antes de apresentar ao usuário.

Comment: Downvoter, se o voto foi por algum problema na resposta, favor informar, senão de nada adianta negativar se o erro continuar, pois eu não percebi erro algum na resposta.

Comment: Eu dei upVote meti certo !