# Setar um jDateChooser

Tags: java, jdatechooser

Estou com um problema para fazer o `insert` lá no banco PostgreSQL. O código aparentemente está ok mas na hora de compilar da erro.
O erro é referente ao tipo de dado que tento inserir no banco. O erro que dá é:

> error: incompatible types: java.util.Date cannot be converted to java.sql.Date

Este erro aparece para todas as linhas de inserção de data.

```
modeloIntenrnacao.setDtAdmisPlano((jDateChooserDtAdmissPlano.getDate()));

modeloIntenrnacao.setNome(jTextFieldNomePaciente.getText());
modeloIntenrnacao.setMatricula(Integer.parseInt(jTextFieldMatricula.getText())); 
modeloIntenrnacao.setDtAdmisPlano((jDateChooserDtAdmissPlano.getDate()));
modeloIntenrnacao.setHospOrig(jTextFieldHospOrig.getText());

modeloIntenrnacao.setId(jTextFieldId.getText());
modeloIntenrnacao.setIndicacao(jTextFieldindicacao.getText());
modeloIntenrnacao.setTipoInternac((String)jComboBoxTpInterna.getSelectedItem() );
modeloIntenrnacao.setTipoLeito((String)jComboBoxTpLeito.getSelectedItem());
modeloIntenrnacao.setIdadeAprox(Integer.parseInt(jTextFieldIdadeAprox.getText()));
modeloIntenrnacao.setDataInternac((jDateChooserdDtInternac.getDate()));
modeloIntenrnacao.setDataPrevAlta((jDateChooserdInterAlt.getDate()));
modeloIntenrnacao.setObservacoes(jTextAreaObservacoes.getText());
modeloIntenrnacao.setIdCodInternac(Integer.parseInt(jTextFieldIdInternacao.getText()));
controleInterna.salvaFormInternac(modeloIntenrnacao);
```

Comment: Acesse o link para aprender a fazer um **[mcve]** e edite a pergunta adicionando-o para que seja possivel te ajudar.

Comment: Possível duplicata de: [Converter java.util.date para java.sql.Date](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220170/28595)

Answer (score 2):

O erro acontece porque o `JDateChooser` trabalha com `util.Date` como tipo de data, e persistência de banco de dados em java sempre utiliza `sql.Date`. Embora a segunda estenda a primeira, não é garantido que todo tipo `util.Date` seja um tipo `sql.Date`, o que justifica o erro. Você precisa converter um tipo para outro antes de salvar no seu banco de dados. [Nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/220173/28595) mostra como converter de um tipo pra outro.

É importante salientar que o java provê de classes mais novas e otimizadas para manipular datas, caso se interesse, recomendo que leie [Como migrar de Date e Calendar para a nova API de datas no Java 8?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/28595)

Comment: "*não é garantido que todo tipo `sql.Date` seja um tipo `sql.Date`*" - Acho que você se confundiu aqui.

Comment: @VictorStafusa é tanto Date que java tem agora que até me confundir xD