# Saber quantos anos, meses, dias, horas, etc se passaram desde uma determinada data

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, data

Eu gostaria de saber como faço com que o output da diferença entre duas datas fique da maneira que eu quero, neste caso gostaria que fosse:

> Desde 16 - 07 - 2014 23:00:00 passaram: X anos, Y meses, K dias, Z horas, W minutos, S secs

O que eu tenho:

```
import datetime
d1 = datetime.datetime(2014,7,16,23)
d2 = datetime.datetime.now()

diff = d2 - d1

print(diff) # este não é o output que quero.
```

Comment: E qual seria exatamente a saída esperada? `3-0-12 15:3:35`? Isso não faz nenhum pouco de sentido.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, exato o formato seria qualquer coisa como: X anos, Y meses, K dias, Z horas, W minutos, S secs. Vou corrigir acima na pergunta, erro meu

Comment: Algo assim? http://ideone.com/3zmzN9

Comment: Exato @AndersonCarlosWoss, será que há alguma maneira de ter mais precisão? Por exemplo meses de 31 dias e/ou anos bisextos... Mas sim é isso mesmo

Comment: Tem como, mas o trabalho será bem maior, a ideia é a mesma que eu usei. E não é uma redeclaração da variável, apenas a atualização do seu valor. Quando eu calculo o número de horas, é preciso descontar esse total do número de segundos para não ser considerado duas vezes.

Comment: Obrigado @AndersonCarlosWoss, pode responder que a sua solução é a correta, irei aceitar pois me ajudou. Obrigado

Answer (score 8, accepted):

De forma bem simplificada você pode fazer:

```
import datetime
 
d1 = datetime.datetime(2014,7,16,23)
d2 = datetime.datetime.now()
 
diff = d2 - d1
 
days = diff.days
years, days = divmod(days, 365)
months, days = divmod(days, 30)
 
seconds = diff.seconds
hours, seconds = divmod(seconds, 3600)
minutes, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)
 
print(f"Desde {d1} passaram {years} anos, {months} meses, {days} dias, {hours} horas, {minutes} minutos e {seconds} segundos")
```

No objeto `diff` teremos a diferença entre as datas. Pelo atributo `day` e `seconds` pegamos esta diferença em relação ao número de dias e segundos, respectivamente. Para saber a quantidade de anos, calculamos a divisão inteira entre a quantidade de dias por 365 e atualizamos o valor de `days` para descontar a quantia relativa a esses anos. Com o mês, calculamos a divisão por 30 e atualizamos novamente a quantidade de dias.

Para as horas e minutos a lógica é exatamente a mesma, dividindo o número de segundos por 3600 e 60, respectivamente.

Vale lembrar que esta diferença é aproximada, pois não leva em considerações ano bissextos dentro do intervalo considerado, nem a quantidade exata de dias em cada mês.

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/3zmzN9).

Answer (score 4):

Uma opção é instalar o [módulo `dateutil`](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/) (`pip install python-dateutil`) e usar um [`relativedelta`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html), que calcula a diferença entre dois `datetime`'s da forma que você deseja:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

d1 = datetime(2014, 7, 16, 23)
d2 = datetime(2019, 5, 10, 17, 30, 45)
# diferença entre d1 e d2
diff = relativedelta(d2, d1)
print("{} anos, {} meses, {} dias, {} horas, {} minutos, {} segundos"
       .format(diff.years, diff.months, diff.days, diff.hours, diff.minutes, diff.seconds))
# a partir do Python 3.6, é possível usar f-strings
print(f"{diff.years} anos, {diff.months} meses, {diff.days} dias, {diff.hours} horas, {diff.minutes} minutos, {diff.seconds} segundos")
```

O resultado é um objeto que possui a diferença devidamente "quebrada" em campos, da forma que você precisa. A saída é:

> 4 anos, 9 meses, 23 dias, 18 horas, 30 minutos, 45 segundos

---

## Aritmética de datas não é óbvia

Vale lembrar que [aritmética de datas não é nada óbvia, e muitas vezes é bem contra-intuitiva](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/12/01/the-joys-of-date-time-arithmetic/). A [diferença em anos e meses](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/370227/112052), por exemplo, pode ter vários casos cujos resultados variam conforme as datas envolvidas.

Por exemplo, a diferença entre 1 de janeiro e 1 de fevereiro é de 1 mês, assim como a diferença entre 1 de fevereiro e 1 de março:

```
# diferença entre 1 de janeiro e 1 de fevereiro
print(relativedelta(datetime(2019, 2, 1), datetime(2019, 1, 1)))
# diferença entre 1 de fevereiro e 1 de março
print(relativedelta(datetime(2019, 3, 1), datetime(2019, 2, 1)))
```

Ambos resultam em um `relativedelta` de 1 mês, e o código acima imprime duas vezes a mesma coisa:

> relativedelta(months=+1)

Mesmo que entre 01/01/2019 e 01/02/2019 tenha 31 dias, e entre 01/02/2019 e 01/03/2019 tenha 28 dias, o `relativedelta` considera que em ambos os casos a diferença é de 1 mês. Isso acontece porque meses possuem tamanhos variados e a diferença equivalente em dias pode variar de acordo com as datas envolvidas.

---

Outro exemplo, a diferença entre 28, 29, 30 ou 31 de janeiro e 28 de fevereiro de 2019:

```
d2 = datetime(2019, 2, 28)
print(relativedelta(d2, datetime(2019, 1, 28)))
print(relativedelta(d2, datetime(2019, 1, 29)))
print(relativedelta(d2, datetime(2019, 1, 30)))
print(relativedelta(d2, datetime(2019, 1, 31)))
```

Em todos os casos acima, a diferença é de exatamente um mês. O código acima imprime 4 vezes o mesmo `relativedelta`:

> relativedelta(months=+1)

Isso acontece porque os meses podem ter 28, 29, 30 ou 31 dias. Se eu somar 1 mês a 31 de janeiro de 2019, o resultado *deveria* ser 31 de fevereiro de 2019. Mas como fevereiro não tem 31 dias, este valor é ajustado para 28 de fevereiro:

```
print(datetime(2019, 2, 28) + relativedelta(month=1)) # 2019-01-28 00:00:00
```

<sup>*Nem todas as API's/linguagens fazem este ajuste. No JavaScript, por exemplo, [o resultado é uma data em março](https://hkotsubo.github.io/blog/2019-04-09/nao-reinvente-a-roda-2-como-somar-meses-e-anos-a-uma-data#javascript)*.</sup>

O mesmo ocorre se eu somar 1 mês a 28, 29 e 30 de janeiro de 2019: o resultado é 28 fevereiro de 2019. Por isso, a diferença entre as datas mostrada acima é sempre 1 mês.

---

Vale lembrar que os casos acima dão exatamente 1 mês porque não foi definido um horário para cada `datetime` (e por padrão ele é setado para meia-noite, o que quer dizer que todas as datas acima possuem o horário igual a meia-noite). Mas se setarmos um horário nas datas:

```
d2 = datetime(2019, 2, 28)
print(relativedelta(d2, datetime(2019, 1, 28, 10, 30)))
print(relativedelta(d2, datetime(2019, 1, 29, 10, 30)))
print(relativedelta(d2, datetime(2019, 1, 30, 10, 30)))
print(relativedelta(d2, datetime(2019, 1, 31, 10, 30)))
```

No caso, eu setei o horário de 10:30 na data inicial, mas na data final eu mantive o *default* (meia-noite). Isso quer dizer que, como ainda não chegou as 10:30 do dia 28/02, ainda não se completou um mês (pois o `relativedelta` também leva em conta o horário). Por isso a diferença não é mais de 1 mês, e a saída é:

```
relativedelta(days=+30, hours=+13, minutes=+30)
relativedelta(days=+29, hours=+13, minutes=+30)
relativedelta(days=+28, hours=+13, minutes=+30)
relativedelta(days=+27, hours=+13, minutes=+30)
```

---

Há também o caso da diferença em anos, quando há anos bissextos envolvidos. Por exemplo, qual a diferença entre 29/02/2016 e 28/02/2017?

```
print(relativedelta(datetime(2017, 2, 28), datetime(2016, 2, 29)))
```

Neste caso, a diferença é de 1 ano:

> relativedelta(years=+1)

Isso é uma escolha de implementação da API, e pode variar de uma linguagem para outra. No Java >= 8, na [API `java.time`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/112052), por exemplo, [a diferença entre essas datas é de zero anos](https://ideone.com/fbsDJO), pois a API entende que somente a partir de 29/02 é que completa 1 ano (e nesse caso, como não é ano bissexto, somente de 01/03 em diante é considerado que se passou 1 ano).

Qual das APIs está certa? Ambas, pois não existe uma regra definitiva para aritmética de datas (tal como existe na matemática). Isso porque meses e anos não têm tamanhos fixos (meses podem ter de 28 a 31 dias, anos podem ter 365 ou 366 dias), e as diferenças sempre dependem das datas envolvidas. Na matemática uma centena sempre tem 10 dezenas, mas na aritmética de datas podemos ter "uma centena com 10 ou 11 dezenas" (seja um mês com 28, 29, 30 ou 31 dias, ou um ano com 365 ou 366 dias), dependendo do caso.

No caso do ano bissexto, basta pensar em alguém que nasceu em 29/02/2016. Em 28/02/2017, já poderíamos considerar que esta pessoa tem 1 ano de idade? Ou somente em 01/03/2017? O `relativedelta` entende que em 28/02/2017 já se passou 1 ano, o `java.time` entende que não.

Nesse caso, não existe resposta certa: o que temos são decisões de implementação, e cabe a você saber como funciona a API que está usando, e caso queira resultados diferentes, fazer os ajustes necessários manualmente.