# Contar a quantidade de meses entre uma data e outra

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, data

Eu gostaria de contar a quantidade de meses entre uma data e outra.

Vou deixar um exemplo, o que eu quero é basicamente só um contador mesmo.

Ex: quantidade de meses entre 05/02/2018 até hoje (21/03/2019)

Comment: se a data for 28/02/2019, quer que o resultado seja 1 mês ou 0?

Comment: nesse caso seria 0 mesmo

Comment: Quantidade de meses entre 05/02/2018 até hoje (21/03/2019). qual é o resultado? 13 ou 12

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Antes é preciso entender dois conceitos importantes:

- uma **data** é um ponto específico do calendário. Ex: hoje é 21/03/2019 (dia 21 do mês de março do ano de 2019)
- uma **duração** é uma quantidade de tempo. Ex: morei na cidade X por 3 anos e 5 meses (não disse em que data comecei a morar, é apenas a quantidade de tempo, sem nenhuma relação com calendários)

Ambas podem até usar as mesmas palavras (dias, meses, anos etc), mas são conceitos diferentes.

Uma das respostas está obtendo uma duração (o [`TimeSpan`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netframework-4.7.2)) e usando-a para criar outra data ([`DateTime`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netframework-4.7.2)), o que não faz sentido: o [`DateTime` representa uma data, e o `TimeSpan` representa uma duração](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netframework-4.7.2#datetime-vs-timespan). Ponto.

É claro que os conceitos estão relacionados: se eu tiver duas datas (instâncias de `DateTime`) e calcular a diferença entre elas, o resultado será a quantidade de tempo entre essas datas (ou seja, um `TimeSpan`).

---

Enfim, para calcular a diferença de meses entre duas datas, vai depender do seu critério para considerar o que é um "mês".

O método mais direto para calcular a diferença entre datas é:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2018, 2, 5);
TimeSpan difference = DateTime.Now - date;
Console.WriteLine(difference.TotalDays);
```

[`TotalDays`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.totaldays?view=netframework-4.7.2) retorna a diferença em dias, incluindo as casas decimais (já que leva em conta o horário atual também). Rodando agora, eu obtive `409.804892438586`. Se quiser, pode usar também [`difference.Days`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.days?view=netframework-4.7.2), que retorna o valor como um inteiro (`409`).

Mas 409 dias são quantos meses?

> "Ah, é só dividir por 30, dá 13 meses"

Na verdade depende. Meses têm tamanhos variados, podendo ter 28, 29, 30 ou 31 dias, e nem sempre a conta é tão simples assim.

Por exemplo, entre 01/01/2019 e 01/02/2019 há 31 dias. Dividindo por 30 e arredondando, dá 1 mês.

Mas entre 01/02/2019 e 01/03/2019 há 28 dias. Dividindo por 30, dá 0,93: se arredondar pra baixo, dá zero meses. Mas entre 1 de fevereiro e 1 de março a diferença não é de um mês? Então devemos arredondar pra cima nesse caso?

Mas e se fosse entre 01/01/2019 e 29/01/2019, a diferença também é de 28 dias. Só que entre 1 de janeiro e 29 de janeiro ainda não se passou 1 mês, então eu não posso arredondar pra cima nesse caso. *"Ah, então eu só arredondo pra cima se não estiver no mesmo mês".*

Aí você vê que entre 01/01/2019 e 27/02/2019 a diferença é de 57 dias, que dividido por 30 dá 1,9. Se arredondar pra cima dá 2, mas entre 1 de janeiro e 27 de fevereiro ainda não se passaram dois meses. E agora?

Dividir por 30 (ou por qualquer outro valor "médio" arbitrário) sempre terá esse problema. Isso acontece porque meses têm tamanhos variados e a quantidade exata de meses equivalente aos dias **vai depender das datas envolvidas**.

Aritmética de datas [não é nada óbvia, e muitas vezes é contra-intuitiva](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/12/01/the-joys-of-date-time-arithmetic/). Não é que nem na matemática, onde 10 unidades sempre são uma dezena, 10 dezenas são uma centena, etc. Com datas, podemos ter "uma dezena que não tem 10 unidades" (como um mês que pode não ter exatamente 30 dias, ou um ano que pode ter 366 dias). Por isso não existe **a** regra correta para isso, cabe a você escolher uma forma de calcular essas diferenças.

---

Se quiser, você pode fazer um cálculo considerando apenas o mês e ano:

```
static int ajustaMesAno(DateTime d) {
    return d.Year * 12 + d.Month;
}

DateTime date = new DateTime(2018, 2, 5);
int mesesDiff = ajustaMesAno(DateTime.Now) - ajustaMesAno(date);
Console.WriteLine(mesesDiff);
```

Considerando que `DateTime.Now` retorna a data de 21/03/2019, o código acima calcula a diferença em meses entre 05/02/2018 e 21/03/2019, e o resultado é 13.

Mas e se a data inicial for 22/02/2018? Você vai considerar que a diferença é 12 meses (pois só no dia 22/03/2019 é que completará o décimo terceiro mês) ou de 13 meses (porque só interessa o mês, independente do dia)?

Se quiser considerar que são 12 meses porque só depois do dia 22/03 é que completa o mês, basta incluir o ajuste:

```
DateTime inicio = new DateTime(2018, 2, 22);
DateTime fim = new DateTime(2019, 3, 21);
int mesesDiff = ajustaMesAno(fim) - ajustaMesAno(inicio);
if (inicio.Day > fim.Day) {
    mesesDiff--;
}
Console.WriteLine(mesesDiff); // 12
```

No exemplo acima eu usei a data final como 21/03/2019 para fins didáticos (para que o resultado seja 12), mas você pode trocar por `DateTime.Now` para usar a data atual.

---

#### Não confunda `DateTime` com `TimeSpan`

Apenas para explicar porque o que [uma das respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/370220/112052) sugeriu não é o correto.

Primeiro ela calcula a diferença entre as datas e obtém o `TimeSpan`. **Até aqui OK**:

```
DateTime inicio = new DateTime(2018, 03, 21);
DateTime fim = new DateTime(2019, 03, 21);
TimeSpan ts = fim.Subtract(inicio); // 365.00:00:00
```

Se você imprimir o `TimeSpan`, será mostrado "365.00:00:00" (uma duração de 365 dias, zero horas, zero minutos e zero segundos, ou seja, exatos 365 dias).

Depois - e **esta é a parte errada** - ela usa o valor de [`Ticks`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.ticks?view=netframework-4.7.2) para criar outro `DateTime` (adicionei um `WriteLine` para vermos o resultado):

```
DateTime periodo = new DateTime(ts.Ticks);
Console.WriteLine(periodo); // 1/1/0002 12:00:00 AM
```

Só que `Ticks` retorna a quantidade de *ticks*. Segundo a [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks), um *tick* corresponde a um intervalo de 100 nanossegundos. No exemplo acima, o valor de `Ticks` é `315360000000000` (mais de 300 trilhões de *ticks*, pois esta é a quantidade de intervalos de 100 nanossegundos que existem em 365 dias).

O [construtor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTime__ctor_System_Int64_) de `DateTime` que recebe o valor de *ticks* cria uma **data** (não uma duração) correspondente a quantidade de *ticks* desde 1 de janeiro do ano 1, à meia-noite (não é o ano 2001 nem 1901, é o **ano 1**). No caso, a data resultante acima é 1 de janeiro do ano 2 (pois é a data correspondente a "315360000000000 *ticks* depois de 1 de janeiro do ano 1 à meia-noite").

**Isso não é uma duração (não é a diferença entre as duas datas).** Se você usar as propriedades desta data, vai obter os valores relativos à data. Por exemplo, `d.Month` retorna `1`, mas por acaso a diferença entre as datas é de 1 mês? `d.Year` é `2`, a diferença é de dois anos? Não, porque a variável `periodo` é um `DateTime` (uma data), não uma duração.

Por fim, a resposta ainda imprime a data desta forma:

```
Console.WriteLine("Anos: {0}  Meses: {1}  Dias: {2}", periodo.Year - 1, periodo.Month, periodo.Day);
```

O resultado é:

> Anos: 1  Meses: 1  Dias: 1

Seria uma "duração" de 1 ano, 1 mês e 1 dia? Não, se reparar bem a diferença entre as datas usadas no exemplo é de exatamente 1 ano. O resultado está errado e isso acontece porque os conceitos de data e duração foram confundidos. Foi criada a data de 1 de janeiro do ano 2 e os valores do dia, mês e ano foram impressos como se fossem durações.

Você quer a diferença entre as datas (ou seja, uma duração), e **isso já foi obtido** quando você criou o `TimeSpan`. Nesse caso não tem porque criar outra data (outro `DateTime`) a partir do valor do `TimeSpan`.

Comment: entendi, muito boa explicação deixou bem claro toda a diferença entre DateTime e TimeSpan e ainda deu uma explicação ainda mais completa que eu queria porque provavelmente eu iria arredondar para 30 mesmo, mas vou optar por esse ajuste. Mas ainda há um problema que é o mesmo que eu tinha comentado acima estou recebendo o valor da date de um DateTimePicker ja tentei tanto pegar a propriedade **.Text** como a propriedade **.Value** e tanto com as duas o codigo -- **DateTime date = new DateTime(dtpVigencia.Text);** acaba resultando em **Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'long'**

Comment: @PHPatrick O `Value` do `DateTimePicker` já é um `DateTime`, pode fazer `DateTime date = dtpVigencia.Value` direto.

Comment: @PHPatrick O construtor de `DateTime` recebe um `long` (um tipo numérico), por isso a mensagem de erro (isso não quer dizer que o valor é "muito longo", e sim do tipo errado). Outra coisa, vi que vc desmarcou a resposta. Se faltou alguma coisa, me avise que eu adiciono...

Answer (score 7):

Tente utilizar dessa maneira.

```
DateTime inicio = new DateTime(2018, 03, 21);
DateTime fim = new DateTime(2019, 03, 21);

TimeSpan ts = fim.Subtract(inicio);
DateTime periodo = new DateTime(ts.Ticks);

Console.WriteLine("Anos: {0}  Meses: {1}  Dias: {2}", periodo.Year - 1, periodo.Month, periodo.Day);
```

Comment: Seu código retorna `Anos: 1  Meses: 1  Dias: 1` (seria 1 ano, 1 mês e 1 dia?) mas a diferença entre 21/03/2018 e 21/03/2019 é de 1 ano apenas...

Answer (score 7):

Utilize somente matemática. Como no exemplo abaixo:

```
DateTime inicio = new DateTime(1980, 01, 28);
DateTime fim = new DateTime(2019, 03, 21);

var i = Math.Truncate(fim.Subtract(inicio).Days / (365.25 / 12));
```

Caso queira verificar se está correto, entre [neste site](https://www.calendario-365.com.br/calcular/periodo-entre-duas-datas.html) e insira as datas.

Referência: [Difference in months between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4639057/10508872).

Comment: Tem um *corner case*: entre 01/02/2019 e 01/03/2019 dá zero (mas a diferença entre elas não é de 1 mês?) Discutível, mas ainda sim, um *corner case*... :-)

Answer (score 4):

Outra opção:

```
DateTime data = DateTime.Parse("5 / 02 / 2018");
DateTime hoje = DateTime.Today;

int meses = ((hoje.Year - data.Year) * 12) + hoje.Month - data.Month;

meses += data.Day > hoje.Day ? -1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    static int GetQtdMoth(DateTime inicio, DateTime fim)
    {
        int years = fim.Year - inicio.Year;
        if (years < 0)
            return 0;
        if (years == 0)
            return fim.Month - inicio.Month;
        int meses = 12 - inicio.Month;
        return (years - 1) * 12 + meses + fim.Month;
    }
```