# Conversão de data para string

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto e estou com um problema em uma conversão de data para uma string (acredito que seja isso).

Estou fazendo a contagem de meses entre uma data e outra (algoritmo [obtido nesta outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/370215/contar-a-quantidade-de-meses-entre-uma-data-e-outra), caso desejem um pouco mais de contexto).

Porém o que está dando errado é que eu quero exibir essa contagem dos meses em um TextBox.

```
static int ajustaMesAno(DateTime d)
    {
        return d.Year * 12 + d.Month;
    }

 DateTime inicio = dtpvigencia.Value;
 DateTime fim = DateTime.Now;
 int mesesDiff = ajustaMesAno(fim) - ajustaMesAno(inicio);
   if (inicio.Day > fim.Day)
      {
          mesesDiff--;
      }
 mesesDiff = int.Parse(txtcontador.Text);
```

Esse bloco de instruções está sendo executado dentro de um `btncadastrar`, ou seja, quando eu clico nele deveria preencher o TextBox `txtcontador`, mas isso não acontece. Após clicado no botão ele exibe o erro:

> A cadeia de caracteres de entrada não estava em um formato correto.

Comment: Se você quer preencher o TextBox `txtcontator` o certo não seria você fazer `txtcontator.Text = mesesDiff.ToString()`? Você está fazendo ao contrário...

Comment: sim exatamente isso, não sei onde eu tava com a cabeça agora, um negócio tão simples mds, muito obrigado, se quiser comentar como resposta eu coloco como melhor resposta

Comment: Normal, muitas vezes nos perdemos em algumas coisinhas simples...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se não entendi errado sua dúvida, você parece estar fazendo ao contrário do que precisa, faça dessa forma:

```
static int ajustaMesAno(DateTime d)
{
    return ((d.Year * 12) + d.Month);
}

DateTime inicio = dtpvigencia.Value;
DateTime fim    = DateTime.Now;
int mesesDiff   = (ajustaMesAno(fim) - ajustaMesAno(inicio));

if (inicio.Day > fim.Day)
{
  mesesDiff--;
}

txtcontador.Text = mesesDiff.ToString();
```