# O que é o novo objeto Temporal do JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, api, característica-linguagem, data, temporal

Descobri uma proposta do **TC39** que está em [estágio 3](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal) de um novo objeto para se trabalhar com datas. Este se chama `Temporal`.

Analisei um código de exemplo que usa esta nova API:

```
console.log(
  "Initialization",
  Temporal.now.instant()
);

// Initialization 2021-01-13T20:57:01.500944804Z
```

Ele funciona como um método *static* (semelhante aos *statics* do objeto `Math`), e no exemplo acima ele retorna "quase" uma *string* na mesma forma que `new Date().toISOString()`:

```js
console.log(new Date().toISOString());
```

Sobre o assunto, foi dito que `Temporal` seria uma solução mais simples para desenvolvedores JavaScript/TypeScript que precisam trabalhar e manipular datas. Esta solução poderia até [dispensar o uso](https://dev.to/eagleera/dates-in-js-and-the-temporal-proposal-3832) de bibliotecas externas como *date-fns* e *momentjs*. Na hora me despertou interesse e gostaria de saber mais sobre esta nova implementação.

1. Esta é uma implementação nova que veio pra substituir o objeto `Date`? Sei que o `Date` não vai a lugar algum, mas a API Temporal veio pra resolver alguns problemas?

   1. Se sim, quais?
2. Sei que está em estágio 3, mas é possível usá-lo no Node.js em alguma versão através de uma *flag*?
3. Alguma versão do TypeScript suporta, mesmo que experimentalmente, esta nova API?
4. As dores de cabeça que eu tenho ao trabalhar com datas vão finalmente ser resolvidas com um "*objeto salvador*"? (sei que bala de prata não existe)

Comment: _(Off-topic)_ Só para constar, "bala de prata" se refere a uma solução ou tecnologia capaz de aumentar substancialmente a produtividade dos projetos, não tem sido encontrada num nível mais "macro" (como a troca do paradigma de programação) porém ganhos significativos em nível mais "micro" existem, por exemplo adotar a tecnologia certa para o problema em questão (em oposição a adotar uma menos adequada) ou usar uma biblioteca que melhora a produtividade para resolver certo problema. Aí entraria também uma API mais moderna para lidar com datas (que não sei se uma classe só dá conta de melhorar).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/495083/112052) já deu uma visão geral, só gostaria de complementar alguns pontos.

> ***Obs**: como a API ainda está sujeita a mudanças, não me aprofundei muito nos exemplos. Coloquei apenas alguns que usam a versão atual do [*polyfill*](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal/blob/main/polyfill) (que pode ou não ter mudado quando você estiver lendo esta resposta), para dar uma noção do que a API é capaz.*

---

Podemos começar com a principal motivação desta proposta, [segundo seus próprios criadores](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal#overview--motivation):

> *`Date` has been a long-standing pain point in ECMAScript. This proposes `Temporal` ... that brings a modern date/time API to the ECMAScript language.*

Em tradução livre, seria: "*`Date` tem sido há muito tempo um ponto problemático em ECMAScript. Propomos `Temporal`... que traz uma API de datas moderna para a linguagem*".

A ideia da [proposta](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/index.html), portanto, é criar uma nova API de datas, para [corrigir alguns pontos que eles consideram problemáticos em `Date`](https://maggiepint.com/2017/04/09/fixing-javascript-date-getting-started/).

<sup>Uma curiosidade é que alguns dos responsáveis pela proposta são os criadores do [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).</sup>

---

Um dos problemas é o fato de [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), apesar do nome, não ser *exatamente* uma data (no sentido de representar um **único** valor de dia, mês, ano, hora, minuto e segundo). Conforme já explicado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/456089/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/455437/112052), o `Date` na verdade representa um [*timestamp*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70473/112052): a quantidade de milissegundos decorrida desde o [Unix Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (que por sua vez equivale a `1970-01-01T00:00Z` - 1 de janeiro de 1970 à meia-noite, em [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC)).

Ou seja, o `Date` representa um instante único, um ponto na linha do tempo. Pense no "agora": neste exato momento, que dia é hoje e que horas são? Em cada parte do mundo, a resposta será diferente (em algumas partes do mundo, é 14 de fevereiro, em outras pode ser dia 13 ou 15, e o horário também será diferente). Apesar da data e hora serem diferentes, o instante (o valor do timestamp) é o mesmo para todos. E o `Date`, segundo a [especificação da linguagem](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-objects), só guarda a informação do timestamp.

Quando você imprime a data (via `alert` ou `console.log`) ou quando obtém informações dela (seja via os *getters* ou `toString()`), este timestamp é convertido para o fuso horário que está configurado no ambiente onde o código está rodando (*browser*, Node, etc). Ou seja, o `Date` usa a configuração do fuso horário para converter o timestamp para os valores corretos de data e hora (ou converte para UTC, quando você usa métodos como `toISOString()` ou os "*getters UTC*", como `getUTCHours`, `getUTCMonth`, etc).

Essa abordagem *one-size-fits-all* (um tipo para <strike>*a todos governar*</strike> todas as situações) pode até "simplificar" as coisas (pois assim temos um único tipo de propósito geral), mas também acaba gerando várias situações - na minha opinião - inconvenientes.

Por exemplo, se você só quer uma data de aniversário (somente dia, mês e ano), sem se importar com o horário ou timezone, bastaria fazer algo como `new Date(ano, mes, dia)`. Porém, na verdade internamente o horário será ajustado para meia-noite no fuso horário do ambiente no qual o código roda (seja o *browser*, ou o Node, etc). Isso porque somente o dia, mês e ano não é o suficiente para obter o timestamp (por exemplo, uma data como o dia 14/02/2021 não representa um instante único, você precisa saber qual o horário e em qual fuso horário ele se refere, para ter um valor de timestamp). Então com `Date` você sempre está lidando com timestamps e fusos horários, mesmo quando não quer ou não precisa.

Um exemplo (rodando no Node - lembrando que ajustar o `process.env.TZ` não funciona no Windows, e ajustá-lo no meio do script [só funciona a partir do Node 13](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/3286)):

```
let d = new Date(2021, 1, 14); // em Date, fevereiro é mês 1 :-(
let t = Temporal.PlainDate.from({ year: 2021, month: 2, day: 14 }); // fevereiro é mês 2 \o/
console.log(d.toString(), t);

// mudar para o timezone da Califórnia
process.env.TZ = 'America/Los_Angeles';
console.log(d.toString(), t);
```

Eu crio um `Date` e um `Temporal.PlainDate` que correspondem a 14 de fevereiro de 2021 - aliás, outro bônus incrível desta API: os meses **não** são indexados em zero - janeiro é 1 [e não zero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/405998/112052)!

O timezone configurado no meu ambiente é `America/Sao_Paulo` (vulgo "Horário de Brasília"). Então o `Date` terá o horário ajustado para meia-noite no Horário de Brasília, e este é o timezone usado para imprimir a data.

Mas quando eu mudo o timezone do ambiente, isso afeta a saída de `toString()` (o timestamp do `Date` ainda é o mesmo, mas este será convertido para o novo timezone ao ser impresso). Já `PlainDate` não é afetado por esta configuração, pois ele só guarda o dia, mês e ano, sem se importar com o horário ou o timezone. A saída é:

```
Sun Feb 14 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Brasilia Standard Time) Temporal.PlainDate <2021-02-14>
Sat Feb 13 2021 19:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) Temporal.PlainDate <2021-02-14>
```

<sup>Lembrando que o resultado pode variar de acordo com o timezone que estiver configurado no seu ambiente.</sup>

Repare que `Date.toString()` mostra um valor diferente de acordo com o timezone que está configurado (aliás, o mesmo ocorre com os *getters*: `d.getDate()` retornaria 14 ou 13, dependendo do timezone configurado). Já `PlainDate`, por não ter nenhuma informação sobre horários ou timezones, não é afetado por nenhuma configuração e mantém seu valor constante.

Creio que isso evitará muitos erros que costumam ocorrer até hoje ("*Criei um `Date` mas ele mostra o dia/horário errado*").

Além disso, a nova API define vários tipos diferentes, um para cada situação (indo no caminho oposto do *one-size-fits-all*): tem um tipo para data (somente dia, mês e ano), outro para horário (somente hora, minuto, segundo), outro para data e hora, mas sem fuso horário, outro para data/hora e fuso, outro para timestamp, etc.

Esta imagem (retirada da [documentação](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/)) nos dá um bom resumo dos tipos disponíveis:

[image: Temporal types]

E esta mostra a relação entre estes tipos:

[image: Temporal types relationship]

---

#### Conversão entre timezones

Uma coisa que o JavaScript não tem é conversão entre diferentes timezones.

O mais próximo que temos é algo como `d.toLocaleString('pt-BR', { timeZone: 'Europe/Berlin' })`, que de fato retorna os valores de data e hora convertidos para o timezone indicado. Mas o problema é que o formato depende do *locale*, e não temos controle sobre isso. E se quisermos a data/hora em um timezone específico, mas em outro formato? Eu teria que ir trocando o *locale* até encontrar um, mas e se nenhum tiver o formato específico que eu quero? Ou se eu simplesmente não quiser um formato, e sim um objeto contendo os valores de data e hora convertidos para outro timezone?

Com `Date`, não dá. Já o `Temporal` prevê [várias formas de converter](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/cookbook.html#time-zone-conversion):

- mantendo o horário local: tenho um objeto que representa 14/02/2021 às 10h no Horário de Brasília, quero mudar somente o timezone (ou seja, converter para 14/02/2021 às 10h no fuso do Japão, por exemplo)
- mantendo o instante: quando é 14/02/2021 às 10h no Horário de Brasília, que dia e hora é no Japão? (R: 22h do mesmo dia)

A API ainda trata casos mais complexos que só os timezones trazem para você, como as transições de horário de verão: permite que você trate os vários *corner cases* que ocorrem (quando uma hora é pulada, ou quando ela ocorre 2 vezes - nos casos em que o relógio é atrasado em uma hora quando termina o horário de verão, por exemplo), além de permitir consultar o histórico de mudanças de cada timezone.

---

#### Aritmética de datas

Atualmente o JavaScript não possui um bom suporte para aritmética de datas. Na prática, o melhor que dá para fazer para calcular a diferença entre duas datas é subtrair os valores dos timestamps e depois fazer os cálculos na mão.

Mas nem sempre isso é suficiente. Só para ficar em um caso, a [diferença em meses não é algo tão trivial quanto parece](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/370215/112052): por exemplo, entre 01/01/2019 e 01/02/2019 há 31 dias. Dividindo por 30 e arredondando, dá 1 mês.

Mas entre 01/02/2019 e 01/03/2019 há 28 dias. Dividindo por 30, dá 0,93: se arredondar pra baixo, dá zero meses. Mas entre 1 de fevereiro e 1 de março a diferença não é de um mês? Então devemos arredondar pra cima nesse caso?

Mas e se fosse entre 01/01/2019 e 29/01/2019, a diferença também é de 28 dias. Só que entre 1 de janeiro e 29 de janeiro ainda não se passou 1 mês, então eu não posso arredondar pra cima nesse caso. "*Ah, então eu só arredondo pra cima se não estiver no mesmo mês*".

Aí você vê que entre 01/01/2019 e 27/02/2019 a diferença é de 57 dias, que dividido por 30 dá 1,9. Se arredondar pra cima dá 2, mas entre 1 de janeiro e 27 de fevereiro ainda não se passaram dois meses. E agora?

Com `Temporal`, bastaria fazer algo do tipo:

```
const today = Temporal.PlainDate.from('2019-01-01');
const futureDate = Temporal.PlainDate.from('2019-02-27');
const until = today.until(futureDate, { largestUnit: 'months' });
console.log(until); // 1 mês e 26 dias

// ou, se quiser apenas a quantidade de meses, use until.months
```

Aliás, está previsto um tipo específico para durações: [`Temporal.Duration`](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/duration.html). Com isso ficará mais simples fazer operações como "somar dias/meses/anos/qualquer-outra-quantidade-de-tempo a uma data".

Claro, isso poderá mudar o comportamento de alguns *corner cases*. Por exemplo, se você somar 1 mês à 31 de janeiro:

```js
let d = new Date(2021, 0, 31); // 31 de janeiro de 2021
// somar 1 mês
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1);
console.log(d.toString()); // 3 de março!
```

Na verdade a "soma" é feita ajustando-se o valor do mês e mantendo os demais campos. No caso acima, mudamos o mês para fevereiro, e o dia mantém-se em 31, mas como fevereiro não tem 31 dias, é feito um ajuste para 3 de março (os dias "excedentes" acabam "dando *overflow*" e "invadindo" o mês seguinte).

Mas aí entra uma questão semântica: se tenho uma data em janeiro e somo 1 mês, por que o resultado é uma data em março? Não deveria ser em fevereiro? Tudo bem que isso é discutível, já que não existe uma regra "oficial" para aritmética de datas (tal como existe na matemática) e cada API implementa de um jeito. Mas o `Temporal` (usando a implementação atual do *polyfill*) ajusta a data para o último dia de fevereiro, caso o valor do dia exceda a quantidade de dias do mês:

```
let d = Temporal.PlainDate.from('2021-01-31'); // 31 de janeiro de 2021
d = d.add(Temporal.Duration.from({ months: 1 }));
console.log(d); // Temporal.PlainDate <2021-02-28> (28 de fevereiro de 2021)
```

Enfim, um bom resumo das possibilidades está na própria [documentação](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/cookbook.html#arithmetic).

---

Resumindo, os problemas de se trabalhar com datas vão continuar existindo (como tratar corretamente, converter entre timezones, fazer cálculos, etc). O que pode ficar mais fácil - assim espero - é resolver esses problemas :-)

E lembrando que `Date` não vai sumir, inclusive a nova API prevê [a conversão de `Date` para `Temporal.Instant`](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/cookbook.html#converting-between-temporal-types-and-legacy-date).

Comment: @CmteCardeal Adicionei mais algumas coisas na resposta. Mas acho que não vou mais adicionar muita coisa pois a API ainda está sujeita à mudanças (inclusive, eu cheguei a testar algumas semanas atrás e realmente a versão atual mudou bastante, até os nomes de algumas classes e métodos inclusive), então acho que vou esperar ela ser oficialmente lançada para poder atualizar a resposta com mais exemplos...

Comment: Tivemos essa atualização no Github da proposta: _""NOTA: Embora a API desta proposta não deva ser alterada, os implementadores desta proposta NÃO DEVEM enviar implementações Temporal não sinalizadas até que a IETF padronize os formatos de serialização de sequência de fuso horário / calendário.""_ Acho que a API em si não vai mais mudar. O que falta agora é só questões de implementações. Não cheguei a verificar completamente, mas pode ser que a API siga esse padrão agora, logo mudanças no estágio 3 já são bom difíceis de acontecer.

Comment: @CmteCardeal Bom, mesmo assim, acho que vou esperar mais um pouco pra atualizar a resposta. Ainda nem terminei de ler toda a documentação...

Answer (score 13):

A API Temporal é, no momento em que escrevo esta resposta, uma proposta de adição ao ECMAScript que se encontra no estágio 3 do processo de incorporação à especificação (o famigerado *TC39 process*). [Repositório referente à proposta.](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal)

Mediante estandardização, a API Temporal consistirá de um objeto global `Temporal` (similar aos já existentes `Math`, `Date`, `JSON` etc) que irá aglutinar classes, funções e utilitários para a manipulação de datas e horas no JavaScript. Embora a API desta proposta não deva ser alterada, os implementadores desta proposta NÃO DEVEM enviar implementações `Temporal` não sinalizadas até que a [IETF](https://www.ietf.org/?pk_campaign=ietf-google-ads&pk_source=google&pk_medium=cpc&pk_content=ietf-brand) padronize os formatos de serialização de sequência de fuso horário / calendário.

Sobre a API podemos citar:

- Construtores notáveis do objeto `Temporal`:

  - `Temporal.Instant`
  - `Temporal.PlainDateTime`
  - `Temporal.PlainDate`
  - `Temporal.PlainTime`
  - `Temporal.PlainYearMonth`
  - `Temporal.PlainMonthDay`
  - `Temporal.TimeZone`
  - `Temporal.Duration`
- Outras propriedades do objeto `Temporal`:

  - `Temporal.now`

Já quero deixar uma vontade: cada um dos construtores acima tem uma funcionalidade específica e seus próprios métodos. :-) Para detalhes individuais, consultar a [especificação](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/#sec-temporal-objects) e [documentação](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/) da proposta.

Até então, o único meio "nativo do JavaScript" para lidar com datas e horas no JavaScript é utilizar o objeto `Date` e suas respectivas funções e métodos. No entanto, essa API é extremamente antiga e possui vários problemas de *design*.

Como é de conhecimento comum, o JavaScript foi implementado num prazo extremamente curto por Brendan Eich, que baseou o funcionamento do `Date` na API (hoje majoritariamente depreciada) `java.Util.Date`. Apesar de, com atualizações futuras, o Java ter ganhado novos meios de lidar com datas e horas, o JavaScript permaneceu com a infame API `Date`. A Temporal API é a "evolução" do gerenciamento de datas e horas no JavaScript, sem os problemas da API antiga.

A nova API Temporal visa à resolução desses problemas, uma vez que:

- Fornece APIs simples e fáceis de usar para executar computações relacionadas à datas e horas.
- Suporte de primeira classe para todas as *time zones*, o que inclui suporte a horários de verão (cálculos *[DST](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time)-safe*)
- Lida somente com objetos imutáveis (ao contrário da maioria das APIs `Date`, que são mutáveis).
- Analisa somente formatos de string estritamente especificadas.
- Suporta outros calendários, além do Gregoriano.

Desse modo, como vimos acima, o novo objeto `Temporal` fornecerá uma grande variedade de construtores e objetos para:

- Representar propriamente informações relativas à datas e horas.
- Possibilitar computações apropriadas baseadas em cada tipo.

Não acho que vale a pena alongar mais que isso, uma vez que a [documentação da proposta](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/) é bem completa e expressiva, além de que, como vimos, pode estar sujeita à mudanças. Quando a API for estabilizada, comprometo-me a atualizar esta resposta com informações mais detalhadas.

---

## FAQ da pergunta

> Esta é uma implementação nova que veio pra substituir o objeto Date? Sei que o Date não vai a lugar algum, mas o Temporal veio pra resolver alguns problemas?

Não. O `Date` realmente não vai a lugar nenhum, até porque isso quebraria a web, o que iria contra um dos principais princípios do processo TC39, que é não quebrar APIs antigas do JavaScript.

A API Temporal veio para tornar o trabalho com datas e horas mais simples. É bem provável que torne a API `Date` menos comum em novos projetos e aplicações, mas `Date` jamais deixará de existir no JavaScript.

> Sei que está em estágio 2, mas é possível usá-lo no Node.js em alguma versão através de uma *flag*?

Editado ao dia 11 de março de 2021: Acabou de passar para o estágio 3, o que significa que as *engine* poderão começar implementações iniciais – ainda sem estabilidade garantida.

O Node.js (baseado no motor V8) *ainda* não possui suporte nativo à API Temporal, mas existe *polyfill* que pode ser utilizado.

No entanto, não acho sábio fazer uso dessa API neste momento para projetos "reais", uma vez que ainda não está totalmente estabilizado.

> Alguma versão do TypeScript suporta, mesmo que experimentalmente, esta nova API?

Não. O TypeScript ainda não fornece definições de tipos “nativas” para a API Temporal.

> As dores de cabeça que eu tenho ao trabalhar com datas vão finalmente ser resolvidas com um "objeto salvador"? (sei que bala de prata não existe)

Todas, provavelmente, não. :-) Mas como vimos acima, a API Temporal resolverá diversos problemas históricos da API `Date`, o que decerto facilitará o trabalho com datas e horas.

No entanto, é um campo complicado e repleto de *edge-cases*. Apesar de facilitar, a API Temporal não faz com que eles sumam.

Comment: Pois é, o `Date` sempre vai existir por causa da retrocompatibilidade, que é um dos "pilares" da web moderna. Mas não se preocupe! Assim que `Temporal` for estandardizada (e o suporte se disseminar), `Date` raramente será usada em novos projetos — pelo menos eu espero. :P

Comment: @CmteCardeal, pode editar, se quiser, estou meio sem tempo para ver isso em detalhes agora. Ainda planejo rescrever essa resposta do zero quando avançar ao estágio 4. O pior mesmo é achar o tempo... :D