# Mostrar data atual em determinado timezone

Tags: javascript, data, timezone

Eu estou tentando colocar no meu site a hora local de outra cidade, através do `data.timezone` retornado pela API do Open Weather.

Este valor está em segundos, por exemplo, se o país tiver uma diferença de 3 horas a mais com relação a UTC, o que aparece na API é 10800, e se for 3 horas a menos, -10800.

Então, para converter para minutos, eu fiz:

```
const timezone = data.timezone / 3600
```

E, para mostrar na tela:

```
let currentHour = new Date().getHours()
let currentMinutes = new Date().getMinutes()
let currentSeconds = new Date().getSeconds()
let currentHourZone = currentHour + timezone
let dateTimezone = `${currentHourZone}:${currentMinutes}:${currentSeconds}` // (essa variável que está sendo mostrada)
```

Porém, o que está acontecendo  é o seguinte: Ao dar 24 horas ou mais, ele ao invés de voltar para o meia noite (00), ele está acrescentando, e, no minuto, quando vai para 60, ao invés de voltar para 00 e acrescentar 1 às horas, ele também não vai, e a mesma coisa com os segundos, ou seja, não está validando como no padrão do `new Date().toLocaleTimeString()`.

O que eu tentei:

```
if (currentHour === 60) {
        currentHour = '00'
     }

     if (currentMinutes < 10) {
        currentMinutes = '0' + currentMinutes
     }
     if (currentSeconds < 10) {
        currentSeconds = '0' + currentSeconds
     }
```

E, ainda mais:

```
if (dateTimezone = 24 + ':' + currentMinutes + ':' + currentSeconds) {
         dateTimezone = '00' + ':' + currentMinutes + ':' + currentSeconds
     }
     if (dateTimezone = currentHourZone + ':' + 60 + ':' + currentSeconds) {
         dateTimezone = currentHourZone + 1 + ':' + '00' + ':' + currentSeconds
     }
     if (dateTimezone = currentHourZone + ':' + currentMinutes + ':' + 60) {
         dateTimezone = currentHourZone + ':' + currentMinutes + 1 + ':' + '00'
     }
```

E, por último, e o mais perto que chegou de validar:

```
const pastTime = `${24}:${currentMinutes}:${currentSeconds - 1}`
    const midNightTime = `00:${currentMinutes.toString()}:${currentSeconds.toString()}`

    if (dateTimezone > pastTime) {
        dateTimezone = midNightTime
    }
```

Comment: Você pode criar um novo `Date` com o timestamp atual mais o valor de `data.timezone` convertido em milissegundos: `new Date(Date.now() + (data.timezone * 1000));`, depois você usa os métodos do objeto para por exemplo obter às horas, minutos etc. Mas é importante usar os métodos `getUTC...`. [Veja também esta resposta para detalhes sobre datas em JS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/455437/como-mostrar-o-objeto-date-com-o-timezone-que-ele-foi-criado-em-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Segundo a [API do OpenWeather](https://openweathermap.org/current#parameter), o campo `timezone` contém a diferença com relação a UTC, em segundos.

Sendo assim, uma maneira de obter o horário local no timezone indicado seria usar [`toLocaleTimeString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString), passando o timezone nas opções.

Mas tem um detalhe: esta opção aceita os identificadores de timezones definidos pela [IANA](https://www.iana.org/time-zones), que são no formato "Continente/Região" (tal como `America/Sao_Paulo`, `Europe/Berlin`, `Asia/Tokyo`, etc). Mas existe uma alternativa para valores fixos como "-3 horas", que é usar timezones no formato "Etc/GMT[offset]", no qual `offset` é a diferença em horas com relação a UTC, porém com o sinal invertido (sim, se a diferença for de 3 horas depois do UTC, o correspondente seria "Etc/GMT-3").

Outro detalhe importante é que [nem todos os lugares do mundo adotam fusos-horários de "hora cheia"](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/time-zones-interesting.html). Por exemplo, a Índia atualmente está em `UTC+05:30` (sim, 5 horas e meia à frente do UTC), e o Nepal está em `UTC+05:45` (5 horas e 45 minutos à frente do UTC). Sem contar algumas regiões da Austrália, que durante o horário de verão adiantam o relógio em apenas meia hora.

Ou seja, a abordagem que mostrarei abaixo é limitada, pois funciona apenas quando a diferença em relação a UTC é de hora cheia (já que os timezones no formato "Etc/GMT" suportam apenas horas cheias):

```js
const data = { timezone: -10820 };

// valor das horas arredondado (invertendo o sinal)
const horasTz = (-Math.sign(data.timezone)) * Math.floor(Math.abs(data.timezone) / 3600);
const sign = horasTz >= 0 ? '+' : ''; // se for negativo, o próprio número já terá o sinal "-"
// exibir a hora atual no timezone indicado
const agora = new Date();
console.log(agora.toLocaleTimeString('pt-BR', { timeZone: `Etc/GMT${sign}${horasTz}`}));
```

A parte chata é arredondar o valor e manter o sinal. O arredondamento é importante para os casos já mencionados (fusos de "horas quebradas"), e deve-se atentar para o caso de valores negativos (ao arredondar `-3.5`, o resultado seria `-4`, então o ajuste acima é para que seja `-3`), e também para inverter o sinal (pois os timezones "Etc/GMT" devem ter o sinal invertido).

---

Se for para funcionar inclusive com os fusos de "horas quebradas", o jeito é fazer manualmente:

```js
const data = { timezone: -10800 };
const agora = new Date();

function mod(x, y) {
    return x - (y * Math.floor(x / y));
}
let n = mod((agora.getUTCHours() * 3600) + (agora.getUTCMinutes() * 60) + agora.getUTCSeconds() + data.timezone, 86400);

let hour = Math.floor(n / 3600);
n %= 3600;
let min = Math.floor(n / 60);
let sec = n % 60;

// função para retornar o valor com zero à esquerda, caso necessário
function pad(val) {
    return val.toString().padStart(2, '0');
}

console.log(`${pad(hour)}:${pad(min)}:${pad(sec)}`);
```

Assim ele funciona para qualquer valor que `data.timezone` tiver, inclusive se for de um dos fusos já mencionados (de "horas quebradas"). Vale lembrar que você precisa usar os *getters* UTC (`getUTCHours` para pegar o horário em UTC, já que a diferença é em relação a UTC). Se usar `getHours`, será retornado o horário de acordo com o fuso horário do ambiente (seja o browser ou o que está na configuração do Node, etc).

Fiz um cálculo simplificado pois só estamos interessados no horário, sem se importar com o dia, mês e ano (pois aí o cálculo ficaria um pouco mais complicado). O ponto que é um pouco mais complicado é o resto da divisão, que tive que fazer uma função à parte para tratar os casos de números negativos (por exemplo, se o horário UTC fosse meia-noite e o timezone fosse `-10800`, o resultado ficaria negativo (`-3:00:00`), então fiz um ajuste para que ele se torne `21:00:00`).

---

[Nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/498025/problema-com-o-timezone-openweathermap-api#comment923493_498025) foi sugerido mudar o valor do timestamp:

```js
const data = { timezone: -10800 };
function pad(val) {
    return val.toString().padStart(2, '0');
}

const date = new Date();
// mudar o valor do timestamp
date.setTime(date.getTime() + data.timezone * 1000);
let h = date.getUTCHours();
let m = date.getUTCMinutes();
let s = date.getUTCSeconds();
console.log(`${pad(h)}:${pad(m)}:${pad(s)}`);
```

Apesar de "funcionar", você deve usar com cautela, pois ao alterar o valor do timestamp, na verdade você está criando um `Date` referente a um instante diferente do atual. Se você não vai usar o `Date` para mais nada, não é tão grave assim, mas se for usá-lo posteriormente, esteja ciente de que ele agora possui um valor modificado que não corresponde mais à data/hora atual. Leia [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/455444/112052) (na seção "Gambiarra") para entender melhor, e para saber mais sobre o `Date` do JavaScript, leia [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/456089/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/344030/112052).

---

Outra alternativa é usar alguma lib externa (enquanto o [`Temporal`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/495075/112052) não é aprovado), como por exemplo o [Moment Timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/):

```js
const data = { timezone: -10800 };
console.log(moment().utcOffset(data.timezone / 60).format('HH:mm:ss'));
```

```html
    <script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado. Agradeço imensamente pela atenção e ajuda.