# Concatenar data e hora de campos distintos

Tags: javascript, data

Estou criando um sistema de agendamentos e preciso concatenar uma data e um horário definidos em campos distintos. Preciso, por exemplo, pegar a data 19/02/2022 do campo 1 e contatenar com o horário 22:57 do campo 2. Veja:

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="data_agendamento" name="data_agendamento">
<input type="time" class="form-control" id="hora_agendamento" name="hora_agendamento"> 

let data_agendamento = new Date(document.getElementById("data_agendamento").value + 'T00:00');
let hora_agendamento = document.getElementById("hora_agendamento").value;

alert(data_agendamento + hora_agendamento);
```

O alert está exibindo:

```
Sat Feb 19 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília)22:57
```

Preciso que a saída seja `19/02/2022 22:57:00`.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 2):

Se você tem a data em um campo e a hora em outro, então deveria passar ambos para o construtor de `Date`. Não faz sentido você criar a data com o horário igual à meia-noite e depois tentar concatenar o horário somente na hora de imprimir.

Ou seja, deveria ser assim:

```js
function mostraData() {
    // passe a data e hora juntos no construtor
    let datahora = new Date(document.getElementById("data_agendamento").value
                            + 'T'
                            + document.getElementById("hora_agendamento").value);
    alert(datahora.toLocaleString('pt-BR'));
}
```

```html
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="data_agendamento" name="data_agendamento">
<input type="time" class="form-control" id="hora_agendamento" name="hora_agendamento"> 

<button onclick="mostraData()">Mostrar data</button>
```

E aqui temos que explicar uma coisa: data é uma coisa, string é outra. Uma data é apenas um ponto específico no calendário (um determinado dia, mês e ano). Já uma string (ou um "texto", que é o que você vê quando imprime a data, seja com `console.log` ou com `alert`) é uma representação da data (e não a data em si).

Por exemplo, 19/02/2022 é uma data que corresponde ao dia 19 de fevereiro de 2022 do nosso calendário. Mas esta mesma data pode ser representada de diversas maneiras: `19/02/2022`, `2022-02-19`, `Feb 19th, 2022`, `Dezenove de fevereiro de dois mil e vinte e dois`, etc. Todos esses formatos são textos (strings) diferentes, mas todos representam a mesma data.

No caso do JavaScript, um `Date` representa a data (o ponto na linha do tempo) e ela não tem um formato específico. Quando você mostra a data (por exemplo, no `alert`), ela é mostrada em algum formato, mas isso não quer dizer que ela está naquele formato. No caso, ela acaba chamando o [método `toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString), que retorna a data no formato que você viu (`Sat Feb 19 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília)`), e concatenar isso com o horário não faz o menor sentido (repare que o horário da data é meia-noite, mas na verdade deveria ser o horário que estava no `input`).

Por isso que eu passei o horário no construtor, pois aí criamos o `Date` com a data e hora corretas.

Depois, para imprimir, temos que converter a data para o formato que você quer. No caso, já é possível fazer isso com o [método `toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString), passando `pt-BR`, que corresponde ao português brasileiro e já retorna a data no formato desejado (mas se fosse outro formato muito diferente, aí talvez tenha que [formatar manualmente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6526/112052)).

Para mais detalhes sobre o `Date` do JavaScript, leia [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/456089/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/455437/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/408160/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/416172/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/344030/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/498025/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/494302/112052).

---

Se bem que, para ter a data e hora ao mesmo tempo, outra alternativa é usar um único `input`, mudando o tipo para [`type="datetime-local"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local):

```js
function mostraData() {
    // o input já tem a data e hora juntos, basta passar tudo para o construtor de Date
    let data_agendamento = new Date(document.getElementById("data_agendamento").value);
    alert(data_agendamento.toLocaleString('pt-BR'));
}
```

```html
<input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="data_agendamento" name="data_agendamento">

<button onclick="mostraData()">Mostrar data</button>
```

Assim, o `value` dele já terá a data e hora no formato correto para serem passados ao construtor de `Date`.

Comment: Ótima explanação sobre Date, hkotsubo! Abandonei a ideia de usar dois campos para armazenar data e hora, respectivamente. Vou usar o datetime-local. Obrigado!

Comment: @CriandoBits Se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, vc pode aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que estou vendo no código que você postou, acredito que um dos problemas seja que está tentando exibir a data no carregamento da página, logo se a página está sendo carregada teoricamente não temos informações a serem exibidas nesse momento. Outro coisa é objeto `Date()` na qual você já está definindo a hora como `00:00` com o `T00:00`.

Se você quer somente exibir a data, pode adicionar um `button` e ao clicar nele exibir as informações necessárias.

No html:

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="data_agendamento" name="data_agendamento" />
<input type="time" class="form-control" id="hora_agendamento" name="hora_agendamento" /> 

<input type="button" value="Show date console" onClick="showDate()" />
```

Aqui utilizei [JQuery](https://jquery.com/)

```
function showDate(){
  let data_agendamento = $("#data_agendamento").val();
  let hora_agendamento = $("#hora_agendamento").val();

    console.log(data_agendamento + " " + hora_agendamento);
}
```

Neste caso as informações serão impressas no console.
Pode verificar o código rodando [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/uLsvzmca/3/)

Se precisar de mais algumas manipulações em relação a data pode olhar esta documentação no site do [Mozzila](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: A pergunta pede que o formato da data seja dd/mm/aaaa, mas da forma que vc fez, mostra como aaaa-mm-dd.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, Leandro. Resolvi usar apenas um campo para receber data e hora. Gratidão!