# Como fazer um filtro em um array com elementos Timestamp?

Tags: javascript, data, timestamp

Preciso criar filtros para um gráfico e estou utilizando a lib Highcharts apenas no front.
Os dados estão sendo consumidos de uma API em um array de arrays como este:

```
[
  [
    1565308800000,
    24960
  ],[
    1565568000000,
    24960
  ]
]...
```

Estou pegando os valores do index [0] de cada array  que são datas em timestamp mas não consigo comparar para fazer os filtros.

```
if (value === '1') {
   const data = list.map((item) => item[0])
```

ele me retorna apenas os primeiros valores.

Tentei o `.filter()`

```
const FilteredValue = data.filter (function (data) {
      return data > 2019;
})
```

Já tentei com o ano e também com o valor em timestamp e não da certo.

- Devo converter o timestamp? Se sim como faço isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depende **muito** do que você quer fazer, mas primeiro você precisa entender [o que é o timestamp](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70473/112052).

---

## Entendendo o timestamp

Basicamente, um timestamp como 1565308800000 indica que se passaram mais de 1,5 trilhões de milissegundos, contados a partir do [Unix Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (que por sua vez, corresponde a 1 de janeiro de 1970, à meia-noite, em [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)).

Só que esse valor é "universal", no sentido de que é o mesmo para o mundo todo. Ele representa um instante específico, um ponto na linha do tempo. E aí que começam os problemas...

Ao converter o timestamp para uma data, você tem que levar em consideração o fuso horário, pois em cada um o valor corresponde a uma data e hora diferentes. Alguns exemplos:

| Fuso horário | Data/hora |
| --- | --- |
| America/Sao_Paulo | 08/08/2019 21:00 |
| America/Los_Angeles | 08/08/2019 **17**:00 |
| Asia/Tokyo | **09**/08/2019 **09**:00 |
| UTC | **09**/08/2019 **00**:00 |

Todas as datas e horas acima correspondem ao timestamp `1565308800000`. Ou seja, o ponto na linha do tempo é o mesmo: é o instante que ocorreu 1.565.308.800.000 de milissegundos depois do Unix Epoch. Só que esse mesmo instante corresponde a uma data e/ou hora diferentes, dependendo do fuso horário que você considerar.

Então se você converter o timestamp para uma data, e/ou quiser compará-lo com outra data, terá que levar isso em consideração.

> Para entender mais sobre como funciona o `Date` do JavaScript, veja [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/456089/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/455444/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/344030/112052).

---

## Diferentes formas de converter podem dar resultados diferentes

Dependendo de como você fizer, pode obter um resultado diferente em alguns casos. Isso porque o `Date` do JavaScript, apesar do nome, não guarda uma data (no sentido de ter um único valor para dia, mês, ano, hora, minuto e segundo). Na verdade ele só guarda o valor do timestamp.

Só que quando usamos o `Date` para obter informações como o dia (com `getDate()`) ou a hora (com `getHours()`), os valores são retornados de acordo com o timezone que está configurado no ambiente no qual o código está rodando (seja ele o *browser* ou *runtimes* como o Node.js e [Deno](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deno), etc).

Ou seja, se você converter o timestamp para uma data e imprimi-la:

```js
var data = new Date(1565308800000);
console.log(data.toString());
```

A saída poderá variar de acordo com a configuração do fuso horário. Por exemplo, se estiver no Horário de Brasília, a saída será `Thu Aug 08 2019 21:00:00 GMT-0300 (Brasilia Standard Time)`, mas se eu mudar para o fuso do Japão, a saída passa a ser `Fri Aug 09 2019 09:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time)`. E o mesmo vale para os *getters* (`getDate()` e `getHours()` retornarão valores diferentes de acordo com o fuso).

Claro que para o seu exemplo, no qual só queria comparar o ano, pode "funcionar" na maior parte do tempo. Mas ainda sim há margem para problemas, como por exemplo:

```js
var data = new Date(1577844000000);
if (data.getFullYear() > 2019) {
    console.log('ok');
}
```

Se o código acima rodar em um ambiente no qual o fuso horário configurado é o Horário de Brasília, o "ok" não será mostrado, já que este timestamp corresponde a 31/12/2019 às 23:00 no Horário de Brasília. Mas se o fuso for, por exemplo, de algum lugar da Europa ou Ásia, aí sim ele mostra "ok", pois nestes fusos horários o timestamp corresponde a algum horário do dia 01/01/2020.

---

O mesmo vale se você criar uma data arbitrária, [como sugeriu a outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/522153/112052). Na verdade tem outro porém lá, que é o fato de ter usado uma string em um formato não-padronizado. No Firefox, por exemplo, `new Date('12-01-2020')` retorna "Invalid Date" (no Chrome e Node.js "funciona").

Isso porque [o único formato definido pela especificação](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) e que é garantido que funcione em qualquer ambiente é o definido pela [norma ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (que no caso seria "ano-mês-dia", ou seja, `2020-12-01`). Qualquer outro formato é dependente da implementação e varia muito de um ambiente para outro, podendo ou não funcionar (veja mais sobre o assunto [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/408160/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/469717/112052)).

Enfim, se quiser criar uma data específica, pode usar este formato, ou os valores numéricos:

```js
// criando um Date equivalente a 1 de dezembro de 2020

// string no formato ISO 8601
var data = new Date('2020-12-01');

// ou, usando valores numéricos
var data = new Date(2020, 11, 1); // não é erro, o mês é 11 mesmo
```

Um detalhe é que se usar os valores numéricos, dezembro tem que ser `11`, pois em JavaScript os meses são *irritantemente* indexados em zero (janeiro é zero, fevereiro é 1, etc). Veja mais [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/416172/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/405998/112052).

**Mas ainda tem uma "pegadinha"**.

Quando você só informa o dia, mês e ano, o horário é automaticamente setado para meia-noite. Mas há uma diferença importante entre as duas opções acima.

No primeiro caso (string no formato ISO 8601), o horário é setado para meia-noite em UTC, enquanto que no segundo caso, o horário é setado para meia noite no fuso horário do ambiente. Isso pode dar diferença no valor do timestamp:

```js
var d1 = new Date('2020-12-01'); // meia-noite em UTC
var d2 = new Date(2020, 11, 1); // meia-noite no timezone do browser

console.log(d1.toString());
console.log(d1.valueOf());

console.log(d2.toString());
console.log(d2.valueOf());
```

Eu rodei o código acima no meu *browser*, configurado com o Horário de Brasília, e a saída foi:

```
Mon Nov 30 2020 21:00:00 GMT-0300 (Brasilia Standard Time)
1606780800000
Tue Dec 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Brasilia Standard Time)
1606791600000
```

No primeiro caso, ele criou um `Date` correspondente a 01/12/2020, à meia-noite em **UTC** (que por sua vez, corresponde a 30/11/2020 às 21h no Horário de Brasília). Já no segundo caso, ele criou o `Date` correspondente a 01/12/2020, à meia-noite no Horário de Brasília. Por isso os timestamps são diferentes.

E se você rodar em ambientes com outro fuso horário configurado, os resultados serão diferentes (o segundo timestamp não será o mesmo que eu obtive).

---

## Então como eu faço?

Dependendo de como você escolher fazer as conversões (seja convertendo o timestamp que você tem, seja criando um `Date` com uma data fixa), podem ter *corner cases* nos quais uma data "válida" ficará de fora (ou uma "inválida" será considerada).

Apenas para citar alguns exemplos de como poderia ser feito:

```js
var list = [
  [ 1565308800000, 24960 ],
  [ 1565568000000, 24960 ]
];

// criar uma data limite usando algum dos métodos acima, e pegar o timestamp
var limite = new Date('2019-08-10').valueOf();
var filtrados = list.filter(dados => dados[0] > limite);
console.log(filtrados); // [ [ 1565568000000, 24960 ] ]

// ou converter o timestamp para Date e verificar o critério desejado
filtrados = list.filter(function(dados) {
    var d = new Date(dados[0]);
    return d.getDate() > 10; // filtrar os dias maiores que 10
});
console.log(filtrados); // [ [ 1565568000000, 24960 ] ]
```

Lembrando sempre dos detalhes já mencionados acima: cada abordagem terá algum detalhe específico a ser considerado, sempre relacionado ao fuso horário. Se o código rodar no browser, por exemplo, você não tem controle sobre a configuração do fuso (e aí teria que recorrer a bibliotecas externas para tal, já que o JavaScript não possui um suporte decente para isso - [no futuro terá](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/495075/112052), mas por enquanto não tem).

Se estiver usando Node.js >= 13 no Linux, você pode setar o timezone no início do script. Por exemplo:

```js
process.env.TZ = 'America/Sao_Paulo'; // Horário de Brasília
```

No caso, `America/Sao_Paulo` corresponde ao Horário de Brasília. Os nomes dos timezones são definidos pela [IANA](https://www.iana.org/time-zones), e podem ser consultados [aqui](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/main/zone1970.tab).

Comment: Cara muito obrigado por esclarecer, sua explicação foi excelente e ao final você acabou falando exatamente o que eu também precisava, sucesso e obrigado!!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode pegar a data que deseja comparar e converte-la também para timestamp utilizando a função `new Date().getTime()`. Por exemplo, digamos que só quero datas anteriores a 1º de dezembro de 2020.

```
const FilteredValue = data.filter (function (data) {
  const primeiroDezembro = new Date('12-01-2020').getTime()
  return data < primeiroDezembro;
})
```

Existem algumas bibliotecas que facilitam essas comparações, como a [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/v2.23.0/docs/isBefore)

Comment: Funcionou amigo! Obrigado!!

Comment: @LuizFelipe e Bruno, vale lembrar que `new Date('12-01-2020')` não é garantido que funcione em todos os browsers - testei no Firefox 90 em uma máquina Ubuntu, por exemplo, e deu "Invalid Date". Isso porque o único formato garantido pela especificação que funciona em qualquer ambiente é "yyyy-mm-dd" (no caso, seria `new Date('2020-12-01')`), mas ainda sim tem outros detalhes importantes que são explicados [na outra resposta](/a/522203/112052)