# Converter duração em segundos em anos, meses, dias e demais unidades de tempo

Tags: javascript

Mostrar um tempo por extenso para o usuário é interessante para o mesmo saber o tempo por extenso de determinado, exemplo:

```
6m22d11h
```

Que significa 6 meses, 22 dias e 11 horas.

Gostaria de fazer uma função que me retorna exatamente isso: quando fosse informado um valor em segundos, ele transformasse nesse tempo supracitado.

Ainda não encontrei uma que mostre desde o ano, mês, encontrei somente a partir de dias.

Por exemplo ainda não encontrei uma função que retorne:

```
12a6m22d11h
```

Segue a função que tentei elaborar, está incompleta ainda:

```js
const ANO = 31536000
const MES = 2628000
const DIA = (60 * 60) * 24
const HORA = 60 * 60
const MINUTO = 60
const SEGUNDO = 1
const converterPara = tempo => {
    var minutes = 0
    var seconds = 0
    var hours = 0
    var day = 0
    var month = 0
    var mes = ''
    var dia = ''
    var hora = ''
    var min = ''
    var sec = ''
    
    
    if( tempo < MINUTO  ){
        return `${tempo}s`
    }else if( tempo >= MINUTO && tempo < HORA ){
        minutes = Math.floor( (tempo % 3600) / MINUTO );
        seconds = tempo % 60;
        return seconds > 0 ? `${minutes}min${seconds}s` : `${minutes}min`
    }else if ( tempo >= HORA && tempo < DIA ){
        hours = Math.floor( tempo / 3600 );
        minutes = Math.floor( (tempo % 3600) / MINUTO );
        seconds = tempo % 60;
        return minutes > 0 ? seconds > 0 ? `${hours}h${minutes}min${seconds}s` : `${hours}h${minutes}min` : `${hours}h`
    }else if( tempo >= DIA && (Math.floor( (tempo % DIA )/ MES ) == 0) ){        
        
        day = Math.floor( tempo / DIA );
        hours = Math.floor( (tempo % DIA) / HORA  );
        minutes = Math.floor( (tempo % 3600) / MINUTO );
        seconds = tempo % 60;      
        

        if( day > 0 ){
            dia = `${day}d`
            if( hours > 0 ){
                hora = `${hours}h`
                if( minutes > 0 ){
                    min = `${minutes}min`
                    if( seconds > 0 ){
                        sec = `${seconds}s`
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return `${dia}${hora}${min}${sec}`
    }else if( tempo >= DIA && (Math.floor( (tempo % ANO ) / MES ) > 0) ){
        
        month = Math.floor( ( tempo % DIA ) / MES )
        
        day = Math.floor( tempo / MINUTO / MINUTO / MINUTO / 24  );
        hours = Math.floor( (tempo % DIA) / HORA  );
        minutes = Math.floor( (tempo % 3600) / MINUTO );
        seconds = tempo % 60;       
        mes = `${month}m`

        if( day > 0 ){
            dia = `${day}d`
            if( hours > 0 ){
                hora = `${hours}h`
                if( minutes > 0 ){
                    min = `${minutes}min`
                    if( seconds > 0 ){
                        sec = `${seconds}s`
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return `${mes}${dia}${hora}${min}${sec}`
    }
    
}

console.log( 'tempo',converterPara( 2691010 ) );
```

Mas se eu coloco o valor `34261142`, que representa `12m31d12h59min2s`, não chego ao resultado desejado.

Comment: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/locale/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente, vale lembrar que converter uma determinada duração em segundos (ou minutos, ou horas) para meses ou anos sempre será impreciso. Afinal, um mês pode ter 28, 29, 30 ou 31 dias, e um ano pode ter 365 ou 366 dias.

Uma duração em meses e/ou anos sempre poderá resultar em uma quantidade diferente de dias, pois **isso depende das datas envolvidas** (ou seja, da data a partir da qual você conta a duração). Conforme já explicado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/370227/112052):

> *Entre 01/01/2019 e 01/02/2019 há 31 dias. Dividindo por 30 e arredondando, dá 1 mês.*
>
> *Mas entre 01/02/2019 e 01/03/2019 há 28 dias. Dividindo por 30, dá 0,93: se arredondar pra baixo, dá zero meses. Mas entre 1 de fevereiro e 1 de março a diferença não é de um mês? Então devemos arredondar pra cima nesse caso?*
>
> *Mas e se fosse entre 01/01/2019 e 29/01/2019, a diferença também é de 28 dias. Só que entre 1 de janeiro e 29 de janeiro ainda não se passou 1 mês, então eu não posso arredondar pra cima nesse caso. "Ah, então eu só arredondo pra cima se não estiver no mesmo mês".*
>
> *Aí você vê que entre 01/01/2019 e 27/02/2019 a diferença é de 57 dias, que dividido por 30 dá 1,9. Se arredondar pra cima dá 2, mas entre 1 de janeiro e 27 de fevereiro ainda não se passaram dois meses. E agora?*
>
> *Dividir por 30 (ou por qualquer outro valor "médio" arbitrário) sempre terá esse problema. Isso acontece porque meses têm tamanhos variados e a quantidade exata de meses equivalente aos dias vai depender das datas envolvidas.*

E como meses e anos têm tamanhos variados, consequentemente a quantidade de segundos em um mês ou um ano também varia, e qualquer valor médio arbitrário que você usar terá problemas similares aos mencionados acima.

---

Dito isso, se quer continuar usando os valores médios, basta ir dividindo a duração para obter as quantidades de cada unidade, e ir descontando do total (**porém os resultados que obtive são diferentes do que você espera, e abaixo explico os motivos**):

```js
function obterDuracao(tempoTotalSegundos) {
    const duracoes = [ ['ano', 31536000], ['mes', 2628000], ['dia', 3600 * 24], ['hora', 3600], ['minuto', 60], ['segundo', 1] ];
    var segundos = tempoTotalSegundos;
    var result = '';
    for (const[unidade, duracao] of duracoes) {
        // quantidade de "unidade de tempo" contida no total de segundos
        const d = Math.floor(segundos / duracao);
        if (d > 0) // se maior que zero, inclui no resultado
            result += `${d}${unidade[0]}`;
        segundos %= duracao; // desconta a unidade do total
        if (segundos == 0)
            break; // se o tempo já zerou, não tem porque continuar o loop
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(obterDuracao(34261142)); // 1a1m1d2h59m2s
console.log(obterDuracao(2691010));  // 1m17h30m10s
```

Ou seja, primeiro eu pego o total de segundos e vejo quantos anos tem neste total. Se for maior que zero, incluo no resultado final. Depois desconto essa quantidade de anos do total, e o que sobrar eu uso para verificar a próxima unidade (ou, se o total zerar, eu interrompo o *loop*, pois não tem porque continuar).

Só que os resultados foram diferentes dos seus, e na minha opinião, faz sentido. Afinal, você queria que `34261142` resultasse em `12m31d12h59min2s` (12 meses, 31 dias, etc...). Mas 12 meses já são suficientes para formar 1 ano, por isso o meu resultado começar com `1a` faz mais sentido.

Depois, o resultado que você espera tem 31 dias, mas isso é o suficiente para completar 1 mês, por isso no meu resultado (quem tem `1m`) faz mais sentido. E como você usou um valor médio para o mês (2628000 segundos, que corresponde a 30,4166666... dias), então 31 meses dá mais que um mês (por isso que meu resultado também acaba tendo 1 dia, e as 12 horas do seu resultado acabam virando 2, pois essas 10 horas de diferença, mais as horas que sobraram do mês, foram usadas para completar 1 dia).

Claro que o seu resultado também equivale a 34261142 segundos, mas eu ainda acho que "1 ano e 1 mês" faz mais sentido que "12 meses e 31 dias". O mesmo vale para o segundo exemplo: o seu resultado é `31d3h30min10s` (31 dias, que dá mais de 1 mês), enquanto o meu dá `1m17h30m10s` (1 mês, e repare que as horas que "sobraram" não foram suficientes para completar 1 dia, por isso a próxima unidade é "17 horas").