# Como imprimir a idade em número inteiro? É possível colocar o dia, mês e ano em uma só variável?

Tags: python, datetime

```
import datetime

from datetime import date

nome = input('Digite o nome\n')

sobrenome = input('Digite o sobre nome\n')

dia = int(input('dia do nascimento\n'))

mes = int(input('mes do nascimento\n'))

ano = int(input('ano do nascimento\n'))

Nascimento = datetime.date(ano, mes, dia)

Idade = (date.today() - Nascimento)

result =(Idade.days / 365.25)



print(f'Olá! o nome completo é {nome} {sobrenome} e hoje você tem {result} anos')
```

Comment: Seria isso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/224844/112052 ?

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Saber quantos anos, meses, dias, horas, etc se passaram desde uma determinada data](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/224844/saber-quantos-anos-meses-dias-horas-etc-se-passaram-desde-uma-determinada-da)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Para aparecer a idade inteira é necessário formatar o `result`. Tente essa linha de código.

Antes:

```
print(f'Olá! o nome completo é {nome} {sobrenome} e hoje você tem {result} anos')
```

Depois:

```
print(f'Olá! o nome completo é {nome} {sobrenome} e hoje você tem {result:.0f} anos')
```

Arredondar para baixo fica assim:

````
print(f'Olá! o nome completo é {nome} {sobrenome} e hoje você tem {math.floor(result)} anos') 
```
````

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Deu mais ou menos certo, ao imprimir a idade ela veio arredondada para cima. Antes dava 25.7... agora deu 26. Teria como arredondar para baixo?

Comment: Sim, usando o `math.floor()`.
Coloque assim que ele arredonda para baixo.

**print(f'Olá! o nome completo é {nome} {sobrenome} e hoje você tem {math.floor(result)} anos')**

Comment: Não esqueça de importar a biblioteca `import math`

Answer (score -1):

Você pode usar a função [`datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) para interpretar uma string contendo a data de nascimento conforme sua formatação, por exemplo:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> data_nascimento = input('Digite a data de nascimento: ')
Digite a data de nascimento: 15/02/1982
>>> datetime.strptime(data_nascimento, '%d/%m/%Y')
datetime.datetime(1982, 2, 15, 0, 0)
```

Seu programa poderia ser reescrito da seguinte forma:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date

nome = input('Digite o nome: ')
sobrenome = input('Digite o sobrenome: ')
nascimento = input('Digite a data de nascimento: ')

idade = date.today().year - datetime.strptime(nascimento, '%d/%m/%Y').year

print(f'Olá! O nome completo é {nome} {sobrenome} e hoje você tem {idade} anos')
```

Saída:

```
Digite o nome: Fulano
Digite o sobrenome: de Tal
Digite a data de nascimento: 25/12/1980
Olá! O nome completo é Fulano de Tal e hoje você tem 42 anos
```