# Formatar data no java

Tags: java, datetime

Preciso formatar uma data que vem por exemplo:
`20161109103000` para `2016-11-09 10:30:00`.

Já tentei usar `SimpleDateFormat`, `DateTimeFormatter` e não consegui formatar
a data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tente conforme abaixo:

```
String strData = "20161109103000";  
Date dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").parse(strData);
String dataFormatada = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(dt);
```

Saida da variável `dataFormatada`:

> 2016-11-09 10:30:00

Isso vai criar um objeto tipo `util.Date` da string e depois converter para o formato desejado em string, novamente.

Veja o resultado no ideone: https://ideone.com/ZDplvz

Comment: Acho que meu feed está me sacaneando! =D huehue

Comment: @white o meu mostrou certinho, só que eu já tava com a pagina do site aberta haha

Comment: @Articuno muito massa esse ideone. Obrigado! :)

Answer (score 2):

Usando a nova API `dava.time`, com o `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.ResolverStyle;

class Datas {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter original = DateTimeFormatter
                .ofPattern("uuuuMMddHHmmss")
                .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);
        DateTimeFormatter novo = DateTimeFormatter
                .ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
                .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);

        LocalDateTime dataHora = LocalDateTime.parse("20161109103000", original);
        String formatado = dataHora.format(novo);
        System.out.println(formatado);
    }
}
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/pm8e0A)

E veja [esta pergunta e a sua resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/132) para saber mais sobre a API `java.time`.

E é importante lembrar que os objetos do tipo `DateTimeFormatter` só precisam ser criados uma única vez e podem ser reutilizados a vontade. Você pode colocá-los em variáveis estáticas. Isso é algo que não ocorre com o `SimpleDateFormat`.