# Como subtrair horas em java?

Tags: java, android, time, calendar

Estou tentando a dias fazer a diferença de horas na minha aplicação. O caso é o seguinte: Com base no **horário atual e minuto atual**, quero comparar outro horário que tenho em uma string e preciso saber quantas horas e quantos minutos ainda falta, mesmo que o outro horário string seja do dia seguinte.

O horário em string tem o seguinte formato obrigatoriamente:

```
String horario = "07:30";
```

Tentei o seguinte código mas não obtive sucesso:

```
     Calendar hoje = Calendar.getInstance();
        String minutosAtual = 
        String.valueOf(hoje.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
        calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        String strinHora = "14:20";
        String[] hora = strinHora.split(":");
        Integer.parseInt(hora[0]));
        calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
        int minutoInt = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, -Integer.parseInt(hora[0]));
        calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -Integer.parseInt(hora[1]));

        //Define Format of date
        SimpleDateFormat dataFormatada = new 
        SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        String dateStrin = dataFormatada.format(calendar.getTime());
        System.out.println(dateStrin);
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se você puder/quiser usar a API do `java.time`, veja a minha [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/234327/132).

Mas, sem usar o `java.time`, dá para fazer isso ao criar uma classe `Horario`. Essa classe `Horario` é um quebra-galho que serve para quando você não tem a classe `java.time.LocalTime` disponível:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

class Teste {

    private static void mostrar(Horario agora, String objetivo) {
        Horario desejada = Horario.parse(objetivo);
        Horario falta = desejada.diferenca(agora);
        System.out.println(
                "Entre " + agora
                + " e " + desejada
                + ", a diferença é de " + falta
                + ".");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Horario agora = Horario.agora();
        mostrar(agora, "07:30");
        mostrar(new Horario( 5, 30), "07:30");
        mostrar(new Horario( 7, 10), "07:30");
        mostrar(new Horario( 0,  0), "07:30");
        mostrar(new Horario( 7,  0), "07:30");
        mostrar(new Horario( 7, 30), "07:30");
        mostrar(new Horario( 7, 31), "07:30");
        mostrar(new Horario(10,  0), "07:30");
        mostrar(new Horario(19, 30), "07:30");
        mostrar(new Horario(23, 59), "07:30");
        mostrar(new Horario( 0,  0), "23:59");
        mostrar(new Horario(23, 59), "00:00");
    }
}

class Horario {
    private final int horas;
    private final int minutos;

    public Horario(int horas, int minutos) {
        if (horas < 0 || horas > 23 || minutos < 0 || minutos > 59) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        this.horas = horas;
        this.minutos = minutos;
    }

    public int getHoras() {
        return horas;
    }

    public int getMinutos() {
        return minutos;
    }

    public static Horario parse(String input) {
        char[] cs = input.toCharArray();
        if (cs.length != 5) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            if (i == 2) continue;
            if (cs[i] < '0' || cs[i] > '9') throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        if (cs[2] != ':') throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        int h = (cs[0] - '0') * 10 + cs[1] - '0';
        int m = (cs[3] - '0') * 10 + cs[4] - '0';
        return new Horario(h, m);
    }

    public static Horario agora() {
        GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
        return new Horario(gc.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), gc.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    }

    public Horario diferenca(Horario outro) {
        int difHoras = this.horas - outro.horas;
        int difMinutos = this.minutos - outro.minutos;
        while (difMinutos < 0) {
            difMinutos += 60;
            difHoras--;
        }
        while (difHoras < 0) {
            difHoras += 24;
        }
        return new Horario(difHoras, difMinutos);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ((horas < 10) ? "0" : "") + horas + ":" + ((minutos < 10) ? "0" : "") + minutos;
    }
}
```

A classe `Horario` implementa a lógica do horário que você quer. O `GregorianCalendar` é utilizado apenas para pegar a hora do relógio e nada mais. Afinal de contas, trabalhar com o `GregorianCalendar` é algo torturoso (e portanto, tento minimizar a sua utilização). Além de que, não há no pacote `java.util` nenhuma classe que represente horários sem datas.

Eis a saída produzida:

```
Entre 06:27 e 07:30, a diferença é de 01:03.
Entre 05:30 e 07:30, a diferença é de 02:00.
Entre 07:10 e 07:30, a diferença é de 00:20.
Entre 00:00 e 07:30, a diferença é de 07:30.
Entre 07:00 e 07:30, a diferença é de 00:30.
Entre 07:30 e 07:30, a diferença é de 00:00.
Entre 07:31 e 07:30, a diferença é de 23:59.
Entre 10:00 e 07:30, a diferença é de 21:30.
Entre 19:30 e 07:30, a diferença é de 12:00.
Entre 23:59 e 07:30, a diferença é de 07:31.
Entre 00:00 e 23:59, a diferença é de 23:59.
Entre 23:59 e 00:00, a diferença é de 00:01.
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/r4X3kS)

Comment: Essa classe `Horario` é simplesmente fantástica. Achei bem interessante você implementar as conversões junto com comparações tambem :)

Comment: Cara, deu super certo e essa classe é fantástica!!! Só tive que alterar um detalhe: gc.get(Calendar.HOUR para gc.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY. Parabéns @Victor Satafusa e muito obrigado!!

Comment: @Edeson.A.Bizerril Bem observado! Já editei a resposta para arrumar esse detalhe. E também adicionei os métodos `getHoras()` e `getMinutos()` que havia esquecido e que você provavelmente vai precisar depois.

Comment: Valeu! Vc é 10!

Answer (score 3):

Use a classe [**`java.time.LocalTime`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html). Veja mais sobre ela [nesta outra pergunta e resposta minha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/132).

Se quiser fazer sem usar o pacote `java.time`, veja [a outra resposta minha a esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/234343/132).

Eis aqui um código de exemplo:

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.ResolverStyle;

class TesteDatas {
    private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATO_HORAS = DateTimeFormatter
            .ofPattern("HH:mm")
            .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);

    private static LocalTime faltando(LocalTime agora, LocalTime desejada) {
        return desejada.minusHours(agora.getHour()).minusMinutes(agora.getMinute());
    }

    private static void mostrar(LocalTime horario, String objetivo) {
        LocalTime desejada = LocalTime.parse(objetivo, FORMATO_HORAS);
        LocalTime falta = faltando(horario, desejada);
        System.out.println(
                "Entre " + horario.format(FORMATO_HORAS)
                + " e " + desejada.format(FORMATO_HORAS)
                + ", a diferença é de " + falta.format(FORMATO_HORAS)
                + ".");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalTime agora = LocalTime.now();
        mostrar(agora, "07:30");
        mostrar(LocalTime.of( 5, 30), "07:30");
        mostrar(LocalTime.of( 7, 10), "07:30");
        mostrar(LocalTime.of( 0,  0), "07:30");
        mostrar(LocalTime.of( 7,  0), "07:30");
        mostrar(LocalTime.of( 7, 30), "07:30");
        mostrar(LocalTime.of( 7, 31), "07:30");
        mostrar(LocalTime.of(10,  0), "07:30");
        mostrar(LocalTime.of(19, 30), "07:30");
        mostrar(LocalTime.of(23, 59), "07:30");
        mostrar(LocalTime.of( 0,  0), "23:59");
        mostrar(LocalTime.of(23, 59), "00:00");
    }
}
```

Eis aqui a saída (a primeira linha vai variar de acordo com o horário em que você executar):

```
Entre 01:02 e 07:30, a diferença é de 06:28.
Entre 05:30 e 07:30, a diferença é de 02:00.
Entre 07:10 e 07:30, a diferença é de 00:20.
Entre 00:00 e 07:30, a diferença é de 07:30.
Entre 07:00 e 07:30, a diferença é de 00:30.
Entre 07:30 e 07:30, a diferença é de 00:00.
Entre 07:31 e 07:30, a diferença é de 23:59.
Entre 10:00 e 07:30, a diferença é de 21:30.
Entre 19:30 e 07:30, a diferença é de 12:00.
Entre 23:59 e 07:30, a diferença é de 07:31.
Entre 00:00 e 23:59, a diferença é de 23:59.
Entre 23:59 e 00:00, a diferença é de 00:01.
```

A chave para o cálculo da diferença está no método `faltando`:

```
    private static LocalTime faltando(LocalTime agora, LocalTime desejada) {
        return desejada.minusHours(agora.getHour()).minusMinutes(agora.getMinute());
    }
```

Ou seja, para calcular a diferença entre os dois horários, subtraem-se as horas e os minutos. A classe `LocalTime` dá a volta ao redor da meia-noite em caso de horários que seriam negativos ou que ultrapassariam 23:59.

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/mu0Hgw)

Ah, é importante lembrar que os objetos do tipo `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` só precisam ser criados uma única vez e podem ser reutilizados a vontade. Eles são *thread-safe* e imutáveis e você pode colocá-los em variáveis estáticas. Isso é algo que não ocorre com o `java.util.SimpleDateFormatter`.

Comment: Mas na API do android, dependendo de qual ela estiver usando, ainda não há suporte para o java-8. O OP provavelmente teria que importar a lib do jodatime. Veja: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36028494/5524514

Comment: Acho que está havendo algum problema, pois os importes não funcionando no Android Studio. Uso linux, Open JDK, será esse o problema? Tem alguma solução pra resolver, tipo uma dependencia? Grato!

Comment: @Edeson.A.Bizerril Isso daí depende do Java 8. Qual é a versão do seu android?

Comment: @Edeson.A.Bizerrilv adiciona a API do android O que funcionará, ela já da suporte ao java-8 completo.

Comment: @Articuno Veja isso: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary.html - Ou seja, com API level 26, isso é suportado. Entretanto, isso aí ainda não está muito popularizado.

Comment: @VictorStafusa  sim, comentei apos pesquisar aqui, mas essa api ainda é nova, o recurso provavelmente só vai funcionar em modelos com android O, que nem saiu da fase de testes ainda. Talvez seria interessante uma alternativa pra funcionar na api do N tambem.

Comment: @Articuno Postei uma outra resposta sem usar o `java.time` (e o Edeson deve ser notificado sobre ela, naturalmente).

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Só com horários não dá para fazer isso. Neste caso você precisaria ter a data também. Afinal de contas, olhando para uma string `"07:30"` e para uma outra `"07:30"` não dá para saber se estão ou não no mesmo dia se você não tiver essa informação vindo de algum outro lugar.

Comment: Pessoal, muito obrigado pelos comentários de vocês. Quando eu disse: "mesmo que o outro horário string seja do dia seguinte", estou me referindo nos caso semelhantes a esse: "Entre 00:00 e 23:59, a diferença é de 23:59", citado no primeiro exemplo. Observe que nesse exemplo, temos quase 24h de um horario para o outro. No meu caso, não terei situações tão extremas assim. Tenho, na verdade, um vetor que o ultimo horário é 18:30 e o primeiro é 7:30 do dia seguinte.