# Comparação entre datas

Tags: java, data

Eu estou querendo validar a inclusão de datas no meu sistema, referentes ao lote dos produtos, porém acredito estar meio precipitado na forma como eu estou fazendo.

Para o que eu preciso, pensei em 3 situações que eu deveria controlar, que seriam elas:

> A data de fabricação não pode ser posterior/maior que a data de validade;
>
> A data de validade não pode ser anterior/menor a data de fabricação (parece meio redundante se analisar a 1ª validação);
>
> A data de validade não pode ser menor que a data atual;

Eu fiz um exemplo bem **simples** e **enxuto**, apenas para ilustrar, e para que possam ser apontados os erros na comparação entre as datas.

```
  public class ValidaData extends JFrame {

    JLabel labelFab = new JLabel("Fabricação: ");
    CampoData fabricacao = new CampoData();

    JLabel labelVal = new JLabel("Validade: ");
    CampoData validade = new CampoData();

    JButton botao = new JButton("Calcular");

    public ValidaData() {
        setSize(500, 200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel painel = new JPanel();
        painel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        painel.add(labelFab);
        painel.add(fabricacao);

        painel.add(labelVal);
        painel.add(validade);

        painel.add(botao);
        botao.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(90, 20));
        botao();
        add(painel);
    }

    private void botao() {
        botao.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
            valida();
        });
    }

    Date dataAtual;

    private boolean valida() {
        if (fabricacao.getValor().compareTo(validade.getValor()) != 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "A data de fabricação, não pode ser posterior a data de validade!");
            fabricacao.requestFocus();
            return false;
        } 
        
        else if (validade.getValor().compareTo(fabricacao.getValor()) != 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "A data de validade, não pode ser anterior a data de fabricação!");
            validade.requestFocus();
            return false;
        }
        
        else if (validade.getValor().compareTo(dataAtual = new Date()) != 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "A data de validade esta vencida !");
            validade.requestFocus();
            return false;

        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Deu certo !!");
            return true;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(()
                -> {
            ValidaData e = new ValidaData();
            e.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}

class CampoData extends JFormattedTextField {

    private SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    public CampoData() {
        setColumns(6);
        try {
            MaskFormatter mf = new MaskFormatter("##/##/####");
            mf.install(this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void setValor(Object valor) {
        setText(sdf.format((Date) valor));
    }

    public Date getValor() {
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat sdft = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            return sdft.parse(getText());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Não foi possível obter a data!");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize os métodos [`after`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#after-java.util.Date-) e [`before`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#before-java.util.Date-) da classe `util.Date` para comparar datas, ao invés de `compareTo`:

```
private boolean valida() {
    if (fabricacao.getValor().after(validade.getValor())) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "A data de fabricação, não pode ser posterior a data de validade!");
        fabricacao.requestFocus();
        return false;
    } 

    else if (validade.getValor().before(fabricacao.getValor())) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "A data de validade, não pode ser anterior a data de fabricação!");
        validade.requestFocus();
        return false;
    }

    else if (validade.getValor().before(dataAtual = new Date())) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "A data de validade esta vencida !");
        validade.requestFocus();
        return false;

    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Deu certo !!");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Recomendo que leia [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/177130/28595) a respeito da nova API de datas do java, como e porque migrar para ela.

Comment: apenas uma dúvida, no caso de trocar o formatted textField por outro componente, como aquele JDateChooser, a validação pode não ficar correta ? fiz um teste, e mesmo formatando ele, ele pega a data assim: Sat Sep 02 15:19:54 BRT 2017. Porém no "visor" dele, ele me mostra um dd/MM/yyyy, neste caso after e before podem não ser adequados ?

Comment: @GustavoSantos não entendi sua duvida. As alterações que eu fiz no código não levam em conta de onde vem os dados, apenas que as datas são do tipo `util.Date`. Você pode trocar pelo componente que quiser na sua tela(ou até usar em modo texto), **contanto que** garanta que os valores comparados no método `valida()` sejam do tipo mencionado. Eu sugeriria até passar os valores de fabricacao e validade por parametro a este método.