# Erro ao tentar comparar data

Tags: java, data

Estou tentando criar uma validação, para sabe se o usuário tem no mínimo 12 anos.

Eu tentei me basear nessa questão: [Comparação entre datas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/234325/compara%C3%A7%C3%A3o-entre-datas).

Porém, acredito estar comparando de forma errada, já que me da o seguinte erro:

> ```
> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
> at java.util.Date.getMillisOf(Date.java:958)
> at java.util.Date.compareTo(Date.java:978)
> at validacoes.IdadeMaior.testeData(IdadeMaior.java:55)
> at validacoes.IdadeMaior.lambda$botao$0(IdadeMaior.java:47)
> at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
> at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
> at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
> at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
> at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
> at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
> at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
> ```

O que eu deveria fazer ?

o que eu tentei:

```
import com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class IdadeMaior extends JFrame {

    JLabel dataNascLabel = new JLabel("Data nascimento: ");
    JDateChooser dataNasc = new JDateChooser();
    JButton botao = new JButton("Calcular");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IdadeMaior idade = new IdadeMaior();
        idade.setVisible(true);
    }

    public IdadeMaior() {

        JPanel painel = new JPanel();
        painel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        painel.add(dataNascLabel);
        painel.add(dataNasc);
        dataNasc.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(105, 23));

        painel.add(botao);
        botao.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(90, 22));
        botao();
        add(painel);

        setSize(500, 200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private void botao() {
        botao.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
            testeData();
        });
    }

    Date dataAtual;

    private boolean testeData() {
        //data não pode ser menor que 12
        if (dataNasc.getDate().compareTo(dataAtual) <= 12) {
            //if (dataNasc.getDate().before(dataAtual)) {

            System.out.println("Data digitada: " + dataNasc.getDate());

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro!");
            dataNasc.requestFocus();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Onde que estoura o erro?

Comment: Na outra questão eu fui bem enfatizado em dizer pra utilizar os métodos after e before, mas vejo que você está utilizando compareTo.

Comment: Quando o erro ocorre? Que ação você faz?

Comment: @Articuno eu editei ali, coloquei o erro + completo. Da erro quando eu clico no botão que faz o teste das datas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro ocorre porque `dataAtual` nao foi iniciada.

Inicie esta variavel:

```
Date dataAtual = new Date();
```

Outra coisa é sempre checar se o valor resgatado do componente não está nulo, e utilizar `before` para comparar se uma data é anterior a outra.

Para verificar também se a diferença entre os anos das datas é maior que 12, sem sair muito do seu código e utilizando como base [**esta resposta**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10215152/5524514), fiz algumas modificações no seu método:

```
private boolean testeData() {
    //data não pode ser menor que 12

    boolean dataValida = false;

    Date dataNascimento =  dataNasc.getDate();

    if (dataNascimento != null && dataNascimento.before(dataAtual)) {

        Calendar cDataAtual = new GregorianCalendar();
        Calendar cDataNasc = new GregorianCalendar();

        cDataAtual.setTime(dataAtual);
        cDataNasc.setTime(dataNascimento);

        int diferenca = cDataAtual.get(Calendar.YEAR) - cDataNasc.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        if (cDataAtual.get(Calendar.MONTH) < cDataNasc.get(Calendar.MONTH) || cDataAtual.get(Calendar.MONTH) == cDataNasc.get(Calendar.MONTH) && cDataAtual.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) < cDataNasc.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) {
            diferenca--;
                }
        dataValida = diferenca >= 12 ? true : false;
    } 

    return dataValida;
}
```

Dessa forma, basta validar o retorno do método, se `true`, a data é maior que 12 anos, se `false`, é menor que 12.

Veja o teste:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Conforme mencionei na outra resposta, é interessante que você utilize [**a nova API de datas do java8**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/177130/28595), e isso está muito bem explicado toda sua utilização  aqui mesmo no site.

Comment: o before vai pegar a data antes, no caso, pra especificar um intervalo, no caso 12 anos, tem alguma opção de concatenar ou alguma outra forma de saber ?

Comment: @Javinha você quer verificar se a data é anterior a atual em 12 anos?

Comment: eu queria tentar saber se a pessoa tem no mínimo 12 anos,para não deixar ela se cadastrar.

Comment: @Javinha precisa ser com Date? Com java8 essa operação é muito mais facil.

Comment: eu so utilizei o util Date :( ! é muito difícil ?

Comment: @Javinha veja a edição, fiz com base no seu código, mas eu acho que fica bem feio e complexo, apesar de funcional. Claro que "feio" não diz nada, é opiniao minha apenas, pois com a nova API fica bem mais simples, na resposta tem o link explicativo dessa api.

Answer (score 0):

Qual o valor da variável `dataAtual`?
Java **não** vai salvar a data atual nela só por causa do nome (ainda mais sendo PT). O valor inicial é `null` e se conferir a [documentação](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo-java.util.Date-) do `compareTo` vai ler

> **Throws:**
>
> `NullPointerException` - if anotherDate is `null`.

Está faltando `dataAtual = ...`, talvez `dataAtual = new Date()`.

Alem disso também é aconselhável conferir o significado do valor retornado por esse método:

> the value 0 if the argument Date is equal to this Date; a value less than 0 if this Date is before the Date argument; and a value greater than 0 if this Date is after the Date argument.

portanto não faz sentido comparar esse valor com `12` - o método pode retornar o número de secundos entra as datas, ou mili-secundos, ou horas, ou dias, ou apenas -1, 0 e +1...