# Data não recebe valor mais 30 dias

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

Estou com um código que quero verificar se a data é superior a 30 dias com o JodaTime, mas colocando na saída do console o valor não é atribuído. Vi o seguinte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16461361/add-one-day-into-joda-time-datetime

e fiz a mesma ideia, mas continuou não funcionando.

Segue o código :

```
DateTime dataEnvioPrevistoMaisTrintaDias = new DateTime();
dataEnvioPrevistoMaisTrintaDias = peg.getDataEnvioPrevisto().plus(30);
System.out.println("Data Envio : "+ peg.getDataEnvioPrevisto());
System.out.println("Data Envio + 30 : "+dataEnvioPrevistoMaisTrintaDias);
```

Saída no console:

> Data Envio : 2017-09-29T00:00:00.000-03:00
>
> Data Envio + 30 : 2017-09-29T00:00:00.030-03:00

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creio que o correto seria `plusDays()` e não `plus()` como você está utilizando. Altere esta linha:

```
dataEnvioPrevistoMaisTrintaDias = peg.getDataEnvioPrevisto().plus(30);
```

para:

```
dataEnvioPrevistoMaisTrintaDias = peg.getDataEnvioPrevisto().plusDays(30);
```

---

Aconselho dar uma lida [neste post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/28595) que ensina a manipular classes do novo pacote `java.time`. pois a partir do java-8, todas as funcionalidades do jodaTime foram adicionadas nativamente a linguagem.

Answer (score 4):

Você está usando o método errado. Veja a documentação do [método `plus(long)`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#plus(long)):

> **Parameters:**
>   `duration` - the duration, in millis, to add to this one

Traduzindo:

> **Parâmetros:**
>   `duration` - a duração, em millis, para adicionar a este objeto

Ou seja, ao invés de somar 30 dias, você somou 30 milissegundos!

O método que você deveria usar é o [`plusDays(int)`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#plusDays(int)).

Answer (score 3):

O método que está a utilizar para adicionar dias, o `plus()`, não é o correto. Esse serve para adicionar milisegundos, como a própria [documentação](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#plus(long)) indica:

> public DateTime plus(long duration)
>
> ...
>
> Parameters:
>
> duration - the duration, in millis, to add to this one

Em vez disso tem de usar o `plusDays()` que adiciona a quantidade indicada em dias:

```
dataEnvioPrevistoMaisTrintaDias = peg.getDataEnvioPrevisto().plusDays(30);
```

Documentação para [`plusDays()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#plusDays(int))