# Como pegar hora de um campo e somar com 3 minutos em outro?

Tags: java, datetime

Gostaria de saber como faço para pegar a hora do campo `txt_hora` e passar para o `txt_hora2` somando +3 minutos. No caso no campo um estaria 09:50 e passar para o outro 9:53.

Aqui eu entro com a Hora

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E após clicar em "IR" cai nesta tela

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Conforme a imagem, eu preciso transferir a primeira hora para os outros campos, mas contando +3 minutos. Tentei fazer desta forma, mas não consegui:

```
txt_hora2.setText("" + (Integer.parseInt(txt_hora.getText()) + 3));
```

e desta também:

```
txt_hora2.setText("" + (Integer.parseInt(txt_hora.getText()) + (1000 * 60 * 3)));
```

Comment: De que campo está falando? Não tem código deles na pergunta.

Comment: Acho q não expliquei direito. O campo que digo, é um jtextfield onde eu pego uma hora do sitema em hora e minutos. mas eu gostaria de passar essa hora pra outro jtextfield, mas somando +3 minutos

Comment: Veja isso: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40952687/5524514

Comment: Nesse link tem vários métodos, é só escolher um.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem. o que tenho dificuldade em entender é que em um dos campos eu tenho que trazer a hora correta, mas no segundo campo eu ja tenho q trazer ela contando +3 minutos. pq no meu caso são testes que são realizado a cada 3 minutos, e como eu estou trazendo 3 teste de uma só vez, eu preciso somar +3 no cabeçalho deles.

Comment: Rafael, adicione um **[mcve]** do seu código, nem todos podem ver imagens e elas, dependendo do problema, não ajudam muito.

Comment: neste caso não vou saber cria-lo, mas agradeço pela atenção.

Comment: Fica complicado reabrir sua pergunta então, com um [mcve] facilita testar o problema.

Comment: Entendo, mas agradeço mesmo assim pela ajuda.

Comment: Você não quer que sua pergunta seja reaberta?

Comment: Gostaria sim, pois estou parado por conta dessa duvida,  mas não vou saber informar um exemplo nessa condição.

Comment: Pense pelo lado de quem quer te ajudar, com a pergunta fechada, você não vai obter ajuda, e sem um [mcve], fica mais difícil ainda sugerir algo que possa resolver seu problema. Eu mesmo gostaria de te ajudar, mas se você não demonstrar um esforço em facilitar minha colaboração em entender seu problema, como espera obter ajuda? Por isso a gente pede um exemplo testável e simples, no link explica como fazer uma versão simplicada do seu código.

Comment: o problema é que eu não sei desenvolver um exemplo que seja executável, sem o banco de dados, pois essas informações são de lá, e o exemplo que eu poderia fazer só rodaria no netbeans, que não seria aplicável por vocês.

Comment: primeriro você tem converter para um date e após isso usar o Calendar e dar um add() de 3 minutos, a pergunta teria que ta aberta para postar a solução.

De uma olhada nisso
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015536/java-how-to-add-10-mins-in-my-time

Comment: Sugiro que pesquise por JSpinner tambem ao inves de ficar convertendo string pra data e hora. Java possui um componente que já te possibilita recuperar valores Timestamp diretamente sem conversões ou parses, optar por campos de textos é ficar dando voltas em algo que a linguagem simplifica para você.

Answer (score 1):

Como você não apresentou um [exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), vou supor que seja sempre garantido que este campo receba horas formatadas e dentro do intervalo válido de cada unidade de hora para serem consideradas válidas(Ex.: horas  < 24, minutos <60...).

Primeiro você precisa converter o texto do campo de `String` para um tipo temporal, como `util.Date` e depois efetuar esta operação. Uma vez convertido o tempo no tipo certo, você efetua o cálculo, recuperando o tempo em milissegundos e adicionando os 3 minutos também em milissegundos:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
Date time = format.parse(txt_hora.getText());
txt_hora2.setText(sdf.format(new Date(time.getTime() + (3*60*1000))));
```

---

Gostaria de recomendar a leitura a respeito da [**nova API de datas do java**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/177130/28595), pois com ela operações com tempo ficam mais simples.