# Como salvar no tipo Date nesse formato 10-10-2017 usando SimpleDateFormat?

Tags: java, data, simpledateformat

Como salvar um `Date` no formato `10-10-2017` usando `SimpleDateFormat`?

```
Date data = null;
SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
try {
    data = formato.parse(dataInicio);

} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

promocao.setData_inicio(formato.format(data));
```

Comment: Tenho certezxa que isto já foi respondido antes https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=SimpleDateFormat

Comment: Acho que não, preciso muito realizar esse processo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estou me baseando [no seu comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/255054/como-salvar-no-tipo-date-nesse-formato-10-10-2017-usando-simpledateformat#comment523319_255056):

> *...banco de dados salva neste formato "2017-11-13" e no meu programa tenho que converter uma string data = "13-11-2017" para o formado do banco*

Ou seja, no início você tem uma `String` que contém uma data em um determinado formato. Então a primeira coisa a fazer é transformar esta `String` em um [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) (este processo é chamado de *parsing*).

Primeiro você cria um [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) com o mesmo formato da `String`, que no caso é "dia-mês-ano". E depois você usa o método `parse`, passando a `String` que você quer *parsear* (ou seja, transformar em `Date`):

```
String data = "13-11-2017";

// criar um SimpleDateFormat com o mesmo formato da String (dia-mês-ano)
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
// cria o Date, baseado na String
Date date = parser.parse(data);
```

Agora que você já tem o `Date`, você pode transformá-lo em outra `String` com o formato que você quer. Para isso você precisa criar **outro** `SimpleDateFormat` com o formato desejado, que no caso, é "ano-mês-dia" (este processo é chamado de formatação, por isso usamos o método `format`):

```
// criar um SimpleDateFormat com o formato da String que eu quero converter
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
// cria a String
String formatoFinal = formatter.format(date);
```

Com isso, a `String` `formatoFinal` terá o valor `2017-11-13`.

### `Date` ou `String`?

Mas ainda fiquei com uma dúvida: o campo que você está salvando é uma `String` ou um `Date`? Se for uma `String`, então você usa o `formatoFinal` acima.

Mas se for um `Date`, então você não precisa converter, basta salvar o objeto `Date` diretamente. Isso [porque o `Date` **não tem um formato**](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/). O que acontece é que, quando você faz um *select* no banco, ele mostra a data em algum formato específico, mas se o campo está definido como um `Date`, você não precisa se preocupar com este formato ao salvar.

### API `java.time`

Caso você esteja usando Java >= 8, pode usar a [API `java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html), que é [mais nova e melhor do que `Date`](http://blog.caelum.com.br/conheca-a-nova-api-de-datas-do-java-8/), em vários aspectos (mais detalhes [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/112052)).

De qualquer forma, no seu caso é o código é bem parecido, já que é um caso de uso mais simples da API. A ideia é a mesma: para transformar uma `String` em data, usa-se um método de *parsing*, e para transformar a data em `String`, usa-se um método de formatação.

A diferença é que o `java.time` possui vários tipos diferentes para cada situação. No seu caso, você está trabalhando somente com dia, mês e ano, então a melhor opção é usar um [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html):

```
String data = "13-11-2017";
// transformar a String em um LocalDate
// criar um DateTimeFormatter com o mesmo formato da String
DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-uuuu");
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(data, parser);

// transformar o LocalDate em String com o outro formato
// criar um DateTimeFormatter com o formato da String que eu quero converter
// no caso, estou usando uma constante que já retorna o que eu quero
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE;
// cria a String
String formatoFinal = formatter.format(date);
```

Repare que eu usei uma constante já existente ([`ISO_LOCAL_DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE)), que possui o formato que eu quero (ano-mês-dia), mas eu também poderia usar `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd")`.

Na verdade, **neste caso específico**, a `String` `2017-11-13` está no [formato ISO 8601](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), e todas as classes do `java.time` usam este formato como *default*. Então você poderia simplesmente fazer:

```
String formatoFinal = date.toString(); // 2017-11-13
```

---

Caso você use Java 6 ou 7, é possível usar `LocalDate` e `DateTimeFormatter` através do [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), um *backport* para as classes do Java 8. A única diferença é que no Java 8 as classes estão no pacote `java.time`, enquanto no *backport* o pacote é `org.threeten.bp`.

---

**Obs**: quando for guardar datas no banco de dados, eu recomendo usar os tipos de data e hora disponíveis ao invés de usar `Strings`. Assim, você pode salvar diretamente o `Date`, por exemplo. E nos drivers mais novos (se não me engano, a partir do JDBC 4.2) você pode inclusive trabalhar diretamente com as classes do `java.time` (consulte a documentação do seu banco de dados para verificar a compatibilidade).

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi sua dúvida, é bem simples:

```
    SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    System.out.println(formato.format(new Date()));
```

**Obs:** como o colega ali comentou, provavelmente esse tipo de dúvida já foi respondido.

Comment: e caso eu tivesse uma string data = "13-11-2017" como ficaria no seu código?

Comment: Date date = formato.parse("13-11-2017");

Comment: Só o que muda é o formato que você passa em: new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");

Comment: Acho que não entendi muito bem, tenho um campo datainicio no banco de dados do tipo Date que salva neste formato "2017-11-13" e no meu programa tenho que converter uma string data = "13-11-2017" para o formado do banco dito acima.

Comment: Se o campo datainicio é do tipo Date no banco de dados, você pode salvar como um objeto Date do Java mesmo. Esse formato "2017-11-13" me parece ser só como o seu banco de dados exibe a data.

Comment: Qualquer coisa edita sua pergunta e mostra o trecho que você salva a data no banco.