# Unparseable date: "2017-10-30T02:00:00.000Z"

Tags: java, angularjs, data

Estou montando um cadastro onde passo uma data e, ao salvar, está mostrando este erro:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2017-10-30T02:00:00.000Z"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at controller.saude.PacientesController.cadastrarPacientes(PacientesController.java:77) ~[classes/:na]
```

Meu método salvar:

```java
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/pacientes")
    public HttpStatus cadastrarPacientes(@RequestBody ObjectNode json) throws ParseException  {
        
        SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            
            Entidades entidades = new Entidades();
            entidades.setIdEntidade(json.get("pessoa").get("entidade").get("idEntidade").asLong());
            
            Pessoas pessoas = new Pessoas();
            pessoas.setNome(json.get("pessoa").get("nome").textValue());
            pessoas.setNomeSocial(json.get("pessoa").get("nomeSocial").textValue());
            pessoas.setFoto(json.get("pessoa").get("foto").textValue());
            pessoas.setNomeSocial(json.get("pessoa").get("nomePai").textValue());
            pessoas.setNomeMae(json.get("pessoa").get("nomeMae").textValue());
            pessoas.setDataNascimento(formato.parse(json.get("pessoa").get("dataNascimento").textValue()));
            pessoas.setEntidade(new Entidades());
            pessoas.setEntidade(entidades);
            pessoas.setTipoPessoa(json.get("pessoa").get("tipoPessoa").textValue());
    }
```

Uso HTML e Angular no front-end:

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label>Data Nascimento :</label> <input   name="data" id="data"  type="date" class="form-control" ng-model="paciente.pessoa.dataNascimento" format-date />
</div>
```

E estou usando essa diretiva:

```js
app.directive("formatDate", function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, modelCtrl) {
            modelCtrl.$formatters.push(function(modelValue) {
                if (modelValue){
                    return new Date(modelValue);
                }
                else {
                    return null;
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

O JSON que está chegando no backend está assim:

```js
{
    "pessoa": {
        "nome": "aa",
        "nomeSocial": "aa",
        "dataNascimento": "2017-10-30T02:00:00.000Z",
        "tipoPessoa": "F",
        "entidade": {
            "idEntidade": "1"
        },
        "nomeMae": "a"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O *pattern* utilizado no `SimpleDateFormat` tem que representar o formato da data que você recebe.

Ao invés de:

```
SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Use:

```
SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");
```

Na [documentação da classe `SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) há uma tabela relacionando cada letra ao elemento que ela representa.

Answer (score 3):

A partir do Java 8 você pode usar a [API `java.time`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/112052).

No caso, a string `"2017-10-30T02:00:00.000Z"` representa uma data e hora em [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) ([é o que o "Z" no final indica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Coordinated_Universal_Time_(UTC)), que está em UTC), e além disso ela está no formato definido pela [norma ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), que já é aceito diretamente pelas classes desta API.

Como está em UTC e você precisa converter para [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), uma opção é usar [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html):

```java
// obtém o java.time.Instant
Instant instant = Instant.parse("2017-10-30T02:00:00.000Z");
// converte para java.util.Date
Date date = Date.from(instant);
```

---

Não faça como a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/301858/112052), que ignorou o "Z". O código até "funciona" (no sentido de não dar erro), mas isso acontece porque [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) é uma classe muito permissiva e não costuma dar erro em muitos casos nos quais deveria - veja alguns exemplos [aqui](https://eyalsch.wordpress.com/2009/05/29/sdf/) e [aqui](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue172.html).

O problema é que se você ignorar o "Z", a data não é mais considerada em UTC, e sim no timezone *default* da JVM. Por exemplo, minha JVM está usando como *default* o timezone `America/Sao_Paulo`, que corresponde ao Horário de Brasília. O que acontece se ignorarmos o "Z"?

```java
String s = "2017-10-30T02:00:00.000Z";

// ignorando o Z
SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
System.out.println(formato.parse(s)); // Mon Oct 30 02:00:00 BRST 2017

// não ignorando o Z
formato = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");
System.out.println(formato.parse(s)); // Mon Oct 30 00:00:00 BRST 2017
```

Repare que o horário resultante foi diferente. No primeiro caso, como o "Z" foi ignorado, considerou-se que a data e hora estão no timezone **default** da JVM (no meu caso, às 2 da manhã do Horário de Brasília). No segundo caso, ao não ignorar o "Z", o resultado foi meia-noite no Horário de Brasília (que corresponde à 2 da manhã em UTC - a diferença é de 2 horas porque em 30 de outubro de 2017, estávamos em Horário de Verão).

Usando `Instant`, como no primeiro exemplo acima, o "Z" também não é ignorado (que é o correto, pois o fato de estar em UTC é uma informação importante, e ignorá-lo pode resultar em uma data/hora que corresponde a um instante completamente diferente).

---

Não ficou claro se as strings sempre vêm em UTC, ou se elas podem ter outros [*offsets*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) (como por exemplo `"2017-10-30T02:00:00.000-03:00"`, para uma data e hora 3 horas atrás do UTC). Se for esse o caso, pode usar um [`java.time.OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html):

```java
// obtém o java.time.OffsetDateTime
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2017-10-30T02:00:00.000-03:00");
// converte para java.util.Date
Date date = Date.from(odt.toInstant());
```

`OffsetDateTime` também funciona para a string original (`"2017-10-30T02:00:00.000Z"`).

Answer (score 0):

Pra mim sem o Z no final funcionou:

```
SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
```