# Converter String de sequência errada para ser exibida

Tags: java, data

Possuo uma *string* no seguinte formato `2017-12-08`, porém preciso exibi-lá formatada para o usuário da seguinte forma: `08/12/2017`, Pensei em usar o `SimpleDateFormat` porém para isso preciso que a variável esteja no formato `Date`, e não estou conseguinte converter essa `String` em `Date`.

Como poderia fazer isso, ou há algum modo de formatar essa *string* para que seja exibida do jeito que preciso ao usuário?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String strDate = "2017-12-08";

SimpleFormatDate oldFormat =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
SimpleDateFormat newFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

System.out.print(newFormat.format(oldFormat.parse(strDate)));
```

Veja funcionando no ideone: https://ideone.com/6lTkua

Porém, recomendo que avalie trabalhar com [**a nova API de datas do java versão 8**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/28595)