# Percorrer entre duas datas

Tags: java, android, datetime, data

Tenho duas datas em milliseconds.
Eu preciso recuperar cada dia desse período para fazer um insert no banco de dados. Pensei em fazer um for para pegar cada dia desse período, mas não tenho ideia de como fazer!

Comment: Essas datas são o que? Valores `long` obtidos por `System.currentTimeMillis()`?

Answer (score 0):

Dá para fazer assim, usando a API a partir do java 8:

```
long a = ...;
long b = ...;
Instant ia = Instant.ofEpochMilli(a);
Instant ib = Instant.ofEpochMilli(b);
LocalDate lda = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(ia, ZoneId.of("Z")).toLocalDate();
LocalDate ldb = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(ib, ZoneId.of("Z")).toLocalDate();

List<LocalDate> dates = new ArrayList<>();
for (LocalDate ld = lda; !ld.isAfter(ldb); ld = ld.plusDays(1)) {
    dates.add(ld);
}
```

Veja mais sobre isso [nessa outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/132).