# Parsing de um timestamp com timezone

Tags: java, datetime, data, timestamp, parse

Eu estava fazendo um pequeno código para implementar um caso de tratamento em um módulo de aplicação de um amigo e fiquei preso com um problema.

Este é um teste unitário. Para colocar no módulo da aplicação eu teria que fazer uns ajustes ao inserir no código nativo dele, mas basicamente eu estou recebendo uma `String` de um banco de dados no formato similar ao da `String` dada abaixo:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {
    String value = "2018-4-25 0.0.0.0 -3:00";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss");

    if (value.charAt(6) == '-') {
        SimpleDateFormat myformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-dd H.m.s.S X");
        Date d1 = myformat.parse(value);
        String result = sdf.format(d1);
        result = result + ", " + "000000000 " + "-03:00";
        System.out.println(result);

    } else {
        SimpleDateFormat myformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd H.m.s.S X");
        Date d1 = myformat.parse(value);
        String result = sdf.format(d1);
        result = result + ", " + "000000000 " + "-03:00";
        System.out.println(result);
      }
  }
}
```

Mas a mensagem que eu recebo é:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelliJ IDEA\lib\idea_rt.jar=63052:C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelliJ IDEA\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\...\IdeaProjects\untitled\out\production\untitled Main

Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2018-4-25 0.0.0.0 -3:00"
    at java.base/java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:395)
    at Main.main(Main.java:23)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Nosso idioma é o **Português**, traduza sua pergunta.

Comment: Perdão, não havia notado q está em pt-br

Enfim, é um código que eu recebo uma string vinda de um banco de dados e preciso converter para Date. Porém, o parse não está indo bem. Isso que eu não tô compreendendo

Comment: Traduz sua pergunta primeiro, senão ela vai ser fechada.

Comment: Pronto!
Obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Doucmentação do formato `X`:

> ```
> Letter  Component     Presentation         Examples
> X       Time zone     ISO 8601 time zone   -08; -0800; -08:00
> ```

e mais

> ```
> ISO8601TimeZone:
>          OneLetterISO8601TimeZone
>          TwoLetterISO8601TimeZone
>          ThreeLetterISO8601TimeZone
>  OneLetterISO8601TimeZone:
>          Sign TwoDigitHours
>           Z
>  TwoLetterISO8601TimeZone:
>          Sign TwoDigitHours Minutes
>           Z
>  ThreeLetterISO8601TimeZone:
>          Sign TwoDigitHours  : Minutes
>           Z
> ```

ou seja, o formato para o fuso horário, usando o formato `X`, **exige dois dígitos** para a hora. Se tentar interpretar o texto `"2018-4-25 0.0.0.0 -03:00"` deve funcionar. 
Outra opção: adicione `"GMT"` antes do fuso - `"2018-4-25 0.0.0.0 GMT-3:00"` - e uso o formato `z` ou `Z`.

Seu código tambem está um pouco estranho - não é necessário testar se a setima letra (indice 6) é `-`. Por exemplo para interpretação com o formato `y`, a classe `SimpleDateFormat` apenas diferencia entre o formato abreviado (`"y"` ou `"yy"`)  e o completo com mais de duas repetições do `y`. Semelhante para a interpretação do mes...

*Essa resposta foi baseada na [documentação oficial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)*

Answer (score 1):

Conforme dito na [resposta do Carlos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/295614/112052), a classe [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) suporta apenas *offsets* com 2 dígitos na hora (algo como `-03:00`).

Uma maneira de contornar esse problema é quebrar a `String` em 2 partes: uma com a data e hora, e outra com o *offset*, e usar esse valor para setar o timezone do `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
String value = "2018-4-25 0.0.0.0 -3:00";
// separar data e hora (2018-4-25 0.0.0.0) do offset (-3:00)
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("^(.*) ([\\+\\-]\\d{1,2}:\\d\\d)$").matcher(value);
if (matcher.matches()) {
    String datetime = matcher.group(1);
    String offset = matcher.group(2);

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-dd H.m.s.S");
    // felizmente, a classe TimeZone aceita offsets com um dígito na hora
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT" + offset));

    Date date = sdf.parse(datetime);
}
```

Dependendo da versão do Java que você usa, também é possível usar a [API `java.time`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/112052) (a partir do Java 8). Você usa esta API para fazer o parse e depois converte para [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html).

No Java 6 e 7, também é possível usar estas classes através do [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) - as classes são praticamente as mesmas, as únicas diferenças são que elas ficam no pacote `org.threeten.bp` (ao invés de `java.time`) e a conversão para `Date` é um pouco diferente do Java 8 (explicarei abaixo).

De qualquer forma, o Java 8 também tem este problema de não aceitar *offsets* com apenas um dígito nas horas. [Isso só foi corrigido no Java 9](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8066806).

O código no Java 8, usando `java.time` (ou Java 6 e 7 usando ThreeTen Backport) está abaixo. Observe que o data/hora e o *offset* são tratados separadamente, e depois unidos para criar um [`java.time.OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html), que depois é convertido para `Date`.

Para fazer o *parsing* eu uso um [`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) para a data/hora e outro para o *offset*. O resultado da data e hora é colocado em um [`java.time.LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) (uma classe que possui exatamente isso: somente a data e hora), e o *offset* é colocado em um [`java.time.ZoneOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html) (uma classe que representa um *offset* - no caso, o `-3:00`).

```
String value = "2018-4-25 0.0.0.0 -3:00";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("^(.*) ([\\+\\-]\\d{1,2}:\\d\\d)$").matcher(value);
if (matcher.matches()) {
    String datetime = matcher.group(1);
    String offset = matcher.group(2);
    DateTimeFormatter datetimeParser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-M-dd H.m.s.S");
    DateTimeFormatter offsetParser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("O");

    LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.parse(datetime, datetimeParser);
    ZoneOffset zOffset = ZoneOffset.from(offsetParser.parse("GMT" + offset));
    OffsetDateTime odt = dt.atOffset(zOffset);

    // converte para java.util.Date
    // Java 8
    Date date = Date.from(odt.toInstant());

    // Java 6 e 7 (ThreeTen Backport)
    Date date = DateTimeUtils.toDate(odt.toInstant());
}
```

A partir do Java 9, é possível fazer o *parsing* de uma vez:

```
String value = "2018-4-25 0.0.0.0 -3:00";
DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // data e hora
    .appendPattern("uuuu-M-dd H.m.s.S ")
    // offset com um dígito nas horas
    .appendOffset("+H:MM", "+0:00")
    // criar formatter
    .toFormatter();
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(value, fmt);

Date date = Date.from(odt.toInstant());
```