# Como comparar todos os valores de um array com uma variável

Tags: java, array

Gostaria de saber se é possível eu ter um array com várias datas e saber se uma outra data é maior que todas as datas dentro do array.

Por exemplo:

```
Date[] datas = {"02/02/2000","03/03/2000","04/04/2000"};
Date data1 = "03/01/2000";
```

Teria como eu saber se a `data1` é menor que todas as datas do array datas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiramente, não dá para converter diretamente de `String` para `Date`. Por isso, precisaremos de uma etapa de conversão:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    sdf.setLenient(false);

    Date[] datas = {sdf.parse("02/02/2000"), sdf.parse("03/03/2000"), sdf.parse("04/04/2000")};
    Date data1 = sdf.parse("03/01/2000");
```

Assim sendo, há pelo menos 3 formas de se testar se a `data1` é menor que as que estão no array.

A primeira é percorrer as datas do array e compará-las com a data desejada:

```
        boolean menor1 = true;
        for (Date d : datas) {
            if (d.compareTo(data1) < 0) {
                menor1 = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(menor1 ? "Era a menor." : "Não era a menor.");
```

A segunda é colocar todas essas datas em um `Set` ordenado e ver se a que você quer é a primeira (e portanto a menor):

```
        SortedSet<Date> datas2 = new TreeSet<>();
        for (Date d : datas) {
            datas2.add(d);
        }
        datas2.add(data1);
        boolean menor2 = data1.equals(datas2.first());
        System.out.println(menor2 ? "Era a menor." : "Não era a menor.");
```

A terceira é semelhante à primeira, mas valendo-se de um `Stream`:

```
        boolean menor3 = Stream.of(datas).allMatch(d -> data1.compareTo(d) < 0);
        System.out.println(menor3 ? "Era a menor." : "Não era a menor.");
```

O código completo para mostrar esses exemplos é esse:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;

class TesteDatas {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        sdf.setLenient(false);

        Date[] datas = {sdf.parse("02/02/2000"), sdf.parse("03/03/2000"), sdf.parse("04/04/2000")};
        Date data1 = sdf.parse("03/01/2000");

        // Exemplo 1.
        boolean menor1 = true;
        for (Date d : datas) {
            if (d.compareTo(data1) < 0) {
                menor1 = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(menor1 ? "Era a menor." : "Não era a menor.");

        // Exemplo 2.
        SortedSet<Date> datas2 = new TreeSet<>();
        for (Date d : datas) {
            datas2.add(d);
        }
        datas2.add(data1);
        boolean menor2 = data1.equals(datas2.first());
        System.out.println(menor2 ? "Era a menor." : "Não era a menor.");

        // Exemplo 3.
        boolean menor3 = Stream.of(datas).allMatch(d -> data1.compareTo(d) < 0);
        System.out.println(menor3 ? "Era a menor." : "Não era a menor.");
    }
}
```

[**Veja aqui todas elas funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/aWeVvL)

Por fim, recomendo migrar para os tipos do pacote `java.time`. Veja mais sobre isso [**nessa outra pergunta.**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/132)

Para saber se é maior que todas as outras ao invés de menor, na primeira e na terceira abordagem, basta trocar o `<` por `>`. Na segunda, basta trocar `first` por `last`.

Você também pode querer considerar se a primeira e a terceira abordagem devem usar `<` por `<=` para o caso de a data já estar no array dado e mesmo assim ser considerada menor que todas (ou `>=` se quiser verificar se é maior ao invés de menor).

Comment: Obrigado, amigo. A segunda opção me serviu muito bem.