# Como fazer LocalDateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("America/Sao_Paulo")) no Java.time

Tags: java, datetime, data, java-8, timezone

Gostaria de saber se há alguma forma de imitar esse código no `java.time`:

```
LocalDateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("America/Sao_Paulo"))
```

Não trabalho muito bem com data no Java, se puderem me explicar também o que esse código faz.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pelo código (`DateTimeZone.forId`), estou assumindo que você está usando o [Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html).

No caso, `DateTimeZone.forID("America/Sao_Paulo")` cria um objeto que contém todas as informações do timezone `America/Sao_Paulo`.
Basicamente, o timezone serve - entre outras coisas - para saber a data e hora atual (levando em conta coisas como o horário de verão e mudanças no fuso horário ao longo da história - você pode ver mais informações na própria [wiki da tag timezone](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info)).

Agora, neste exato instante, em cada parte do mundo, a data e hora atual podem ser diferentes. No Brasil agora é 15 de março de 2019 às 16h, mas no Japão já é dia 16 às 4 da manhã. Neste caso, o timezone serve para saber exatamente quais valores de data e hora usar. Os nomes no formato `Continente/Regiao` (como `America/Sao_Paulo`) são padronizados pela [IANA](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) (que mantém a base de timezones que o Java usa **¹**).

Quando o [construtor de `LocalDateTime` recebe um `DateTimeZone`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDateTime.html#LocalDateTime-org.joda.time.DateTimeZone-), ele usa o timezone correspondente para saber quais são os valores do dia, mês, ano, hora, minuto, segundo e milissegundos referentes à data e hora atual. No caso, o `LocalDateTime` terá a data e hora atual, de acordo com o timezone `America/Sao_Paulo` (ou seja, os valores de data e hora terão como base o Horário Oficial de Brasília).

---

No [`java.time`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/112052), a forma equivalente é:

```
LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo"))
```

A ideia é a mesma. A classe [`java.time.ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) cria um objeto correspondente ao timezone `America/Sao_Paulo`, e o método [`now()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#now-java.time.ZoneId-) usa este timezone para saber os valores da data e hora atuais.

Como `LocalDateTime` não tem informações sobre o timezone, o `ZoneId` é descartado (ele não faz parte do `LocalDateTime`, ele só foi usado para obter os valores da data e hora atual).

---

Vale lembrar que o Joda-Time não é 100% idêntico ao `java.time` (veja [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/413649/112052) para mais detalhes). Muitas classes possuem os mesmos nomes e métodos, e muitos dos seus conceitos e ideias foram aproveitados no Java 8. Mas há várias diferenças também, e elas são explicadas em mais detalhes [aqui](http://blog.joda.org/2009/11/why-jsr-310-isn-joda-time_4941.html) e [aqui](http://blog.joda.org/2014/11/converting-from-joda-time-to-javatime.html).

---

(1): O Joda-Time mantém sua própria cópia do *database* da IANA, separado da JVM. Inclusive, este [pode ser atualizado de forma independente da JVM](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/tz_update.html).

Comment: Funcionou, ótima explicação, muito obrigado!