# Como inserir uma data em uma tupla SQL e Java

Tags: java, sql, data, calendar

Estou tentado inserir uma data em uma tupla em SQL mas não consegui,
usando o `Calendar.getInstance()` só consigo a data atual, mas quero escolher outra data para adicionar.

```
public class Prova {

private Calendar data;

public Prova (         
        Calendar data){

    this.data = data;

}

public Calendar getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(Calendar data) {
    this.data = data;
}
```

Classe DAO

```
 public class ProvaDAO {

    public void inserirProva(Prova prova) throws SQLException {

    Connection conn = null;
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBCConection.getUrl(),
            JDBCConection.getUsuario(), JDBCConection.getSenha());

    String sql = "insert into prova (data) values (?)";
    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

    java.sql.Date dataParaGravar = new java.sql.Date(
            Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());

    stmt.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()));

    stmt.execute();
    stmt.close();

    }
```

Main

```
// Não dá certo salvar a data assim 
Prova prova = new Prova(Calendar.getInstance().set(2018, 1, 1));
provaDAO.inserirProva(prova);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao fazer:

```
stmt.setDate(3, new java.sql.Date(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()));
```

Você está criando outra instância de `Calendar` contendo a data/hora atual (pois é isso que [`getInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance()) retorna). Em vez disso, você deveria usar o `Calendar` que está na classe `Prova`.

Outro detalhe é que para criar a data da prova você usou o método [`set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set(int,%20int,%20int)), que não retorna nada (veja na [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set(int,%20int,%20int)) que este método é `void`, ou seja não retorna nenhum valor), então este código sequer compila:

```
Prova prova = new Prova(3, 4, Calendar.getInstance().set(2018, 1, 1));
provaDAO.inserirProva(prova);
```

O certo é primeiro criar o `Calendar`, setar os valores e em seguida passar para o construtor de `Prova`:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(2018, Calendar.JANUARY, 1);
Prova prova = new Prova(3, 4, cal);
provaDAO.inserirProva(prova);
```

E dentro do DAO use a data da prova:

```
stmt.setDate(3, new java.sql.Date(prova.getData().getTimeInMillis()));
```

Repare que usei [`Calendar.JANUARY`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#JANUARY), que deixa o código um pouco mais claro, já que nesta API os meses começam em zero (janeiro é zero, fevereiro é 1, etc). Ou seja, `set(2018, 1, 1)` seta a data para 1 de fevereiro de 2018. Se você quer janeiro, deve fazer `set(2018, 0, 1)`, mas usar as constantes deixa o código menos confuso.

---

### Java 8

A partir do Java 8 existe a [API `java.time`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/112052), que você pode usar em vez de `Calendar`. Por exemplo, para criar uma data específica (apenas o dia, mês e ano), você pode usar a classe [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html):

```
// ao contrário de Calendar, nesta API janeiro é 1
LocalDate data = LocalDate.of(2018, 1, 1); // 1 de janeiro de 2018
```

E para converter para `java.sql.Date`, basta usar o método [`valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#valueOf-java.time.LocalDate-). Para converter o `java.sql.Date` de volta para `LocalDate`, use o método [`toLocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#toLocalDate--)

```
LocalDate data = ....
// converter para java.sql.Date
java.sql.Date sqlDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf(data);
// converter de volta para LocalDate
data = sqlDate.toLocalDate();
```

Ou seja, bastaria você mudar a classe `Prova` para ter um `LocalDate` em vez de um `Calendar`, e para salvar no banco use `valueOf` para obter o `java.sql.Date` e `toLocalDate()` para obter de volta o `LocalDate`.

---

Caso o banco de dados que você está usando tenha um driver compatível com o JDBC 4.2, é possível trabalhar diretamente com as classes do `java.time`, usando os métodos `setObject` da classe [`java.sql.PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) e `getObject` da classe [`java.sql.ResultSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html). Um exemplo com `LocalDate` seria:

```
LocalDate data = ...
// gravar o LocalDate
PreparedStatement ps = ...
ps.setObject(1, data);

// obter o LocalDate do banco
ResultSet rs = ...
LocalDate data = rs.getObject(1, LocalDate.class);
```

Comment: Deu certo, em termos, porque o stmt.setDate(3, prova.getData()); pede um java.sql.Date e esta recebendo um java.util.calendar

Comment: @BulletSentence Atualizei a resposta

Comment: Agora sim deu certo usando "stmt.setDate(3, new java.sql.Date(prova.getData().getTimeInMillis()));" Obrigado!

Comment: @BulletSentence Se vc está usando Java >= 8 pode usar as classes do `java.time`, que são bem melhores do que `Calendar`, adicionei uma breve explicação sobre isso na resposta