# Porque meu programa só funciona se eu evito o try catch do parse?

Tags: java, android, data, calendar

Recebo uma data do SQLITE mas não consigo entender onde está o erro, simplesmente não é visível.

```
String dateValue = empDatadevolucao.getText()
        .toString()
        .trim();

SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

//>> int date = Integer.parseInt(empDatadvl.getText().toString());
Date date = null;
try {
    date = ft.parse(dateValue);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Calendar renova = Calendar.getInstance();
//Somente comentando renova.setTime(date); para evitar que caia no try catch do date = ft.parse(dataValue)

renova.setTime(date); 
renova.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
date = renova.getTime();
String strDate = ft.format(date);

final TextView newDate =  findViewById(R.id.exibeData);
newDate.setText(strDate);
```

Porém se eu comentar ele captura a data do calendário, não formata e não faz o parse.
Entrega algo assim:

```
data atual     15 abr 2019 
data renovação 16 abr 2019
```

Sendo que o esperado era para ele pegar o valor de `empDatadevolucao`, que mostra 20/04/2019 e somar mais 1 dia `renova.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);` (21/04/2019).

Comment: Esse dateValue devolve a data como?? Testei aqui com o dateValue sendo "20/04/2019" e pra mim está certo o código, tá devolvendo no strDate "21/04/2019"

Comment: recebo a data assim 15 abr 2019

Comment: Hmm entendi, o problema esta no nome do mes abreviado, chegando em casa eu mando o jeito certo de converter. Daqui 1 hr mais ou menos

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não tem como o `setTime` cair no `try`/`catch` do `parse`, pois a chamada de `setTime`, além de estar **depois**, está **fora** do `try`/`catch`.

O que acontece é o seguinte: `dateValue` contém a `String` "15 abr 2019" ([conforme seu comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/375935/porque-meu-programa-s%C3%B3-funciona-se-eu-evito-o-try-catch-do-parse#comment746615_375935)). O `SimpleDateFormat` está usando o formato `dd/MM/yyyy` (dia/mês/ano) - o detalhe é que, além das barras, `MM` corresponde ao valor numérico do mês, mas sua string contém o nome do mês ("abr"). Por isso o `parse` dá erro.

Ao dar `ParseException`, você imprime a exceção (`e.printStackTrace()`), mas o código continua executando. E como deu erro no `parse`, a variável `date` está `null`, e ao passar `null` para `setTime`, o resultado é **outra** exceção (no caso, um `NullPointerException`).

Ou seja, o `setTime` dá **outro** erro. Ele não está voltando para o `try`/`catch`. O problema deste código é que se der `ParseException`, você continua executando o restante. Mas se ocorrer erro no `parse`, significa que você não conseguiu criar o `Date`, então você não deveria prosseguir.

Um jeito de arrumar isso é colocar todo o bloco de código dentro do `try`, e no `catch` você coloca alguma mensagem de erro dizendo que não foi possível obter a data.

Já para o formato da data (assumindo que a string que você passa para o método `parse` seja "15 abr 2019"), você deve alterar o formato para usar `MMM` em vez de `MM`, pois assim pegará o nome do mês abreviado (conforme consta na [documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#date-and-time-patterns)). E como o nome do mês está em português, use também um `java.util.Locale` para definir que o idioma é português:

```
SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy", new Locale("pt", "BR"));
Date date = null;
try {
    date = ft.parse("15 abr 2019");
    Calendar renova = Calendar.getInstance();
    renova.setTime(date);
    ... some 1 dia, como já está fazendo
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // erro ao criar o Date, exiba alguma mensagem de erro
}
```

Se você não especificar um `Locale`, será usado o *locale default* da JVM, e nem sempre é garantido que seja português. Se você quer fazer *parsing* de uma string e já sabe em que idioma ela está, é melhor passar o `Locale` correspondente para `SimpleDateFormat`.

Se o formato for `20 de abr de 2019`, por exemplo, basta mudar para:

```
SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("dd 'de' MMM 'de' yyyy", new Locale("pt", "BR"));
```

O texto `de` deve estar entre aspas simples, assim a letra `d` não é interpretada como o dia, e sim como o próprio caractere `d`.

---

## `java.time`

A partir da API Level 26 (necessário minSdkVersion>=26, não basta ter compileSdkVersion>=26), é possível usar o [pacote `java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary), a nova API de datas do Java, muito superior à `Date` e `Calendar`.

Para a data, você pode usar um [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/LocalDate.html), uma classe que representa apenas o dia, mês e ano (que é exatamente o que você precisa). E para transformar uma `String` em uma data, use um [`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html):

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Locale;

DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // aceitar nome do mês em minúsculo
    .parseCaseInsensitive()
    // dia mês ano
    .appendPattern("dd MMM uuuu")
    // usar Locale para idioma português
    .toFormatter(new Locale("pt", "BR"));
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("15 abr 2019", fmt);
date = date.plusDays(1); // soma 1 dia
String strDate = fmt.format(date);
```

Usei `parseCaseInsensitive()` pois em algumas versões da JVM os meses em português podem estar com a primeira letra maiúscula, então é interessante usar esta opção para o *parsing* ser feito corretamente.

Repare também no uso de `uuuu` em vez de `yyyy` para o ano. Para uma explicação mais detalhada sobre isso (e sobre a API em geral), dê uma olhada [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/112052).

Para o formato `20 de abr de 2019`, basta mudar a linha que tem o *pattern* para:

```
.appendPattern("dd 'de' MMM 'de' uuuu")
```

---

Em API Levels < 26, você pode usar o [ThreeTen Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), um excelente *backport* do `java.time`. A maioria das funcionalidades do Java 8 está presente, com algumas diferenças: em vez de estarem no pacote `java.time`, as classes ficam no pacote `org.threeten.bp`. [Veja aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754) como configurá-lo para Android.

Comment: Ótima resposta, era exatamente isso que eu ia propor.

Comment: essas dicas foram excelentes, mas estou na API levels 22 conforme citou é a partir da 26.
então terei que esperar para que eu normalize todo o código tudo primeiro para depois fazer essas correções.

Comment: @user3873165 Na verdade, o primeiro código que sugeri com `SimpleDateFormat` vc pode usar. O que é exclusivo da 26 é o `java.time`, que substitui `Date` e `Calendar` :-)

Comment: referenciei o setTime pois ele usa um objeto do parse --> date = ft.parse(dateValue); 
se faz o parse, tudo ok,
se não faz, desvio, erro, npe, etc...

Comment: @user3873165 Mas é o que disse, se o `parse` deu erro, não tem porque continuar o restante do código, pois vc não terá um `Date` válido... É melhor mostrar uma mensagem de erro dizendo que não conseguiu ler a data ou algo assim

Comment: sim, perfeito, nesse sentido só tenho a agradecer, mas esse é mesmo o motivo de eu estar aqui trabalhando junto ao código, na realidade um atualização do IDE Android Studio me forçou a procurar soluções atuais aos meus problemas. Algumas funções já não funcionavam então estou trocando uma a uma.

Comment: realmente recebo a data como sendo sql - pt br:
15 abr 2019

Comment: erro: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable
date: "20 de abr de 2019"

Comment: @user3873165 Atualizei a resposta. Mas basicamente, o formato que vc passa para `SimpleDateFormat` sempre deve corresponder a string que vc está passando para `parse`