# Classe calendar java

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Boa tarde! surgiu a necessidade de criar uma classe que recebe duas datas na minha atividade, pra deixar o código menos sujo. Dei uma pesquisada e encontrei a classe calendar, mas não entendi totalmente seu funcionamento. No meu caso, o usuário insere a data de inicio do aluguel de um carro(dia, mes e ano), e a data que o carro será devolvido(dia, mes e ano). Como eu posso fazer isso? estou tentando a um tempo, mas sem noção nenhuma da classe, é meio difícil. 
Programo no bluej.

Comment: Boa tarde, você precisa criar dois atributos na sua classe, vamos chamar ela de aluguel, você irá criar o atributo dataAluguel do tipo Calendar/Date como preferir, e o segundo atributo será o dataFinalAluguel com o mesmo tipo do primeiro atributo, isso te ajuda?

Comment: eu usei jodatime pra fazer isso, mas por algum motivo tá gerando exceção somente na data inicial.

Comment: Por favor clique em [edit] e coloque o código, e também a mensagem da exceção. Com código fica mais fácil vc obter uma resposta :-) Leia também [ask] e como montar um [mcve]

Comment: E se estiver usando Java >=8 não precisa mais do Joda-Time (que é considerado um projeto "encerrado"), pois agora existe a [API `java.time`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/112052). Caso esteja usando Java 6 ou 7, o `java.time` não está disponível, mas em vez do Joda-Time, dá para usar o [ThreeTen Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (um backport do Java 8, com a maioria das funcionalidades disponíveis - [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/370367/112052) tem um pequeno resumo, na seção "Alternativas para o Java < 8")