# Como recortar uma String e converter para int em Java?

Tags: java, data

Como posso recortar a `String monthAndYear`, converter e atribuir as variáveis 
respectivas? No momento da conversão apresenta um erro.

```
System.out.print("Enter month and year to calculate income (MM/YYYY): ");
String monthAndYear = sc.nextLine();

int month = Integer.parseInt(monthAndYear.substring(0, 1));
int year = Integer.parseInt(monthAndYear.substring(3));
```

Comment: qual o erro? mostre o valor da variável monthAndYear

Comment: Para obter o mês tem de usar monthAndYear.substring(0, 2), são dois dígitos obrigatórios pela máscara que apresenta.

Comment: Antes de realizar o parseInt também deveria verificar se a variável monthAndYear tem o formato que queria que fosse inserido e caso contrário indica ao utilizador que errou e pergunta de novo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aqui está um exemplo com verificação do que o utilizador coloca.

Neste exemplo o campo `year` permite colocar anos desde o ano 0.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);  
    String monthAndYear = "";
    do{
      System.out.print("Enter month and year to calculate income (MM/YYYY): ");
      monthAndYear = in.nextLine();
    }while(!monthAndYear.matches("^(1[0-2]|0[1-9])/[0-9]{4}$"));


    int month = Integer.parseInt(monthAndYear.substring(0, 2));
    int year = Integer.parseInt(monthAndYear.substring(3)); 

    System.out.println(month);
    System.out.println(year);
    in.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Caso queira restringir o ano coloque em comentário para eu atualizar a resposta.

Comment: O erro acontece no momento da conversão, a variável monthAndYear recebe uma String com a data.                                                                
Este é o erro - Enter month and year to calculate income (MM/YYYY): Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end 1, length 0
 at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:3319)
 at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1874)
 at application.ProgramWorker.main(ProgramWorker.java:59)

Comment: Não consigo reproduzir o seu erro usando esta solução. Pelo erro vc ainda está a utilizar a sua versão e está a tentar obter a substring de uma string menor do que os seus argumentos begin e end.

Answer (score 3):

Uma alternativa (além do `substring` já sugerido [na outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/394492/112052)) seria usar [`split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-):

```
String monthAndYear = ...
String[] partes = monthAndYear.split("/"); // separar pela barra
if (partes.length == 2) {
    int month = Integer.parseInt(partes[0]);
    int year = Integer.parseInt(partes[1]);
}
```

Lembrando que o método [`parseInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) pode lançar um [`NumberFormatException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) caso uma das partes não seja um número (e você pode colocar um `try`/`catch` para verificar isso, se quiser).
E você ainda precisará validar os valores (se o mês está entre 1 e 12, por exemplo), que pode ser feito antes com regex (como sugeriu [a outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/394492/112052)), ou depois de feito o *parsing*.

---

#### Se está lidando com datas, use uma API de datas

Se a sua `String` deve ter uma data (ainda que incompleta, pois só tem o mês e ano), então por que não usar uma API de datas?

Se estiver usando Java >= 8, use as classes do pacote [`java.time`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/112052):

```
String monthAndYear = ...
DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/uuuu");
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.parse(monthAndYear, parser);
int month = ym.getMonthValue();
int year = ym.getYear();
```

A classe [`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) recebe como parâmetro o formato no qual a `String` está (no caso, "mês/ano"). Em seguida usamos um [`java.time.YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html), que é uma classe que representa um ano e mês (justamente o que precisamos).

O método `parse` retorna uma instância contendo os valores numéricos do mês e ano que estavam na `String`. Em seguida, é possível recuperar esses valores numéricos usandos os respectivos *getters*. O *parsing* também já valida se os valores são válidos (se o mês está entre 1 e 12), assim você já garante que é uma data válida. Caso a `String` não esteja no formato indicado, ou algum dos seus valores seja inválido, é lançada uma [`DateTimeParseException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeParseException.html).

---

Para o Java <= 7, você pode usar a classe [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), que funciona de maneira similar ao `java.time`:

```
String monthAndYear = ...
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/yyyy");
sdf.setLenient(false);
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(sdf.parse(monthAndYear));
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

Uma diferença importante é o uso de `setLenient(false)`, caso contrário serão aceitos meses com valores como "00" e "13".

Caso a `String` seja inválida, será lançada uma [`ParseException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/ParseException.html).

Outro detalhe é que para obter o valor numérico do mês você deve somar 1, pois nesta API os meses são indexados em zero (janeiro é zero, fevereiro é 1, etc).

---

Se quiser, para Java 6 e 7 também é possível usar o [ThreeTen Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), um *backport* do `java.time`. Basicamente, ele possui classes e métodos com os mesmo nomes e funcionalidades, a diferença é que, em vez de usar o pacote `java.time`, você usa o `org.threeten.bp`. Tirando este detalhe, o código ficaria igual ao exemplo do Java 8 acima.

Answer (score 2):

No seu caso, além das estratégias já comentadas, também pode ser usado [expressões regulares](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express%C3%A3o_regular):

```
    String monthYear = "07/2019";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([\\d]{2})\\/([\\d]{4})");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(monthYear);

    if (matcher.matches()) {
      int month = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
      int year = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
    }
```

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda