# Calcular o número da semana dentro do mês

Tags: javascript, data

O desafio é calcular o número da semana dentro de determinado mês, sem utilizar iteração (loops ou laços). O objetivo é produzir uma solução replicável para qualquer linguagem de programação.

Foi produzida em JavaScript por dois motivos:

- Aproveitamento de código de uma solução semelhante para o número da semana dentro do ano
- Simplicidade de uso das ferramentas de implementação (*browser*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Baseado nos [seus resultados](https://pastebin.com/Y4mjs7wX), eu diria que você não está calculando exatamente "o número da semana **dentro do mês**".

Prova disso são os resultados para 1 e 2 de janeiro de 2000, que resultou em `5`. Como esses dias podem estar na quinta semana de janeiro (já que, no meu entendimento, a "semana **dentro** do mês", seria o número da semana dentro do mesmo mês)? Pois se é "a semana **dentro do mês**", então não deveria ser `1`?

Na verdade, primeiro temos que definir o que é uma semana e como fazer a contagem das mesmas dentro de um calendário.

---

## Definição de semana

A princípio, uma semana é "qualquer período de 7 dias consecutivos". Mas quando juntamos isso com calendários, as coisas se complicam um pouco, pois existem várias formas de se definir o "número da semana", seja relativo a um ano ou mês.

Existe um conceito que é "a semana do ano" (ainda não vamos falar da "semana dentro do mês", mas posteriormente chegaremos lá): dada uma determinada data, eu quero saber em qual semana do ano ela está. E esse cálculo depende de duas variáveis:

1. O primeiro dia da semana
2. A quantidade de dias na primeira semana

A norma [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), por exemplo, [define](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#First_week) que o primeiro dia da semana é segunda-feira, e a quantidade mínima de dias na primeira semana é 4 (para facilitar, vou escrever esta definição na forma `(Seg, 4)`). Isso quer dizer que a primeira semana de 2000 é aquela que começa em uma segunda-feira **e** possui no mínimo 4 dias no ano 2000.

Se pegarmos o calendário do final de 1999 e início de 2000, temos:

```
Dom Seg Ter Qua Qui Sex Sab
 26  27  28  29  30  31   1  <- dez/1999 e jan/2000
  2   3   4   5   6   7   8  <- jan/2000
  9  10 ...
```

A semana de 27/dez a 2/jan começa em uma segunda-feira, mas tem menos que 4 dias em 2000. Por isso ela não é a primeira semana de 2000, **se** usarmos a definição da ISO 8601, que é `(Seg, 4)`. Então, de acordo com esta definição, a primeira semana de 2000 é de 3 a 9 de janeiro (já a semana de 27/12 a 2/jan é a 52ª semana de 1999). Inclusive, diz-se que o *week-based year* (ano baseado em semanas) de 01/01/2000 é **1999** (o "ano-calendário" é 2000, mas o *week-based year* é 1999 - apesar de ambos serem "anos" e terem o mesmo valor para a maioria das datas, são conceitos diferentes).

Mas a definição da ISO 8601, apesar de muito usada, não é a única. [O primeiro dia da semana varia muito de acordo com aspectos culturais e religiosos](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-Sunday-the-first-day-of-the-week). Em muitos lugares considera-se que a semana começa no sábado ou no domingo, por exemplo.

Uma das tentativas de se padronizar - ou ao menos catalogar - essas definições é o [CLDR (*Unicode Common Locale Data Repository*)](http://cldr.unicode.org), um repositório de informações relacionadas aos *locales* (um *locale* representa uma "região geográfica e seus aspectos culturais, políticos, regionais, etc"). As definições do primeiro dia da semana e a quantidade mínima de dias na primeira semana ficam no arquivo de [`supplementalData`](https://unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/supplemental/supplementalData.xml):

```xml
<firstDay day="mon" territories=" 001 AD AI AL AM AN AT AX AZ BA BE BG BM BN BY CH CL CM CR CY CZ DE DK EC EE ES FI FJ FO FR GB GE GF GP GR HR HU IE IS IT KG KZ LB LI LK LT LU LV MC MD ME MK MN MQ MY NL NO NZ PL RE RO RS RU SE SI SK SM TJ TM TR UA UY UZ VA VN XK"/> 
<firstDay day="fri" territories="MV"/> 
<firstDay day="sat" territories="AE AF BH DJ DZ EG IQ IR JO KW LY OM QA SD SY"/> 
<firstDay day="sun" territories=" AG AR AS AU BD BR BS BT BW BZ CA CN CO DM DO ET GT GU HK HN ID IL IN JM JP KE KH KR LA MH MM MO MT MX MZ NI NP PA PE PH PK PR PT PY SA SG SV TH TT TW UM US VE VI WS YE ZA ZW"/>
<firstDay day="sun" territories="GB" alt="variant" references="Shorter Oxford Dictionary (5th edition, 2002)"/>

<minDays count="1" territories="001 GU UM US VI"/>
<minDays count="4" territories="AD AN AT AX BE BG CH CZ DE DK EE ES FI FJ FO FR GB GF GG GI GP GR HU IE IM IS IT JE LI LT LU MC MQ NL NO PL PT RE RU SE SJ SK SM VA" />
```

Como podemos ver, o primeiro dia da semana pode ser sábado, domingo, segunda ou até mesmo sexta, e alguns locales consideram `1` como o mínimo de dias na primeira semana (diferente da ISO 8601, que considera `4`).

Ou seja, se pegarmos as mesmas datas de dez/1999 e jan/2000 que vimos antes:

```
Dom Seg Ter Qua Qui Sex Sab
 26  27  28  29  30  31   1  <- dez/1999 e jan/2000
  2   3   4   5   6   7   8  <- jan/2000
  9  10 ...
```

Se usarmos a definição `(Dom, 1)` (primeiro dia da semana é domingo, mínimo de dias na primeira semana é 1), então a semana de 26/dez a 1/jan passa a ser a primeira semana de 2000 (pois é a primeira que começa em um domingo e tem pelo menos 1 dia em 2000). Neste caso, os dias entre 26 e 31 de dezembro de 1999 também fazem parte da primeira semana de 2000 (o seu *week-based year* é 2000, apesar do "ano-calendário" ser 1999).

---

#### Semanas dentro de um mês

A norma ISO 8601 [**não** define nenhuma associação entre meses e semanas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#Weeks_per_month). O que existem são diferentes implementações que cada linguagem e API define, e que **tomam algumas decisões arbitrárias** para definir o valor da "semana dentro do mês".

Na API [`java.time`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/112052), por exemplo, é possível obter o número da semana dentro de um mês de duas formas diferentes:

1. considerando a definição de semana: nesse caso, se usarmos a definição ISO 8601 (`(Seg, 4)`), os dias 1 e 2 de janeiro de 2000 não estão na primeira semana de janeiro (qual é o primeiro período de 7 dias que começa em uma segunda e tem pelo menos 4 dias em janeiro de 2000? Não é a semana que tem os dias 1 e 2), então para esses dias o valor da "semana dentro do mês" é zero
2. considerando que a primeira semana do mês começa no dia 1: nesse caso, os dias 1 e 2 de janeiro sempre estão na primeira semana do mês, portanto o valor da "semana dentro do mês" para esses dias é 1

Sei que o foco da pergunta é JavaScript, mas só citei a API em Java porque ela já fornece as duas opções acima nativamente ([veja um exemplo](https://ideone.com/orZKVs)). E se olharmos o [código fonte](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.java), veremos que são cálculos meio chatos de se implementar manualmente. Este é um caso em que reinventar a roda só serviria para propósitos de aprendizado, mas se fosse para um sistema em produção, vale mais a pena usar uma biblioteca dedicada (se tem gente que [adiciona bibliotecas para coisas bem mais triviais](https://www.davidhaney.io/npm-left-pad-have-we-forgotten-how-to-program/), por que não adicionar uma para coisas mais complicadas, como esses cálculos todos que já mencionei?).

Uma alternativa é o [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com), que possui métodos para obter a semana do ano e o *week-based year*, usando tanto as regras do *locale* quanto as regras ISO 8601 (e para isso você vai precisar baixar a [versão com *locales*](https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js)):

```js
// locale França (Seg, 4)
moment.locale('fr-FR');
let d = moment('2000-01-01');
// semana do ano e week-based year, usando as regras do locale
console.log(`${d.week()} of ${d.weekYear()}`); // 52 of 1999
// semana do ano e week-based year, usando as regras ISO 8601
console.log(`${d.isoWeek()} of ${d.isoWeekYear()}`); // 52 of 1999

// locale Brasil (Dom, 1)
moment.locale('pt-BR');
d = moment('2000-01-01');
// semana do ano e week-based year, usando as regras do locale
console.log(`${d.week()} of ${d.weekYear()}`); // 1 of 2000
// semana do ano e week-based year, usando as regras ISO 8601
console.log(`${d.isoWeek()} of ${d.isoWeekYear()}`); // 52 of 1999
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
```

Se quiser, pode ver o [código fonte](https://github.com/moment/moment/) para saber como o cálculo é feito ([este trecho em particular pode ajudar](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/src/lib/units/week-calendar-utils.js)) e se basear nele. Mas infelizmente ela não provê nenhuma implementação para a "semana dentro do mês".

---

De qualquer forma, uma maneira de fazer seria a que está abaixo. Ela considera a mesma regra da opção 1 descrita acima ("se usarmos a definição ISO 8601 (`(Seg, 4)`), os dias 1 e 2 de janeiro de 2000 não estão na primeira semana de janeiro, então para eles o valor da "semana dentro do mês" é zero"):

```js
// considerando os dias da semana segundo a ISO 8601: segunda = 1, terça = 2, ..., domingo = 7 

function isoWeekOfMonth(dt) { // recebe um Date e retorna a semana do mês, considerando as regras da ISO 8601
    function floorDiv(x, y) {
        let r = x / y;
        if (r < 0) {
            r = -Math.floor(-r);
        } else {
            r = Math.floor(r);
        }
        if ((x ^ y) < 0 && (r * y != x)) {
            r--;
        }
        return r;
    }
    // os resultados de floorMod são diferentes do operador % quando há números negativos envolvidos
    // baseado em https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floorMod-int-int-
    function floorMod(x, y) {
        return x - floorDiv(x, y) * y;
    }
    function isoDayOfWeek(dt) {
        let sow = 1; // norma ISO, semana começa na segunda
        let dow = dt.getDay(); // obtém o dia da semana
        if (dow == 0) { dow = 7; } // ajuste para os valores da ISO 8601
        return floorMod(dow - sow, 7) + 1;
    }
    function startOfWeekOffset(day, dow) { 1, 6
        let weekStart = floorMod(day - dow, 7);
        let offset = -weekStart;
        if (weekStart + 1 > 4) {
            // semana anterior tem o mínimo de dias no mês atual
            offset = 7 - weekStart;
        }
        return offset;
    }
    function computeWeek(offset, day) {
        return Math.floor((7 + offset + (day - 1)) / 7);
    }

    let dow = isoDayOfWeek(dt);
    let dom = dt.getDate();
    let offset = startOfWeekOffset(dom, dow);
    return computeWeek(offset, dom);
}

// começando em 1 de dezembro de 1999
let d = new Date(1999, 11, 1); // lembrando que janeiro é mês zero, fevereiro é 1, etc
for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    console.log(d.toLocaleDateString('pt-BR'), isoWeekOfMonth(d));
    d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
}
```

<sup>O código acima foi adaptado do `java.time`, mas não fiz testes muito extensivos, verifiquei alguns meses e anos e *corner cases*, mas em linhas gerais é isso.</sup>

Já a segunda definição é mais fácil (de 1 a 7 de janeiro é a primeira semana, de 8 a 14 é a segunda semana, etc):

```js
function weekOfMonth(dt) { // recebe um Date e retorna a semana do mês, baseado no valor numérico do dia
    return Math.ceil(dt.getDate() / 7);
}

// começando em 1 de dezembro de 1999
let d = new Date(1999, 11, 1); // lembrando que janeiro é mês zero, fevereiro é 1, etc
for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    console.log(d.toLocaleDateString('pt-BR'), weekOfMonth(d));
    d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Implementação

Segue o código abaixo, com os devidos comentários. A função considera o domingo como o primeiro dia da semana.

```
function getMonthlyWeekNumber(dt)
{
    // como função interna, permite reuso
    var getmonweek = function(myDate) {
        var today = new Date(myDate.getFullYear(),myDate.getMonth(),myDate.getDate(),0,0,0);
        var first_of_month = new Date(myDate.getFullYear(),myDate.getMonth(),1,0,0,0);
        var p = Math.floor((today.getTime()-first_of_month.getTime())/1000/60/60/24/7);
        // ajuste de contagem
        if (today.getDay()<first_of_month.getDay()) ++p;
        // ISO 8601.
        if (first_of_month.getDay()<=3) p++;
        return p;
    }
    // último dia do mês
    var udm = (new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth()+1,0,0,0,0)).getDate();
    /*  Nos seis primeiros dias de um mês: verifica se estamos antes do primeiro Domingo.
     *  Caso positivo, usa o último dia do mês anterior para o cálculo.
     */
    if ((dt.getDate()<7) && ((dt.getDate()-dt.getDay())<-2))
        return getmonweek(new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),0));
    /*  Nos seis últimos dias de um mês: verifica se estamos dentro ou depois do último Domingo.
     *  Caso positivo, retorna 1 "de pronto".
     */
    else if ((dt.getDate()>(udm-6)) && ((dt.getDate()-dt.getDay())>(udm-3)))
        return 1;
    else
        return getmonweek(dt);
}
```

### Testes

O referido código foi testado para datas entre 01/01/2010 e 31/12/2020 com o uso das ferramentas de desenvolvedor do Google Chrome. Os resultados podem ser conferidos [neste link](https://pastebin.com/Y4mjs7wX).

### Considerações

Há uma inconsistência ainda não profundamente investigada nos resultados da função acima para o mês de Novembro de qualquer ano. Para os demais meses, a função retorna o resultado correto.