# Por que ao criar um Calendar, preciso subtrair 1 do mês?

Tags: java, data

Quando eu crio um produto e chamo o construtor passando os parâmetros, inclusive dia, mês e ano, não estou conseguindo compreender porque preciso subtrair 1 do mês no método `set`, observe abaixo:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class Produto {

    // Formatador de data
    private static final DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance();

    // Nome do produto
    private String nome;

    // Pedo do produto
    private double peso;

    // Data de validade
    private Date dataValidade;


    // Construtor. Recebe nome, peso e data de validade
    public Produto(String nome, double peso, int dia, int mes, int ano) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.peso = peso;

        // Cria um Calendar e seta os componentes da data
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(ano, mes - 1, dia);

        this.dataValidade = c.getTime();

    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public double getPeso() {
        return peso;
    }

    public Date getDataValidade() {
        return dataValidade;
    }

    // Obtém a data formatada como uma String no padrao curto
    public String getFormattedDataValidate() {
        return df.format(dataValidade);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação de `Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set-int-int-int-), o valor do mês que deve ser passado para o método `set` é indexado em zero. Ou seja, janeiro é 0, fevereiro é 1, etc.

Por isso é subtraído 1 do valor informado, pois ali provavelmente é passado o valor correto do mês (1 para janeiro, 2 para fevereiro, etc). Mas ao passar esse valor pra `Calendar`, tem que subtrair 1 para que ele gere a data correta.

Isso é meio confuso, mas [é assim que a classe `Calendar` funciona](https://stackoverflow.com/q/344380). Esse é um dos motivos (não é o principal, mas com certeza é um que contribui) pelos quais essa API [é tão criticada](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1571265).

---

## `java.time`

Se estiver usando Java >= 8 **e** seu código não depende do uso de [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) e [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), uma alternativa é usar a [API `java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Esta API resolve muitos dos [problemas da API antiga](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1969442).

Se você só quer a data com dia, mês e ano (e não precisa do horário e nem do [timezone](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info)), pode usar um [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html):

```
public class Produto {

    private LocalDate dataValidade;

    public Produto(String nome, double peso, int dia, int mes, int ano) {
        this.dataValidade = LocalDate.of(ano, mes, dia);
        ...
    }
}
```

Essa API possui várias melhorias com relação a `Date` e `Calendar`. A mais simples - e ao mesmo tempo uma das melhores - é que agora os meses não são mais indexados em zero e portanto possuem os valores corretos (janeiro é 1, fevereiro é 2, etc). Não é mais necessário subtrair 1, como era com `Calendar`.

Já para formatar a data, use um [`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). No seu caso, você estava usando [`DateFormat.getDateInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#getDateInstance--), que usa o formato padrão no *locale default* da JVM. Para obter o equivalente no `java.time`, use um [`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html), juntamente com um [`java.time.format.FormatStyle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html):

```
public class Produto {

    private LocalDate dataValidade;

    private static final DateTimeFormatter FMT = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendLocalized(FormatStyle.MEDIUM, null).toFormatter();

    public String getFormattedDataValidade() {
        return FMT.format(dataValidade);
    }
}
```

---

Se você ainda não usa Java 8, pode usar o [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), que possui as mesmas classes já mencionadas (`LocalDate`, `DateTimeFormatter`, etc) e funciona basicamente do mesmo jeito. A diferença é que elas estão no pacote `org.threeten.bp` (ao invés de `java.time`). O *backport* é compatível com JDK 6 e 7.

---

Caso ainda esteja preso ao Java 5 e queira usar algo melhor que `Date` e `Calendar`, uma alternativa é o [Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/) (embora este seja um projeto considerado "encerrado", já que no seu site [há um aviso](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/#Support) indicando isso e recomendando o uso do `java.time`)

O Joda-Time possui classes com nomes similares ao `java.time`, embora não seja 100% igual. As classes ficam no pacote `org.joda.time`, segue um exemplo similar ao código anterior:

```
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

...
LocalDate date = new LocalDate(ano, mes, dia);
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.mediumDate();
System.out.println(fmt.print(date));
```

---

Mais sobre o `java.time` pode ser visto [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/112052).

Comment: Olá. Realmente, acabei de me recordar disso, excelente explicação, Obrigado!