# Converter String para Date Do formato yyyy-mm-dd para dd-mm-yyyy

Tags: java, data, simpledateformat

Fiz um endpoint em Java que contém a informação de data. A data é recebida como string no formato 'yyyy-mm-dd'. Preciso converter para `Date` com formato 'dd-mm-yyyy'. Estou usando o seguinte formato que está com erro. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
@RequestMapping(value="/get/{numeroNotaFiscal}/{cnpj}/{dataNotaFiscal}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Boolean NotaFiscalDataCnpj(@PathVariable String numeroNotaFiscal, @PathVariable String cnpj, @PathVariable String dataNotaFiscal) {
    DB2DAOSo sofv = new DB2DAOSo();
    //Converte de String para Date
    DateFormat formatUS = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
    Date date = formatUS.parse(dataNotaFiscal);

    DateFormat formatBR = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
    String dataConvertida = formatBR.format(date);
    
    Boolean resposta = sofvdnrf.getNotaFiscalDataCnpj(numeroNotaFiscal, cnpj, dataConvertida);
    return resposta;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), para o mês deve-se usar o "M" maiúsculo. O "m" minúsculo corresponde aos minutos.

Sendo assim, ficaria:

```
DateFormat formatUS = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = formatUS.parse(dataNotaFiscal);

DateFormat formatBR = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String dataConvertida = formatBR.format(date);
```

Um detalhe é que `SimpleDateFormat` é bem permissiva e aceita datas inválidas, como "2020-99-99" (e os resultados são bem "estranhos", saiba mais lendo [aqui](https://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue172.html) e [aqui](https://eyalsch.wordpress.com/2009/05/29/sdf/)). Para evitar esses casos, você pode setar o modo leniente para `false`:

```
DateFormat formatUS = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
formatUS.setLenient(false); // assim não aceita datas inválidas
Date date = formatUS.parse(dataNotaFiscal);
... etc
```

Desta forma, datas inválidas lançarão uma exceção.

---

Se estiver usando Java >= 8, outra opção é usar a [API `java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/overview/design.html). Para o seu caso, que só tem dia, mês e ano, pode ser usado um [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html), e para formatar, use um [`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html):

```
LocalDate data = LocalDate.parse(dataNotaFiscal);
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-uuuu");
String dataConvertida = fmt.format(data);
```

---

Detalhe que o método `parse` por padrão já funciona com o formato "ano-mês-dia" (que é o formato definido pela [norma ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)). Mas caso a string estivesse em outro formato, bastaria criar outro `DateTimeFormatter` e passá-lo para o método `parse`. Ex:

```
// supondo que a string está em outro formato
DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu")
    .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT); // para não aceitar datas inválidas
LocalDate data = LocalDate.parse("20/01/2020", parser);
etc..
```

Repare também no uso de "u" em vez de "y" para o ano. Para mais detalhes, veja [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41178418/540552).

Quanto ao uso do `ResolverStyle`, é porque por *default* o *parser* aceita algumas datas inválidas, como 31/04/2020 (pois abril só tem 30 dias). Veja mais detalhes nas respostas [desta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/112052).

Comment: consegui resolver aqui com suas dicas! Muito obrigada!!