# TimeZone errada no JAVA

Tags: java, data, datetime, timezone, simpledateformat

Estou fazendo uma aplicação em que preciso mostrar num gráfico o tempo real da captura de um certo dado

Testei esse código:

```
 SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");       
 format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo")));
```

Mas ele me retorna **12:32** quando na verdade são **21:32**

O que estou configurando errado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), a letra "h" minúscula corresponde a "*hour in am/pm*", com valores entre 1 e 12 (ou seja, é um campo ambíguo, que faz mais sentido se você também usar o *pattern* "a", que indica se o horário é AM ou PM).

Para ter as horas com valores entre zero e 23, use "H" maiúsculo:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
```

> Mesmo assim, "hh" deveria retornar "09", qual foi a data usada na formatação?

---

Outro detalhe é que você misturou a API antiga (`TimeZone`) com a API nova (`ZoneId`), mas não há necessidade disso. Ou use uma, ou outra. No caso, como está usando a API antiga, não use `ZoneId`:

```
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Sao_Paulo"));
```

---

Mas se você está usando `ZoneId`, quer dizer que está com o Java >= 8, então por que não usar logo a [API nova](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/112052)?

Para obter a hora atual em um determinado timezone, você pode usar um [`java.time.LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html), e para formatar, use um [`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html):

```
// hora atual no timezone America/Sao_Paulo
LocalTime horaAtual = LocalTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo"));
// definir o formato (hora:minuto:segundo)
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(fmt.format(horaAtual));
```