# Subtrair 1 mês de uma string contendo data no format dd/mm/aaaa

Tags: java, data

```
String data = "09/04/2021";
String charComeco   = data.substring(0, 2);
String charMeio = data.substring(3, 5); 
Integer  meioTratado2 = Integer.parseInt(charMeio);
meioTratado2 -=1;
System.out.println(meioTratado2);

//Após retirar 1 da data, ela perda o 0 do começo, preciso diminuir 1 mês dessa data e mandar novamente com o 0, ficando assim => 09/03/2021

String charFinal = data.substring(6, 10);
data = "'"+ charComeco + "'" + meioTratado2 + "'" + charFinal + "'";
System.out.println(data); //'09'4'2021'
```

Também gostaria de review para melhora no código, obrigado.

Comment: Use as classes do pacote `time`. Basicamente, pegue a **String** e converta para `LocalDate`, remova quantidade necessária, depois converte para **String** novamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um exemplo funcional:

```
package data;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class ModificarData {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String entrada = "04/03/2020";

        // Formatador de data
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
        
        // Converte a string para LocalDate e remove 1 mês
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(entrada, formatter);
        date = date.minus(1, ChronoUnit.MONTHS);

        // Reatribui a string com o LocalDate.
        entrada = formatter.format(date);
        System.out.println(entrada);
    }
}
```

Comment: Fala man, obrigado pela ajuda :)

Answer (score 1):

Boa noite David,

caso você queira utilizar as bibliotecas do java.time, podemos resolver da seguinte forma:

```
public class SubtrairUmMesDaData {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String date = LocalDate.of(2020,4,9)
            .minusMonths(1).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"));

    System.out.println(date);
}
```

}

Transformamos a entrada em LocalDate, subtraímos um mês e formatamos para o padrão desejado.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Fala man, obrigado pela ajuda :)

Answer (score 1):

Só para complementar as outras respostas, vale explicar porque é melhor usar uma API de datas em vez de manipular a string diretamente.

Primeiro porque, além de dar mais trabalho, a manipulação da string não garante que a data é válida (nem a que você recebe, nem o resultado final).

Por exemplo, se o mês for janeiro (`01`) e você simplesmente subtrair 1, o resultado será zero, então a data inicial fosse `09/01/2020`, o resultado ficaria algo como `09/00/2020`. Ou seja, uma data completamente inválida.

E se a data inicial fosse `31/03/2020`? Ao subtrair 1 do mês, o resultado seria `31/02/2020` (31 de fevereiro, completamente errado).

Claro que você até consegue fazer os devidos ajustes manualmente, mas já existem API's de datas justamente para tratar desses casos para você. A outra vantagem é que essa mesma API também já valida a data, o que garante que você saberá se passar uma data inválida:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.ResolverStyle;

...
String data = "09/04/2021";
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu")
    .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);
// faz o parsing da data e subtrai 1 mês
LocalDate dt = LocalDate.parse(data, fmt).minusMonths(1);
String dataFinal = fmt.format(dt);
System.out.println(dataFinal); // 09/03/2021
```

Eu usei [`ResolverStyle.STRICT`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html#STRICT) para que ele aceite somente datas válidas. Sem isso, o comportamento *default* é aceitar datas como 31 de abril (que é automaticamente ajustada para 30 de abril, [veja aqui um exemplo](https://ideone.com/KL3kcn)). Usando o modo `STRICT`, 31 de abril lança uma exceção ([`DateTimeParseException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeParseException.html), que você pode colocar em um bloco `try`/`catch` se quiser).

Também usei `uuuu` em vez de `yyyy` para o ano, [leia aqui para saber a diferença](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41178418/).

---

Vale lembrar que [aritmética de datas](https://hkotsubo.github.io/tag/aritm%C3%A9tica) é "bizarra" e [muitas vezes contra-intuitiva](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/12/01/the-joys-of-date-time-arithmetic/). Por exemplo, se a data for 31 de março de 2020, o resultado de subtrair 1 mês é 29 de fevereiro de 2020 (como fevereiro não tem 31 dias, o ajuste é feito para o último dia do mês). O mesmo vale se subtrair 1 mês de 29 ou 30 de março de 2020, o resultado também será 29 de fevereiro de 2020 (e se o ano não fosse bissexto, o ajuste seria feito para o dia 28).

Se quer resultados diferentes, terá que ajustar manualmente, pois esta é a forma que a API faz os cálculos.

---

#### Java <= 7

O código acima vale para Java >= 8, pois a API `java.time` não existe em versões anteriores.

Para Java 6 e 7, você pode usar o [ThreeTen Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), que é um *backport* do `java.time`. Basicamente, possui as mesmas classes e métodos, a diferença é que elas estão no pacote `org.threeten.bp`, em vez de `java.time`. Mais detalhes no final [desta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/370367/112052).

Mas se não quiser usar uma biblioteca externa, uma opção é usar a API antiga: [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html) e [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

```
String data = "09/04/2021";

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
sdf.setLenient(false); // para não aceitar datas inválidas

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(sdf.parse(data));
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1); // subtrai 1 mês

String dataFinal = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
System.out.println(dataFinal); // 09/03/2021
```

Eu usei `setLenient(false)` para que não aceite datas inválidas (caso contrário, 31 de abril é ajustado para 1 de maio). No modo não-leniente, datas inválidas lançam um [`java.text.ParseException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/text/ParseException.html).

Comment: Carai '0', preciso de tempo para terminar de ler tudo isso e agradecer pelo conhecimento.