# SimpleDateFormat am/pm format retorna "da tarde" em vez de "PM"

Tags: java, data, simpledateformat

Usando uma solução desta pergunta:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907968/how-to-convert-24-hr-format-time-in-to-12-hr-format

Ao fazer o seguinte:

```
        Int hour = 13;
        SimpleDateFormat _24HourSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        SimpleDateFormat _12HourSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
        Date _24HourDt = _24HourSDF.parse((Integer.toString(hour)+":00"));
        System.out.println(_24HourDt);
        System.out.println(_12HourSDF.format(_24HourDt));
```

O resultado do segundo print é:

```
01:00 da tarde
```

Como faço para retornar:

```
01:00 PM
```

Comment: Provavelmente é o *locale default* da sua JVM. Por favor veja qual é o resultado de `System.out.println(Locale.getDefault())` (não esqueça de fazer o `import java.util.Locale`)

Comment: Retorna: pt_PT 
Como faço para mudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu não consegui reproduzir (testei no Java 8 e 11, com diferentes *locales*) mas provavelmente é por causa do *locale default* da JVM (veja qual é o seu, com `System.out.println(Locale.getDefault())`).

O que acontece é que `SimpleDateFormat` usa o *locale default* da JVM, e este *locale* pode afetar algumas strings de formatação, como é o caso do AM/PM.

Por exemplo, se eu fizer:

```
// locale default será o do Japão
Locale.setDefault(new Locale("ja", "JP"));
int hour = 13;
SimpleDateFormat _24HourSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
SimpleDateFormat _12HourSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
Date _24HourDt = _24HourSDF.parse((Integer.toString(hour) + ":00"));
System.out.println(_12HourSDF.format(_24HourDt));
```

A saída será :

```
01:00 午後
```

Pois `SimpleDateFormat` usa o *locale default* que está configurado no momento em que ele é instanciado. E este *locale* pode afetar as strings que são usadas na formatação.

Mas se você quer strings específicas, que não dependem do que está configurado na JVM, então a solução é setar o *locale* na criação do `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
SimpleDateFormat _12HourSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.US);
```

No caso, `Locale.US` usa o *locale* correspondente ao inglês americano, que usa as strings "AM" e "PM".

Esta solução eu acho melhor porque você só altera o que precisa (a instância específica de `SimpleDateFormat`). Se você mudar o *locale default* (com `Locale.setDefault`), isso afeta todas as aplicações que estiverem rodando na mesma JVM, e isso pode ter efeitos colaterais indesejados.

---

## Java >= 8

A partir do Java 8 você pode usar a API `java.time`, mais moderna e que corrige vários problemas de `Date` e `SimpleDateFormat` (veja mais [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/112052)).

Por exemplo, para criar um horário correspondente a 13:00, não precisa daquele "malabarismo" todo que você fez com `Date`. Basta criar um `java.time.LocalTime` (uma classe que só possui os campos de horário, que parece ser o que você precisa):

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.LocalTime;

...
// criar o horário 13:00
LocalTime time = LocalTime.of(13, 0);
// formatar (não esqueça do locale, para ter as strings AM/PM corretamente)
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a", Locale.US);
System.out.println(fmt.format(time)); // 01:00 PM
```

Para formatar, também é necessário setar o *locale*, senão você acaba tendo o mesmo problema (ele assume o *default* da JVM, e as strings "AM/PM" podem não ser exatamente essas).

Comment: Funcionou! Muito obrigado. Boa resposta e explicação!

Comment: @lemario Não sei qual a versão do Java que vc está usando, mas caso seja Java >= 8, tem uma alternativa - na minha opinião, muito melhor - que é usar a API `java.time`. Adicionei esta opção no final da resposta.