# Como ajustar uma data para o formato dd/MM/yyyy

Tags: java, data, java-8, simpledateformat

Estou recebendo a seguinte data via JSON: "2022-10-27T00:00:00Z".

Quando eu aplico a formatação do `SimpleDateFormat`, ele me apresenta a seguite data: `26/10/2022 21:00:00`.

Como faço para formatar a data e manter o mesmo dia e mesmo horário que estou recebendo?

No programa que estou desenvolvendo, a data vem do banco de dados ou do servidor.

Estou usando:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String dataFormatada = sdf.format(request.getData());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `SimpleDateFormat` usa o timezone que está configurado como padrão, que no caso parece ser do Brasil.

Vc só precisa configurá-lo para usar o timezone desejado. Assim:

```java
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String... args) throws ParseException {
    Date dataQueVemDaRequest = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX").parse("2022-10-27T00:00:00Z");

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

    String dataFormatada = sdf.format(dataQueVemDaRequest);

    System.out.println(dataFormatada);
  }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Funcionou!

Comment: Aproveito para deixar aqui um vídeo do Nélio Alves que aborda vários conceitos sobre datas no Java. Porém como utilizo o Java 8, não se aplicaram para o meu caso, mas pode ser que se aplique para outras pessoas: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WnJUI-jMQGE

Comment: @IurySalino Se está usando Java 8, então seria melhor usar a API `java.time`, que é muito superior a `Date` e `SimpleDateFormat`. [Na minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/568783/112052) coloquei uma alternativa com a nova API

Comment: E só pra constar que `SimpleDateFormat` usa o timezone default da JVM, mas não necessariamente é o mesmo timezone local da máquina. Por exemplo, dá para passar o argumento `-Duser.timezone` para a JVM, ou chamar `TimeZone.setDefault` em qualquer ponto da aplicação (ambos sobrescrevem a configuração local da máquina)

Comment: Obrigado, @hkotsubo. Ajustei o texto para ficar de acordo com sua explicação. Também removi do exemplo o uso do `Instant`. Eu o usei porque, para mim, era o jeito mais simples de conseguir uma data baseada na string que o autor mostrou e achei que não importaria já o autor já tem seu próprio jeito de conseguir um `Date` e a parte da solução que importa está depois que o `SimpleDateFormat` foi instânciado. Mas concordo que pode ficar estranho misturar as APIs neste exemplo específico.

Answer (score 3):

Esse "Z" no final indica que a data/hora está em [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). Mas aqui temos dois problemas:

- um `Date` não guarda nenhuma informação do timezone
- `SimpleDateFormat` usa o timezone *default* que está configurado da JVM (pode ser alterado, como indicou a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/568750/112052)). E se não for UTC, dará esta diferença que você viu

Um detalhe é que a outra resposta usava `Instant.parse` ([antes de ser editada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/568750/revisions)), que é da [API `java.time`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/112052) (ou seja, Java >= 8). Mas se você tem essa API disponível, não deveria usar `SimpleDateFormat` (mais sobre isso abaixo, mas por enquanto vamos focar no `SimpleDateFormat`).

Enfim, se for para fazer o *parsing* e a formatação com `SimpleDateFormat`, você precisa criar um para cada, e na hora de formatar deve usar UTC. Algo assim:

```java
String dataQueVeioDoJSON = "2022-10-27T00:00:00Z";

// primeiro converte a string para Date
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX");
Date date = parser.parse(dataQueVeioDoJSON);

// depois formata para o novo formato
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
// usar UTC
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
String dataFormatada = formatter.format(date);
System.out.println(dataFormatada);
```

Porém **isso só funciona se for garantido que a entrada sempre está em UTC** (ou seja, se sempre tem o "Z" no final).

Não foi dito se é o caso, mas enfim, se vier algo como por exemplo `"2022-10-27T23:00:00-03:00"`, então o código acima não funcionará mais. Isso porque agora a data/hora está com o *offset* `-03:00` (3 horas atrás do UTC), e ao formatá-la usando UTC, o resultado será 28/10/2022 (pois 23h do dia 27 no *offset* `-03:00` corresponde a 2 da manhã do dia 28 em UTC).

Neste caso, você teria que extrair o *offset* da string original, para setá-la no `SimpleDateFormat`:

```java
String dataQueVeioDoJSON = "2022-10-27T23:00:00-03:00";

SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX");
Date date = parser.parse(dataQueVeioDoJSON);

SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
// usar o mesmo offset que está na string original
String offset = dataQueVeioDoJSON.substring(19);
TimeZone tz;
if ("Z".equals(offset)) {
    tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
} else {
    tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT" + offset);
}
formatter.setTimeZone(tz);
String dataFormatada = formatter.format(date);
System.out.println(dataFormatada);
```

---

## Se está usando Java >= 8, use a API `java.time`

Como já dito, na outra resposta usava `Instant.parse`, e como nos comentários você confirmou que funcionou, isso quer dizer que sua versão do Java é maior ou igual a 8.

Sendo assim, é preferível não usar `SimpleDateFormat` e `Date`. Use a nova API, muito mais simples e ainda resolve vários problemas da API antiga.

Por exemplo, para funcionar com qualquer *offset* (não só UTC), basta usar um [`java.time.OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html). Como a string original está no [formato ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), o *parsing* pode ser feito diretamente. Depois, basta usar um [`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) para convertê-la para o formato desejado:

```java
String dataQueVeioDoJSON = "2022-10-27T00:00:00Z";
OffsetDateTime data = OffsetDateTime.parse(dataQueVeioDoJSON);

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu");
String dataFormatada = formatter.format(data);
System.out.println(dataFormatada);
```

Um detalhe é que `OffsetDateTime` guarda a informação do *offset*, por isso não é preciso setá-lo no `DateTimeFormatter`. Agora funciona para qualquer *offset*, inclusive com `"2022-10-27T23:00:00-03:00"` usado no exemplo acima (`Instant.parse`, por sua vez, só funciona com UTC).